# How to create symbols from strings and set values for them?

Tags: evaluation, syntax, symbols, faq

I am trying to convert a list of string names into symbols, which will then be used to store data.  I have 24 files (where the name of each file is a member of the list mentioned above) that I need to process, which is why I am trying to accomplish my goal progammatically.  The code below results in a Tag warning.  I have read the normal documentation sources, and appreciate that you can not inappropriately assign something to a protected symbol, but this doesn't help me solve the problem.

Would you have any advice how to accomplish my goal?

```
Table[(ToExpression[mmsignalnames[[i]]] = 
   Extract[ToExpression[celfilenames[[i]]], mmammindices[[j]]]), {i, 
  1, Length[mmsignalnames]}, {j, 1, Length[mmammindices]}]

Set::write: Tag ToExpression in ToExpression[mmsignalGSM356796] is Protected. >>
```

Comment: Creating many different symbols is an error-prone practice, because you need ways to manage them, which is hard in this case. What you seem to be needing is a hash-table, with keys being your names (as strings) - this is the second suggestion in the answer of @Mr.Wizard.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

One solution is to use the third argument of `ToExpression`:

With minimal modification, a working version of your code would look like this:

```
Table[
  ToExpression[
  mmsignalnames[[i]], 
  InputForm, 
  Function[name, 
    name = Extract[ToExpression[celfilenames[[i]]], mmammindices[[j]]],
    HoldAll]],
 {i, Length[mmsignalnames]}, {j, Length[mmammindices]}]
```

<sup>(Untested because I don't have your data;  but see below for the main idea and a small demonstration.)</sup>

The core of the method is this:

```
ToExpression["a", InputForm, Function[name, name = 1, HoldAll]]
```

`ToExpression` will wrap the result into its third argument before evaluating it.  We can make the third argument a function that sets a value to the symbol (in this simple example it always sets the value to `1`).  `HoldAll` is needed to make sure the symbol won't evaluate when it is passed to the function.

---

You might find all the evaluation control I'm using here a bit confusing.  To learn how to work with unevaluated expressions, I recommend reading

- [Working with Unevaluated Expressions by Robby Villegas](http://library.wolfram.com/infocenter/Conferences/377/)

It is one of the best tutorials on the matter.

---

Finally, after answering your actual question, I'd like to suggest you use a hash table instead of symbols:

Instead of creating symbols from the strings `"a"`, `"b"`, `"c"`, ..., and assigning to them, you could assign to `myTable["a"]`, `myTable["b"]`, ...  This will make programmatic access to this data trivial.  You won't need to bother with evaluation control nearly as much.  And more importantly, you can avoid accidental name collisions with existing symbols.  Here's an example:

```
(myTable[#] = 1) & /@ {"a", "b", "c"}
```

Comment: The link to the Villegas tutorial is now http://library.wolfram.com/infocenter/Conferences/377/

Comment: @MichaelE2 Thanks!  Feel free to make the correction next time!

Answer (score 30):

So recently I've learned from [John Fultz](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/34587/5478) that `RawBoxes` are kind of *verbatim* indicator for `MakeBoxes` which is not well stressed out in documentation.

This or I've missed the point but it doesn't matter, here we have handy way to do this:

```
x = 5;
ToExpression @ MakeBoxes[RawBoxes["x"] = 123];
x
```

> ```
> 123
> ```

Comment: +1 for an exceptionally clear illustration of `RawBoxes`

Comment: @Mr.Wizard My life would have been waaay more easier if somebody have shown me this 2-3 years ago :( But I'm glad I've found and understood this. I think this is one of things I was missing in a long time. Thanks for +1 :)

Answer (score 16):

You need to make the left-hand side of `Set` a symbol at the time of evaluation.  Use `With` or similar to inject the symbol:

```
mmsignalnames = {"one", "two", "three"};

With[{lhs = Symbol[mmsignalnames[[2]]]},
 lhs = 5
];

two
```

> ```
> 5
> ```

Another approach that could be important if you are trying to make assignments to symbols that already have values is this:

```
Function[{lhs}, lhs = 7, HoldAll] @@ MakeExpression[ mmsignalnames[[2]] ] ;

two
```

> ```
> 7
> ```

Or a bit more terse using the ["injector pattern"](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/1937/121):

```
MakeExpression @ mmsignalnames[[2]] /. _@x_ :> (x = 9);

two
```

> ```
> 9
> ```

Also, it bears mentioning that one may also use indexed symbols such as

```
name["two"] = 5;

name["two"]
```

> ```
> 5
> ```

---

For another approach to this kind of problem see:

- [Elegant manipulation of the variables list](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/10322/12)

Comment: In the first case when you know your symbols haven't been defined yet, you could shorten it with Evaluate[ToExpression[mmsignalnames[[2]]]]=5

Comment: @Rojo yes, you can; I think that `With` is more flexible however, and I thought it would be easier to use in practice, though I admit I did not actually try it both ways (I would prefer indexed symbols myself).

Answer (score 12):

In *Mathematica* version 10, you can also use [`Inactive`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Inactive.html) to allow the `Symbol` to be created before doing the assignment.

Here is an example:

```
Clear["x"];
Activate[Inactive[Set][Symbol["x"], 3]]

(* ==> 3 *)

x

(* ==> 3 *)
```

Answer (score 8):

This answer is in the same spirit as Kuba's answer, but it avoids conversion between boxes and expressions.

Here is our workhorse

```
mark::usage = "Use in combination with markedExpression";
markedExpressify::usage = 
  "Use mark to mark strings for conversion to expressions";
markedExpressify[expr_] :=
 Module[{pos, hCExpr, ext, thr, rLH, expresser},
  hCExpr = HoldComplete[expr];
  pos = Position[hCExpr, Unevaluated@mark[_] ];
  expresser =
   Function[
    Null,
    ToExpression @@ {Unevaluated @@ #, InputForm, HoldComplete},
    HoldAllComplete
    ];
  ext = Join@@Extract[hCExpr, pos, expresser];
  thr = Thread[RuleDelayed @@ {HoldComplete @@ pos, ext}, 
    HoldComplete];
  rLH = List @@@ Hold@Evaluate@thr;
  First[ReplacePart @@ {hCExpr, Unevaluated @@ rLH}]
  ]
```

We can then do something like

```
markedExpressify[Unevaluated[mark[#] = f[#] = 123]] & /@ {"y", "x"};
f["x"]
x
```

> ```
> 123  
> 123
> ```

It works even if `mark` has a value, though this is something you should probably avoid.

```
mark = 6;
markedExpressify[Unevaluated[mark["z"] = 5]];
markedExpressify[Unevaluated[mark["g[2]"] = 3]];
z
g[2]
```

> ```
> 5
> 3
> ```

I did not give the function attribute `HoldAll`, because this way it works more nicely with held expressions.

```
markedExpression = Hold[mark@"x" := f@mark@"y" = 5];
markedExpressify@markedExpression
ReleaseHold@markedExpressify@markedExpression
x
f[y]
```

> ```
> Hold[x:=f[y]=5]
> 5
> 5
> ```