# Injecting a sequence of expressions into a held expression

Tags: evaluation, replacement, hold, insert

Consider the following toy example:

```
Hold[{1, 2, x}] /. x -> Sequence[3, 4]
```

It will give

```
Hold[{1, 2, Sequence[3, 4]}]
```

because `Sequence[]` (like `Unevaluated`) is expanded only in the first level of heads with attribute `HoldAll`.

**How can I obtain  `Hold[{1,2,3,4}]`?**  What is the simplest way to do this?

**Notes:**

- Use case: I am trying to generate a piece of code that will be passed to `Compile`.  I need to inject a variable number of iterators (which I have as a list) into a `Do` expression:

  ```
   Hold[Do[code, iterators]] /. iterators -> Sequence[{i,5}, {j,5}]
  ```
- I would prefers solutions that don't match on the expression enclosing `x`.  I would not like to repeat this expression (a `Do` in this case) in my code.
- It's perhaps worth pointing out that

  ```
   Hold[{1, 2, f[3, 4]}] //. f[x___] :> x
  ```

  returns

  ```
   Hold[{1, 2, Sequence[3, 4]}]
  ```

  so I can't easily implement a manual sequence-flattening step.

---

#### Answers

Based on **Leonid's code** we can write a `flattenSequence[]` function that will flatten out all `Sequence` expressions at any level:

```
flattenSequence[expr_] := 
 expr //. f_[left___, Verbatim[Sequence][middle___], right___] :> 
   f[left, middle, right]

flattenSequence[Hold[{1, Sequence[2, 3]}]]

(* ==> Hold[{1, 2, 3}] *)
```

Based on **Mr.Wizard's code** we can write a general function for injecting subexpressions into other expressions while supporting `Sequence`:

```
ClearAll[inject1, inject]

SetAttributes[inject1, HoldFirst]
Quiet[
 inject1[expr_, (Rule|RuleDelayed)[var_Symbol, values : Verbatim[Sequence][__]]] :=
  Replace[Unevaluated[values], Sequence[var__] :> expr];
 inject1[expr_, (Rule|RuleDelayed)[var_Symbol, value_]] :=
  Replace[Unevaluated[value], var_ :> expr],
 
 {RuleDelayed::rhs}
]

SetAttributes[inject, HoldAll]
inject[rules_, expr_] :=
 Internal`InheritedBlock[
  {Rule, RuleDelayed},
  SetAttributes[{Rule, RuleDelayed}, HoldFirst];
  ReleaseHold@Fold[inject1, HoldComplete[expr], rules]
 ]
```

Usage:

```
inject[{a -> Sequence[b, 3], b :> 1 + 1}, Hold[{a, b}]]

(* ==> Hold[{1 + 1, 3, 1 + 1}] *)
```

The replacements are done one after the other, so the second one can use the result of the first.  `Rule` and `RuleDelayed` are both handled correctly.

Comment: If you don't insist on `Sequence` it might be easier

Comment: If you can solve this in a direct and robust way I think it will call into question the need for `Sequence` at all.

Comment: I just read this. You have plenty of answers already. I just wanted to point out that those answers that rely on building the expression on the rhs of a rule, such as the firsts of MrWizard, respect scoping so you can get things renamed if you are injecting inside a scoping construct. This means that your inject might too. Try `inject[{aa -> {3, xx}}, Hold@With[{xx = 8}, Hold[{1, 2, aa}]]]`

Answer (score 59, accepted):

```
{3, 4} /. {x__} :> Hold[{1, 2, x}]
```

> ```
> Hold[{1, 2, 3, 4}]
> ```

Leonid Shifrin used this [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6236264/618728) long before I wrote this answer.

---

In light of Leonid's comment to halirutan it is worth pointing out that you can inject expressions from an arbitrary head including Hold.  You can also use `->` rather than `:>` like this:

```
expr = Hold[{1, 2, x}];

Hold[6/2, 2 + 2] /. _[x__] -> expr
```

> ```
> Hold[{1, 2, 6/2, 2 + 2}]
> ```

Comment: very cool actually

Comment: @acl I lied though: it still uses Sequence, just in the form of BlankSequence.  halirutan uses SlotSequence.  So I think it is not possible without Sequence of one brand or another.

Comment: Yes, but that's beyond the point. One could also do all this by converting to strings and replacing, and to me the other answers seem almost as clumsy as that. You do it with a much lighter touch.

Comment: @Kuba This is not an injection but rather a replacement so it is not quite the same as this question.  I think Leonid's method is probably the most applicable, e.g. `If[Hold[{a, b}], If[Hold[{c, d}], e]] //. h_[x___, _[{y___}], z___] :> h[x, y, z]`.  The `//.` is not efficient on long expressions but handling that will make this longer, making other methods comparatively more attractive.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard Good point. Thanks anyway :) Let me delete those comments then.

Answer (score 23):

How about this:

```
ClearAll[inject];
SetAttributes[inject, HoldRest];
inject[Hold[{args__}], new__] := Hold[{args, new}]
```

This will also accept `Sequence[3,4]` as a second argument. Sequences are spliced, while arguments themselves not evaluated.

**EDIT**

You can also use a composite rule, with some head `s` instead of `Sequence` (you can localize `s` if needed):

```
Hold[{1, 2, x}] /. x -> s[3, 4] /. 
  f_[left___, s[middle___], right___] :> f[left, middle, right]
```

Comment: This is exactly what I meant when I said "I would prefers solutions that don't match on the expression enclosing x. I would not like to repeat this expression (a Do in this case) in my code."  This will be ugly with the `Do`.

Comment: @Szabolcs Does my update address you needs? You could also wrap `s` around your `Sequence`, if you naturally get your results as a `Sequence`

Comment: Yes, it does.  This can be expanded into a function that will flatten out all `Sequence` elements in an arbitrary held expression (i.e. it can made into a self-contained and general tool that integrates well with other solutions)

Answer (score 12):

One way is to use `Function` and the possibility of `SlotSequence`. I define an additional function `f` to be sure nothing gets evaluated:

```
f[x_] := Print["Evaluated"];
Function[Hold[Do[f[1], ##]]][{i, 5}, {j, 5}]

(*
  Hold[Do[f[1], {i, 5}, {j, 5}]]
*)
```

Comment: This will have a problem when `i` or `j` have values before evaluation. You can use `Function[Null,Hold[Do[f[1],##]],HoldAll]` to avoid it.

Answer (score 10):

Not sure how robust this is, but you could do something like

```
flattenSequence[expr_, {x_, p__}] := Module[{f, t},
  f[t__] = expr /. x -> t;
  f[p]]
```

Then for the example above

```
flattenSequence[Hold[{1, 2, x}], {x, 3, 4}]
```

> ```
> Hold[{1, 2, 3, 4}]
> ```

Answer (score 6):

Ok. Here comes the `Inactivate`, Mathematica 10's powerful feature.

`Inactivate` could not solve injecting expression into `Hold`.

But you mentioned you actually want to use this to inject Do iterator in `Compile`. This can be done directly by `Inactivate` without `Hold` stuff. Use this

```
Activate[Inactivate[Compile[{}, Do[code, iterators]]] /. 
  iterators -> Sequence[{i, 5}, {j, 5}]]
```

I personally think that with `Inactivate` and `Activate`, we can think many things differently now, especially meta programming.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard Oh, yeah, But my second part solve Compile problem, what do you think? If this is also unnecessary, I will delete my answer : )

Comment: No, I can see value in that part.  Here's a +1. :-)

Answer (score 5):

Neat solutions provided, but there are probably more straight forward ways to solve the original problem. One of these might help.

```
In:= s=0; Apply[Do[s+=i^i,{i,##}]&,Hold[1,12,3]]; s  

Out[75]= 10000823800  


In:= r=Hold[s=0;{1,12,3};s];  
Part[r,1,2,0]=(Do[s+=i^i,{i,##}]&); ReleaseHold[r]  

Out= 10000823800
```

Answer (score 5):

I remarked before that I didn't think this was possible without Sequence, SlotSequence, BlankSequence, etc. (Without using string processing or the like that is.) It seems I was wrong, unless there is an implicit Sequence in here:

```
Hold[1 + 1, 2 + 2, #] & @ Unevaluated[3 + 3, 4 + 4]
```

> ```
> Hold[1 + 1, 2 + 2, 3 + 3, 4 + 4]
> ```

Comment: This works fine because you are injecting at first level inside Hold. See my following answer for clarifications.

Comment: Indeed, there is an implicit Sequence: try `{#}&@Unevaluated[1, 2] // Trace`.

Comment: @Federico I have this *vague* memory that I saw that in the trace when I posted this but that I did not consider it a "real" `Sequence` since it appears later?  I don't know, and I haven't given this a lot of thought since then.  Anyway, thanks for noting that for future readers.

Answer (score 5):

Perhaps something like this?

```
ClearAll[replaceFlatteningSequences];
replaceFlatteningSequences[lhs_, pat_ :> rhs_] /; MatchQ[lhs, pat] := 
 lhs /. lhs -> rhs
replaceFlatteningSequences[lhs_, pat_ :> Sequence[repSeq__]] := 
 Module[{tag},
  lhs /. {Slot -> tag, SlotSequence -> tag["Sequence"], 
        Function -> tag["Function"]} /. pat :> ## /. 
     all_ :> (all &[repSeq]) /. {tag["Function"] -> Function, 
     tag["Sequence"] -> SlotSequence} /. tag -> Slot
  ]
```

To be used

```
replaceFlatteningSequences[Hold@With[{x = 8}, ## aa &], 
 aa :> Sequence[x, 4]]
```

> Hold[With[{x = 8}, ##1 x 4 &]]

Answer (score 5):

In a previous answer Mr.Wizard suggested

```
Hold[1 + 1, 2 + 2, #] &@Unevaluated[3 + 3, 4 + 4]
```

However injecting deeper inside a `Hold` with this technique does not work:

```
Hold[{1 + 1, 2 + 2, #}] &@Unevaluated[3 + 3, 4 + 4]
```

returns `Hold[{1 + 1, 2 + 2, Sequence[3 + 3, 4 + 4]}]`.

I would like to point out that a little variation does indeed work:

```
Hold[{1 + 1, 2 + 2, ##}] &[3 + 3, 4 + 4]
```

And if one does indeed want the arguments not to be evaluated, then it is possible to use

```
Function[Null, Hold[{1 + 1, 2 + 2, SlotSequence[1]}], {HoldAll}][3 + 3, 4 + 4]
```

Answer (score 5):

I though it is nice untill I had to add `reparse` function :)

```
SetAttributes[mySequence, HoldAllComplete];
mySequence[args__] := RawBoxes[  MakeBoxes[{args}][[1, 2]]  ];
reparse = ToExpression @* FrontEndExecute @* FrontEnd`ReparseBoxStructurePacket @* ToBoxes


y = 7;
Hold[{1, x, 2, x, 3}] /. x :> RuleCondition @ mySequence[y, 1+2] //reparse
```

> ```
>  Hold[{1, y, 1 + 2, 2, y, 1 + 2, 3}]
> ```

Comment: But the result is not that expression, it just *looks like* that expression.  It cannot be re-used programmatically, and the produced cell cannot even be edited manually within the front end, then evaluated, without producing errors.

Comment: @Szabolcs good point, fixed. but it is not so clean now :(