# Problem when defining variable in Mathematica

Tags: functions, variable-definitions

I'm trying to run this:

```
domain := {n, 0, 10};
Plot[n, domain]
```

but it doesn't work. Instead, it generates the message

```
Plot::pllim: Range specification domain is not of the form {x, xmin, xmax}.
```

and returns

```
Plot[n, domain].
```

Why?

I've also tried alternatives such as using `=`, or trying to define `Domain[n_] = {n, 0, 10}` but it all seemed to be of no avail.

Comment: Works as-is in version 12.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Use:

```
domain := {n, 0, 10};
Plot[n, Evaluate[domain]]
```

Plot has the `HoldAll` attribute which prevents `domain` from evaluating:

```
Attributes[Plot]
{HoldAll, Protected}
```

Comment: @Szabolcs, I think I should transfer half my reputation, since you make my terse posts actually readable. Thanks once more.

Answer (score 5):

Indeed the cause is the evaluation order resulting from the `HoldAll` attribute of `Plot`.  Here are several ways to get around this:

```
domain := {n, 0, 10};

Plot[n, Evaluate[domain]]

Plot[n, #] & @ domain

With[{d = domain}, Plot[n, d]]

{domain} /. {d__} :> Plot[n, d]
```

- I normally favor the method using `Function` (`&`) for its brevity.
- I think `With` can be the most easy to read in longer expressions.
- The last method is specialized and is helpful in [difficult operations](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/1929/121).

Answer (score 2):

Alternatively, I only define the range but not the iterator variable, as it is then outside of its scope (`n` in `Plot[f, {n, 0, 1}]` is local to `Plot`):

```
domain = {0, 10};
Plot[n, {n, First[domain], Last[domain]}]
```

or

```
domain = {0, 10};
Plot[n, Evaluate@{n, Sequence @@ domain}]
```