# Keep function range as a variable

Tags: programming, evaluation, syntax

`Plot[2*x^2 - x + 2, {x, -1, 1}]` plots a function of x from -1 to 1. As far as I can see, I cannot "save" this range in a variable:

```
u = {x, -1, 1};
Plot[2*x^2 - x + 2, u]
```

Generates `Plot::pllim: Range specification u is not of the form {x, xmin, xmax}.` Hopefully my intention is obvious, what is the most concise way of accomplishing it?

Because someone will wonder why I could possibly want to do this: I have

```
NDSolve[..., ..., {t, 0, 100}];
Plot[..., {t, 0, 100}];
```

I don't want to need to modify both 100's as my desired range changes. Yes, I could use variables t0 and t1, but is what type is the range/domain expression? Why can't I store it directly?

Comment: The reason why what you tried did not work is that Plot has [the HoldAll attribute](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/tutorial/NonStandardEvaluation.html) (this is to make it work even if `x` has a value).  Unfortunately I see no *convenient* way to get around this.  As MrW pointed it out, `Plot[..., Evaluate[u]]` is not robust: it won't work if `x` has a value.  Yes, this *is* annoying, and I'd also like a really *convenient* way to store these ranges.

Comment: How about: `With[{lims = Sequence[0, 100]},
 NDSolve[...,..., {x, ##}] &@lims;
 Plot[..., {x, ##}] &@lims
 ]`

Comment: Maybe I'm missing something, but it seems the key point is to save the *limits* $-1$ and $1$ in the variable `u` and that it wouldn't do any harm to re-specify the variable `x` explicitly in `Plot`. So why not `u={-1,1}; Plot[f[x], Evaluate@Prepend[u,x]]`? Or is it important that `x` be referenced within `u` itself? If so, why?

Comment: @Szabolcs Can you think of better tags for this question than **syntax**?

Comment: @Mr.Wizard I tried, please review.  I think this is also related to "macro expansion".  There were questions about that, but I can't find them now.  Maybe they were on SO.  This is really about *convenience*, making it easier to type code.  Maybe we should have a tag for things like that?

Comment: Closely related / Possible duplicate: http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/2414/121  (This question seems to be more about *how* whereas the linked question is about *why*.)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

#### Better methods

My original answer was pretty poor and I'll show you why.

Suppose `x` has a value assigned: `x = 7`.  This does not bother `Plot`:

```
Plot[2*x^2 - x + 2, {x, -1, 1}]  (* outputs graphic *)
```

It however *will* prevent my earlier suggestions from working:

```
Plot[2*x^2 - x + 2, Evaluate@u]
```

> During evaluation of In[23]:= Plot::itraw: Raw object 7 cannot be used as an iterator. >>
>
> ```
> Plot[2 x^2 - x + 2, {7, -1, 1}]
> ```

Instead you should store your range in a way that holds the plot parameter unevaluated:

```
u = Hold[{x, -1, 1}];
```

Then you need a way to put this inside the `Plot` expression without it evaluating.  This can be done with a `Function` and a hold attribute and `Apply`:

```
Function[spec, Plot[2*x^2 - x + 2, spec], HoldAll] @@ u  (* outputs graphic *)
```

Or more tersely with the ["injector pattern"](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/1937/121):

```
u /. _[spec_] :> Plot[2*x^2 - x + 2, spec]  (* outputs graphic *)
```

---

#### Old answer

You just need [`Evaluate`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Evaluate.html):

```
u = {x, -1, 1};

Plot[2*x^2 - x + 2, Evaluate @ u]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Or as I often prefer, `Function`:

```
Plot[2*x^2 - x + 2, #] & @ u
```

Comment: Hi @Mr.Wizard, I have a problem that could be related but doesn't seem to work for me. I would like the range limits to depend on some other function or list, something like: `Plot[Evaluate@Map[myFunc[x, #], {x, 0, rangeFunc[yValues]}&, yValues]]` where rangeFunc gives me a number for each y. Is it possible?

Comment: This is because the function myFunc is a 2D interpolation function, which extrapolates to zero outside specific ranges of x which depend on y.

Comment: @Santi I have trouble understanding what you want.  Would you please post a new question with examples of both the *input* and *output* that you want?

Comment: @Wizard ok thanks, the question is there with a small example.

Answer (score 5):

To take a more advanced approach in response to Szabolcs's comment, one can use `UpValues`.  I define a new kind of set function as follows:

```
SetAttributes[setSpec, HoldAllComplete]

setSpec[s_Symbol, spec__] := s /: h_[pre__, s, post___] := h[pre, spec, post]
```

Then make an assignment, and use it:

```
setSpec[u, {x, 0, 10}];

Plot[Sin[x], u, PlotStyle -> Red]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Or with more than one specification:

```
setSpec[v, {x, -3, 3}, {y, -3, 3}, StreamStyle -> "Pointer"]

StreamPlot[{-1 - x^2 + y, 1 + x - y^2}, v,
 PlotLabel -> s, 
 StreamScale -> {Full, All, 0.03}]
```

Answer (score 5):

I have a simple mind and like simple methods. In this case, I suggest using a [formal parameter](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/tutorial/LettersAndLetterLikeForms.html).

```
u = {\[FormalX], -1, 1};
```

The character `\[FormalX]` can be typed using the keystrokes [esc]$x]esc].

Using `\[FormalX]` rather than `x` is robust because `\[FormalX]` has the `Protected` attribute and can not be bound to a value.

```
\[FormalX] = 42; ValueQ@\[FormalX]
```

> Set::wrsym: Symbol `\[FormalX]` is Protected.
>
> False

With `u` defined as above, you can make your plot by evaluating

```
Plot[2*\[FormalX]^2 - \[FormalX] + 2, Evaluate@u]
```

or by evaluating

```
With[{u = u}, Plot[2*\[FormalX]^2 - \[FormalX] + 2, u]]
```

Should you dislike the extra typing needed to insert `\[FormalX]` or should you want the freedom to use a parameter name entirely of your own choosing, you can roll your own formal parameters.

```
SetAttributes[makeFormal, HoldFirst];
makeFormal[u_Symbol] := (Clear[u]; Protect[u];)

Unprotect@x;
x = 42;
makeFormal@x;
Print[Attributes[x]];
ValueQ@x
```

> {Protected}
>
> False

Now `x` will act just like `\[FormalX]`.

```
u = {x, -1, 1};
Plot[2*x^2 - x + 2, Evaluate@u]
```

The above is now safe because x can no longer take a value.