# Reuse ParametricPlot3D plotting options

Tags: plotting, options

I create several ParametricPlot3D's that all should look the same: `BoundaryStyle -> Thick`, `AxesEdge -> {{-1, -1}, {-1, -1}, {-1, -1}}`, `Boxed -> False`, etc. To ensure consistency and make changing the options easier, I would like to specify them only once.

From what I've understood, it's possible to change the default options of ParametricPlot3D permanently by using `SetOptions`. I don't particularly like this solution, because it would affect the appearance of all ParametricPlot3Ds.

Alternatively, I tried using

```
para := {BoundaryStyle -> Thick, AxesEdge -> {{-1, -1}, {-1, -1}, {-1, -1}},
         Boxed -> False}
Show[ParametricPlot3D[{u, v, 0}, {u, 0, 1}, {v, 0, 1}], para]
```

but here MMA complains

> An unrecognized option name ("BoundaryStyle") was encountered while
>   reading a Graphics.

This is the original code for one ParametricPlot3D:

```
ParametricPlot3D[{u, v, 0}, {u, 0, 1}, {v, 0, 1},  
 BoundaryStyle -> Thick, AxesEdge -> {{-1, -1}, {-1, -1}, {-1, -1}}, 
 Boxed -> False]
```

Any suggestion is much appreciated.

Comment: Instead of `para := {...}` use `para = Sequence[...]`, then do `ParamatricPlot3D[..., para]` and drop `Show`.

Comment: @Szabolcs: I get 'ParametricPlot3D::nonopt: "Options expected (instead of para) beyond position 3 in ParametricPlot3D[{u,v,0},{u,0,1},{v,0,1},para]. An option must be a rule or a list of rules."'

Comment: You can use `FilterRules`: `Sequence@@FilterRules[para, Options[ParametricPlot3D]]`

Comment: I am marking this as a duplicate because both the cause and solutions are the same.

Comment: Also see this: http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/22702/121

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can define

```
para = Sequence[BoundaryStyle -> Thick, AxesEdge -> {{-1, -1}, {-1, -1}, {-1, -1}}, Boxed -> False]
```

then use

```
ParametricPlot3D[{u, v, 0}, {u, 0, 1}, {v, 0, 1}, Evaluate[para]]
```

---

Explanation:

`Sequence` will automatically expand inside of an expression.

```
In[]:= {1, Sequence[2,3]}
Out[]= {1, 2, 3}
```

`Graphics` does accept options given as a list (`Graphics[{Circle[]}, {Axes -> False, Frame -> True}]`), but many other functions won't.  So we need to use `Sequence`.

`BoundaryStyle` is an option for `ParametricPlot3D`, but not for `Graphics`, therefore it can't be given in `Show`.  So we have to pass the options to `ParametricPlot3D` directly.

`ParametricPlot3D` has the `HoldAll` attribute, which means that `para` needed to be wrapped in `Evaluate` to make sure that `ParametricPlot3D` will see the actual options and not the symbol `para`.