# Change some option of a function when calling it

Tags: functions, function-construction, optional-arguments

Say I have defined some function like

```
f[p_] := Plot[Sin[p*x], {x, 0, 2 Pi}]
```

Now in most cases, I just need to specify the value of `p` and retrieve the plot. In a very few cases, I also want to change some option of the plot, e.g. `ImageSize -> Large`.

Since my function in reality is a lot more convoluted and already has various optional arguments, I am trying to avoid a solution like

```
f[p_, size_:Automatic] := Plot[Sin[p*x], {x, 0, 2 Pi}, ImageSize->size]
```

I have tried e.g.

```
f[*some value*] /. ImageSize -> Large
```

but to no avail. Is there any way to achieve what I am attempting? Apologies if I am missing some fundamental features of Mathematica...

Comment: I think that a general solution applicable to your situation is to create *persistent option configurations*, for example by using a mechanism I described [here](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/22697/custom-functions-by-delegating-options-in-a-specific-way-and-using-core-function/22702#22702).

Comment: Why not `Show[f[1],ImageSize-> 600]` ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use functions with [optional arguments](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/tutorial/SettingUpFunctionsWithOptionalArguments.html)

For example:

```
ClearAll@f;
Options[f] = Options[Plot];

f[p_, opt : OptionsPattern[]] := Plot[Sin[p*x], {x, 0, 2 Pi}, opt]

f[3]
```

[image: default]

```
f[3, PlotStyle -> {Red, Thick}, ImageSize -> Small]
```

[image: Options passed]

For completeness sake: you can define your function to accept other options (not just those of `Plot`). In that case you can use `FilterRules`.

Comment: Thanks, but as mentioned in my question, the function already has a few optional arguments so I am trying to avoid adding another one which I'd use only once - since at some point it gets confusing which option actually IS used in a specific case (take `f[x_, opt1_:, opt2_:, opt_3]:=...` and the use `f[1, *some specification*]`).

Comment: @Bernd see edit. I would concatenate all your optional parameters to Options. If you elaborate your example I can show you how I  would solve it.

Comment: I'm sorry, I didn't realise the difference between an optional argument (`opt_:`) and your use of `OptionsPattern` (`opt:`), which I hadn't known of. That should do the trick, thanks!

Comment: @Bernd You're welcome:)

Answer (score 1):

A simpler form of Ajasja's idea can be used:

```
f[p_, opt : ___] := Plot[Sin[p*x], {x, 0, 2 Pi}, opt]

f[3, PlotStyle -> {Red, Thick}, ImageSize -> Small]
```

[image]

Comment: This is similar to how old-style options handling used to be done. But it has several drawbacks: You can't get a list of all excepted options of `f`, it matches everything, not just a sequence of rules, you can't use `OptionValue[]`. Of course for this particular purpose it might suffice.

Comment: yes, you are right, thanks for your explanation.