# How can I define a function taking two distinguishable sets of options?

Tags: functions, function-construction, options, optional-arguments

It commonly happens that one wants to define some function `foo` which in turn calls some other function (e.g., `Plot`) that can take a vast variety of optional arguments, and one would like to arrange things so that the caller of `foo` can pass optional parameters intended for the second function (e.g., `Plot`) among the arguments to `foo`.  The latter is expected to simply pass those arguments right through.  The pattern for doing this, according to the documentation, is something like:

```
foo[x_, y_, z_, opts:OptionsPattern[]] := 
   Plot[..., Evaluate[FilterRules[{opts}, Options[Plot]]]]
```

But now suppose that `foo` in fact makes *two* calls to `Plot` (for example), and that one wants to provide the caller the opportunity to pass separate sets of optional parameters for the two calls to `Plot`.  (In general, these two parameter sets would differ.)

How can one retool `foo` so that it can accept 2 sets of optional parameters?  Also, how would one actually *invoke* the function thus defined, with two different, non-empty sets of optional parameters?

Comment: Why not use `"Plot1" -> {options to first plot}` and `"Plot2" -> {options to second plot}` as the options for `foo`? Then you can just do `Plot[..., OptionValue["Plot1"]]` (use `FilterRules` if you must... I leave it out for functions that only I'll be using).

Comment: @rm-rf http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=iZs-e_x0PGM

Comment: kjo, I added an answer with an example.  If this does not satisfy please tell me why and I shall try again.  I left out the `FilterRules` part to keep things simple and because I'm not sure how you would intend to use that with separate option sections anyway.

Comment: Seems to be a duplicate of [this](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/22697/custom-functions-by-delegating-options-in-a-specific-way-and-using-core-function/). At least,my answer there describes what I would personally do in this case.

Comment: @rm-rf: I'm having a hard time understanding your suggestion; if you wouldn't mind posting a more explicit example I'd appreciate it.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard: your solution did the job, thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I propose using two separate `OptionsPattern[]` expressions, and placing the options for the second call in a list following the options for the first call (or anything else).

```
foo[x_, y_, z_, opts1 : OptionsPattern[], PatternSequence[] | {opts2 : OptionsPattern[]}] :=
 Grid[{{
    Plot[Sin[x a], {a, y, z}, opts1],
    Plot[Cos[x a], {a, y, z}, opts2]
 }}]

foo[3.7, 0, 2 Pi]
foo[3.7, 0, 2 Pi, Ticks -> False]
foo[3.7, 0, 2 Pi, {PlotStyle -> Red}]
foo[3.7, 0, 2 Pi, Ticks -> False, {PlotStyle -> Red}]
```

[image]