# How to disable differential styles/markers/etc. for multiple entities?

Tags: plotting, graphics, options

For functions that can produce multiple "style-able" entities, *Mathematica* by default will give each such entity a different style.  Similar conventions apply to other features, either by default, or when `Automatic` is specified as their setting.  For example, in `ListPlot`, if multiple curves are being displayed, then specifying`PlotMarker->Automatic` results in a different choice of plot marker for each curve.

Very often I want to disable this behavior.  E.g., I want *all* the curves produced by a single call to a plotting function to be shown with the same style, same plot marker, etc.

How can I do this?

NOTE that what I want to do *is not the same thing* as setting an *explicit* style, plot marker, etc., to be applied to all the entities.  I specifically want to *avoid* having to choose some style, plot marker, etc!  I just want Mathematica to use the same *default* style, plot marker, etc. (*whatever those are*) for all entities.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

#### Sequence trick

*Update: in recent versions `Sequence` is specifically handled meaning it cannot be used for this "trick" -- however the mechanism is still valid and alternatives can be used.*

As detailed in [Plot draws list of curves in same color when not using Evaluate](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/1731/plot-draws-list-of-curves-in-same-color-when-not-using-evaluate/1735#1735)
 if items are initially contained in a Head besides `List` they are seen as one expression by the style mechanism; if that head later vanishes, allowing it to plot normally, the style remains.

```
Plot[{1, ## &[2, 3], 4}, {x, 0, 1},
  PlotRange -> {0, 5},
  PlotStyle -> Thick
]
```

[image]

I illustrated grouping two lines into the same style to show the flexibility of this method but you could just as easily group all the lines as one:

```
Plot[{## &[1, 2, 3, 4]}, {x, 0, 1},
  PlotRange -> {0, 5},
  PlotStyle -> Thick
]
```

[image]

I don't know how many other plot types this applies to but it does include `ParametricPlot`:

```
ParametricPlot[
 {{2 Cos[t], 2 Sin[t]}, 
  ## &[{2 Cos[t], Sin[t]}, {Cos[t], 2 Sin[t]}],
  {Cos[t], Sin[t]}},
 {t, 0, 2 Pi},
 PlotStyle -> Thick
]
```

[image]

---

#### Option selector

I suspect your aversion to specifying a `PlotStyle` has to do with remembering the default values for the different plot types.  If this is the case I suggest that you use a method to fill in these values automatically.  For each individual plot type you could define behavior for using `PlotStyle -> "Uniform"` as I did for `FillingStyle -> "Match"` [(S.O.8569242)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8569242/618728).  Or you could use a framework such as the one Leonid laid out in [(22697)](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/22697/custom-functions-by-delegating-options-in-a-specific-way-and-using-core-function/22702#22702), but I believe you will still have to deal with multiple configurations because e.g. setting `PlotMarkers` for `ListPlot` will cause all plots to have plot markers (by default) when they did not before.

An alternative to an option selector would be to craft a function that works with the output of each type of plot function to remove styling after-the-fact.  This is probably a less ideal way to go but it may still have application.

Here is a working implementation of the first proposed method (from my Stack Overflow post):

```
Unprotect[Plot, ListPlot, ListLinePlot];

(#[a__, b : OptionsPattern[]] := 
     Block[{$psUni = True}, 
        With[{val = ColorData[1, 1]}, #[a, PlotStyle -> val, b]]] /; ! TrueQ[$psUni] /; 
      OptionValue[PlotStyle] === "Uniform") & /@ {Plot, ListPlot, ListLinePlot};
(#[a__, b : OptionsPattern[]] := 
     Block[{$pmUni = True}, 
        With[{val = System`Private`$PlotMarkers[[1]]}, #[a, PlotMarkers -> val, b]]] /; ! 
        TrueQ[$pmUni] /; OptionValue[PlotMarkers] === "Uniform") & /@ {ListPlot, 
   ListLinePlot};
```

Now:

```
data = Table[{k, PDF[BinomialDistribution[50, p], k]}, {p, {0.3, 0.5, 0.8}}, {k, 0, 50}];
ListLinePlot[data, PlotStyle -> "Uniform", PlotMarkers -> "Uniform"]
```

[image]

Comment: That's really nice trick! +1 ;)

Comment: @Kuba Thank you. :-)

Comment: It is one of those "so obvious when you know them" tricks :)

Comment: @Kuba I don't think it's obvious at all.  I had to ask [my own question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/5605635/618728) about it.

Comment: Oh, I've thought I understand this behaviour intuitevly but after reading this topic I have to agree with you. Nontheless, good to know that.

Comment: This doesn't seem to work in Mathematica 10. Do you know of another way?

Comment: @mrc In 10.0.2 you can use `{1, ## &[2, 3], 4}` however it was reported to me that this does not work in 10.1.0, but I am not using that version yet so I cannot look for alternatives.

Answer (score 4):

Your question is rather broad. I don't know an answer that I'm confident will work for any '"style-able" entities', but mapping a plot expression over the entities you want to plot and using `Show` will work for some cases.

```
data = Table[Sin[k x], {k, 3}, {x, 0, 2 Pi, 0.1}];
ListPlot[data, Joined -> True, PlotMarkers -> {Automatic, 7}]
```

[image: plot.1.png]

```
Show[
  ListPlot[#, Joined -> True, PlotMarkers -> {Automatic, 7}] & /@ data]
```

[image: plot.2.png]

#### Edit

In my example above, each of the three plots naturally have the same plot range, but as Mr.Wizard points out, this is not always the case. Since `Show`, given no other instructions, will use the plot range of the first curve, something might have to be done to override the domination of the first curve.

```
data2 = Table[k Sin[k x], {k, 3}, {x, 0, 2 Pi, 0.1}];
Show[ListPlot[#, Joined -> True, PlotMarkers -> {Automatic, 7}] & /@ data2]
```

[image: plot.3.png]

```
Show[
  ListPlot[#, Joined -> True, PlotMarkers -> {Automatic, 7}] & /@ data2, 
    PlotRange -> All]
```

[image: plot.4.png]

Comment: Oops.  Thanks for catching my mistake.  Seeing nested `Table` for the third time was making me crazy. :-p

Answer (score 1):

In `Plot`-like functions you can always style all the curves and points identically by specifying the `PlotStyle` option in a non-`List` form (for example, `PlotStyle -> Blue` or `PlotStyle -> Directive[Blue, PointSize[Medium]]`) or equivalently as a `List` with only one element: `PlotStyle -> {style}`:

```
data = Table[{x, Sin[k x]}, {k, 3}, {x, 0, 2 Pi, 0.1}];

ListLinePlot[data, Mesh -> All, 
 PlotStyle -> Directive[Blue, PointSize[Medium]]]
```

The following is a low-level solution which does not rely on high-level functions and guarantees exact positioning of the graphics primitives:

```
Graphics[{Blue, Line@#1, PointSize[Medium], Point@#1} & /@ data, 
 Axes -> True, AspectRatio -> 1/GoldenRatio]
```

[image: plot]