# Failing to get colours in Plot

Tags: plotting

When I plot the functions generated by `NestList`, I do not see differently coloured lines, which I do if I explicitly list them out.

I.e. with:

```
map[ x_, α_] := x^2 - α
```

the first `Plot` is monochrome (blue), the second one multicolour as expected:

```
Plot[NestList[map[#, 2] &, x, 5], {x, 0, 1}]
```

> [image: Mathematica graphics]

```
Plot[{x, Nest[map[#, 2] &, x, 1], Nest[map[#, 2] &, x, 2], 
  Nest[map[#, 2] &, x, 3], Nest[map[#, 2] &, x, 4], 
  Nest[map[#, 2] &, x, 5]}, {x, 0, 1}]
```

> [image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: Previously (possible duplicate): [Difference in Plot when using Evaluate vs when not using Evaluate](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/1731/484)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Arguments that are grouped together are styled the same. Because `Plot` has the attribute `HoldAll` the `NestList` is not evaluated so initially the number of arguments is counted as being just one. If you evaluate the argument on the other hand `Plot` sees four arguments. `Plot` uses one style for each argument it can "see". A simpler and instructive case of this is Mr.Wizard's [sequence trick](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/31891/731). For even more information about how this works you can read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5605635/detection-and-styling-of-multiple-functions-in-mathematicas-plot) Q&A.

```
map[ x_, α_] := x^2 - α
Plot[NestList[map[#, 2] &, x, 5], {x, 0, 1}]
```

> [image]

```
Plot[Evaluate@NestList[map[#, 2] &, x, 5], {x, 0, 1}]
(* or *)
Plot[NestList[map[#, 2] &, x, 5], {x, 0, 1}, Evaluated -> True]
```

> [image]