# InstallR on OS X with external R installation on 10.0.1.0

Tags: mac-os-x, rlink

I had no problem to follow the instructions given at [InstallR on OS X with external R installation](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/43731/installr-on-os-x-with-external-r-installation) to get an external R working with Mathematica 10.0.0.0.  However when Mathematica was updated to 10.0.1.0, an error msg came out.

The commands that I issued were:

```
Needs["RLink`"]
SetEnvironment["DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH" -> "/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Resources/lib"];
InstallR["RHomeLocation" -> "/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Resources"];
```

The error msg is

> InstallR::rundetctd: "Failed to detect the R version from the specified path to R home directory. Try using the "RVersion" option to specify the R version explicitly"

I have checked InstallR options and did not find "RVersion" there.   Am I missing something?

Many thanks

Comment: This might be a bug (or, rather, the defaults not set quite right). What version of external R do you use? Generally, you can fix this by providing it explicitly, as indicated in the error message: try adding an explicit option `"RVersion" -> "R-3.1.0"`, for example.

Comment: Yes, I forgot to mention, that "RVersion" option has not yet been documented (but neither has the use of RLink with external R on Mac OS X :)).

Comment: @Leonid Shifrin - Many thanks for the reply.  I am running R version 3.1.  /Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Version shows that I have a dir called 3.1, 3.0 and Current. When I issue the command InstallR["RHomeLocation"->"/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Resources","RVersion"->"3.1"] the same error msg comes out.  "RVersion" -> "R-3.1.0" sends the same msg too.  Any thoughts?

Comment: I'll have to check this. Will get back when I'm done, perhaps one or two days. We did check this before release, and it worked. So, I'll have to look closer and reproduce this. In the mean time, out of curiosity, try "RVersion"->"3.1.1" - which is what we used. If it works, please ping me here (it anyway looks like a bug, but it would be easier to localize). Thanks.

Comment: @Leonid Shifrin.  Many many thanks.   The output of InstallR with 3.1.1 is InstallR::fail: Failed to install R. The following error was encountered: Unable to load dynamic libraries >>.  The error mgs is different!  I must be doing something wrong.

Comment: Unfortunately, this will have to wait for a bit, can't spend any time on this probably until the weekend. Are you able to fall back to using 10.0.0 for your work with RLink, for the time being?

Comment: @Leonid Shifrin.  Many thanks.  I can wait so don't worry.

Comment: @LeonidShifrin for the record, after this release RLink works for me with the explicit "RVersion"->"3.1.1" option :)

Answer (score 2):

Here are the commands I used, which worked for me (of course, I am using R version 3.1.1):

```
Needs["RLink`"]

SetEnvironment[
  "DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH" -> 
   "/Library/Frameworks/R.Framework/Resources/lib"];

InstallR["RHomeLocation" -> 
   "/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Resources", 
   "RVersion" -> "R-3.1.1"];

REvaluate["R.version.string"]
```

Comment: changed R.Framework to R.framework in first reference above. Tested with OS X version of R v 3.3.1 and Mathematica 11.0, worked successfully. Thx!

Comment: My above comment was for my installation on OS X version 10.10.5 . For installing on OS X version 10.11.6 I used the patch here: http://szhorvat.net/pelican/setting-up-rlink-for-mathematica.html with the small change I noted that seems necessary for Mathematica 11.0

Answer (score 2):

I wrote a guide on using external R installations on various operating systems with various Mathematica versions.  I intend to keep this up to date.

- [Setting up RLink for Mathematica](http://szhorvat.net/pelican/setting-up-rlink-for-mathematica.html)

This is accompanied by [a small package](http://szhorvat.net/pelican/setting-up-rlink-for-mathematica.html#automating-these-steps) that automates using an external R.

---

As others mentioned, in your case all is needed is adding the option `"RVersion" -> 3` to `InstallR`.

Comment: Thanks for this -- in particular, it solved my "Unable to load dynamic libraries" error under OSX El Capitan.