# SetOptions does not give expected result with Grid

Tags: plotting, options

Chech this example:

```
SetOptions[Plot,ImagePadding -> {{50, 30}, {Automatic, Automatic}}];    
Options[Plot, ImagePadding]    
 (*{ImagePadding -> {{50, 30}, {Automatic, Automatic}}}*)
SetOptions[Grid, Dividers -> All, Alignment -> Left];
Options[Grid, {Alignment, Dividers}]
 (*{Alignment -> Left, Dividers -> All}*)
Grid[{{Plot[{Sin[x], Cos[x]}, {x, 0, 2}, 
 PlotLegends -> "Expressions"]}, {Plot[Exp[x], {x, 0, 10}]}}]
```

[image]

However this works fine:

```
Grid[{{Plot[{Sin[x], Cos[x]}, {x, 0, 2}, 
  PlotLegends -> "Expressions"]}, {Plot[Exp[x], {x, 0, 10}]}}, 
  Alignment -> Left, Dividers -> All]
```

Any idea why and any solutions?

Thanks

Comment: Recently, I have become of opinion that `SetOptions` should in fact never be used, because it redefines the option values in a global way (which means that two different applications using it may easily conflict with each other without knowing it). You can pass options locally, and it should always work and is much safer. I have discussed a solution that would emulate stateful option changes (and make this convenient), while still passing them locally, [here](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/22702) and [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/7197903).

Comment: @LeonidShifrin Setting Options globally sometimes is helpful. in me case, I have a big code where Grid is used every where and it is going to be pain to add same option to each Grid function. I did not get your point when you said "two different applications use it may easily conflict" . isn't the option when set globally is going to be attached to the needed function? so what is harm with that. As long as the function accept the option in local base with any argument it should not matter to set it globally

Comment: In my post I linked to, I gave a solution that would have almost the same convenience as `SetOptions`, in terms of  setting it once and then just using it, while would be much safer and also would always work (`SetOptions` is known to not work properly on some functions). Re: app conflict - well, imagine two apps which are used intermittently and both set some option to the same built-in function, but in a different way. Then, unless they call `SetOptions` in every function they provide, chances are that at least one such app will not work properly.