# Forcing unifom axis scaling on a list plot

Tags: plotting

I'm trying to draw a `ListPlot` where the x and y axis have the same scale.

My data is

```
{{100, 500}, {461/5, 473}, {548/5, 452}, {1459/10, 437}, {974/5, 428}, {250, 425}, 
 {1526/5, 428}, {3541/10, 437}, {1952/5, 452}, {2039/5, 473}, {400, 500}}
```

A simple `ListPlot` will result in:

[image: Listplot no scale]

where the x and y axis have a different scales.

I want them to force them to have the same scale. So far I've been able to achieve this only by explicitly setting `PlotRange` to the same value for x and y, and using `AspectRation->1`.

Example:

```
range := {Min[Flatten[x]], Max[Flatten[x]]}
ListPlot[x, PlotRange -> {range, range}, AspectRatio -> 1]
```

The result is:

[image: List plot scaled]

Questions:

- Is there a `Plot` option to force the scale to be uniform? Do I always have to set the same range and `AspectRatio` to 1?
- From the second image there is satisfying y ∈ [400, 500] and x < 100 with an x value that is lying outside of the drawing range. I thought by using the `Min` of all x and y this could not happen. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: `AspectRatio -> Automatic`. `PlotRange` in form `{min, max}` applies only to `y` axis. The `x` is `Automatic`, that's why the point is missing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I know there is no other way besides setting the Options you describe, but there are many ways to make setting those Options more convenient.  You can use [`SetOptions`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/SetOptions.html) on `ListPlot` to make them the defaults, or you can use methods such as those shown here:

- [Consistent Plot Styles across multiple MMA files and data sets](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/3247/121)
- [Keep function range as a variable](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/20718/121)
- [Custom functions by delegating options in a specific way and using core functions](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/22697/121)

Regarding the **BONUS**: you must also set the [`AxesOrigin`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/AxesOrigin.html):

```
ListPlot[x,
 PlotRange -> {range, range},
 AspectRatio -> 1,
 AxesOrigin -> range[[1]]
]
```

[image]

Comment: `ListPlot[x, PlotRange -> All, AspectRatio -> Automatic]`

Comment: @Kuba I don't think that's what the OP wants, at least as I read the question.

Comment: I see, I think it is, but my interpretations "sometimes" fail. The range used by OP is equal for both axes only to make aspectratio->1 work, that's what I think.

Comment: @Kuba In retrospect I can see that interpretation now too, and I think you are probably correct.  Alas, wasted effort.  But I'll wait for the OP to confirm before I Close.

Comment: Thanks for the answers. I don't specifically need the same range, I was just trying to have the same scale on the x and y axis. It seems that Kuba's first comment to this answer does the trick, although at a first glance it might not seem so, as the ticks on the y have a different resolution than the ticks on the x.