# Plot range of a 2-dimensional function as a function depending on one variable

Tags: plotting, map

I want to plot a function of 2 variables x and y, for discrete values of y, like:

```
myFunc[x_, y_] := Sin[x y]
yvalues={0.1,0.5,1.0,2.0}
Plot[Evaluate@Map[myFunc[x, #] &, yvalues], {x, 0, 5}]
```

What I want is that the maximum x range (in this case 5) is a function of yvalues, for example, for each value i of yvalues, stop the corresponding plot curve at `Cos[yvalues[[i]]]`.

I need this because in my real case, the function to plot is a 2D interpolation which behaves badly outside some specific intervals depending on y.

Thanks.

Comment: You can add any of `If`, `Piecewise`, `Boole` and more to your definition of `myFunc`.

Comment: @b.gatessucks thanks, but it is not possible, since in real life, myFunc is an interpolation function

Comment: It should be related to something like this answer http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/20719/6138

Comment: Can't you do simply a table? `Table[Plot[Sin[x i], {x, 0, i}], {i, 1, 5}] // 
 Show[#, PlotRange -> All] &`

Comment: otherwise something like this? `tt = {Sin[x], Cos[x], Cos[2 x]}; gg = {{0, 1}, {0, 2}, {0, 3}};
MapThread[Plot[#1, Evaluate@{x, Sequence @@ #2}] &, {tt, gg}]//Show`

Comment: or `gg = {Table[{x, Sin[x]}, {x, 0, 10}] // Interpolation,
  Table[{x, Cos[x]}, {x, 0, 20}] // Interpolation}; Plot[#[x], {x, #[[1, 1, 1]], #[[1, 1, 2]]}] & /@
  gg // Show`

Comment: @chris maybe it works, let me check. Anyway with your little example I get the same color for each curve, even if I use `Evaluated->True` or `Evaluate`

Comment: then this `Table[Plot[Sin[x i], {x, 0, 5 + i}, 
   PlotStyle -> ColorData[10][i]], {i, 1, 3}] // 
 Show[#, PlotRange -> All] &` which is basically the same as eldo

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Another method with a single plot:

```
ClearAll[myFunc2];
yvalues = {0.1`, 0.5`, 1.`, 2.`, 3.`};

myFunc2[x_?NumericQ, y_?NumericQ] := 
       ConditionalExpression[Sin[x y], IntervalMemberQ[Interval[{0, Cos[y]}], x]];
{min, max} = Through[{Min, Max}[Cos[yvalues]]];

Plot[myFunc2[x, #] & /@ yvalues, {x, min, max}, Evaluated -> True, BaseStyle -> Thick,
       ImageSize -> 600,  PlotLegends -> "Expressions"] /. myFunc2[a_, b_] :> Sin[ a b]
```

[image]

Edit: Another alternative is to use

```
myFunc3[x_, y_] :=  ConditionalExpression[Sin[x y], Min[0, Cos[y]] <= x <= Max[0, Cos[y]]];
```

instead of `myFunc2`.

Comment: thanks, that's a nice solution. I still have to understand how this thing with `ConditionalExpression` and `IntervalMemberQ` work.

Comment: @Santi This is pretty much what I did but using alternative functions.  I chose `If` because it's terse and as just about everyone here knows I like that.  `IntervalMemberQ` takes the place of `Cos[#] <= x <= 0 || 0 <= x <= Cos[#]` in mine.

Answer (score 5):

A method using a single `Plot` expression:

```
myFunc[x_, y_] := Sin[x y]
yvalues = {0.1, 0.5, 1.0, 2.0, 3.0};

Block[{x},
 Plot[#, {x, -5, 5}, PlotRange -> All, PlotLegends -> Automatic] &[
  If[Cos[#] <= x <= 0 || 0 <= x <= Cos[#], myFunc[x, #]] & /@ yvalues
 ]
]
```

[image]

Notes:

- I use `Block` to keep `x` localized.
- I did not programmatically determine the range of the plot; I merely used `-5, 5` and let `PlotRange -> All` clip the result.  It would be better (but less clean) to determine the bounds from `yvalues`.  I did not because I did not want to obscure this method.  If desired I can add that however.

Comment: thanks, looks good and the clipping with PlotRange would suit my needs I think. If you want you can post the better method, so I can learn something.

Comment: @Santi You're welcome.  kguler already posted the calculated bounds method in his answer so I won't duplicate that.

Answer (score 3):

Is something like this your intention?

```
myFunc[x_, y_] := Sin[x y]

yvalues = {0.1, 0.5, 1.0, 2.0, 3.0};

fun = Map[myFunc[x, #] &, yvalues];

lim = Table[Cos[yvalues[[i]]], {i, 1, 5}];

plot =
 Table[Plot[fun[[j]], {x, 0, lim[[j]]},
   PlotStyle -> {Red, Green, Blue, Orange, Brown}[[j]]], {j, 1, 5}]

Show[plot, PlotRange -> All]
```

[image]

Comment: yes thanks! I think that would do it. I never thought of using Show, I supposed there was a way to do it inside one single Plot, but this works for me!

Answer (score 3):

If eldo's plot is your desired outcome you could also do:

```
Show[Plot[Sin[x #], {x, 0, Cos@#}, PlotStyle -> Hue[RandomReal[]]] & /@
   yvalues, PlotRange-> All]
```

[image]

Noting  Cos[2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uryUO.png) and Cos[3] are negative.

If you want legends:

```
With[{col = Hue /@ RandomReal[{0, 1}, 5]},
 Legended[
  Show[MapThread[
    Plot[Sin[x #1], {x, 0, Cos@#1}, PlotStyle -> #2] &, {yvalues, 
     col}], PlotRange -> All], 
  LineLegend[col, Sin[# x] & /@ yvalues]]]
```

[image]

Comment: thanks! Legends are a very important point!