# Graphics options defined as a set

Tags: plotting, graphics, formatting, options, display

I need to use almost the same options for several graphics, and would like to simplify the code which is becoming pretty large.  The example below should work, but it doesn't for a reason I don't see.

```
GraphOptions[p1_, p2_, p3_, p4_, p5_, p6_, p7_, p8_] := Sequence[
    PerformanceGoal -> "Quality",
    PlotRange -> {{p1, p2}, {p3, p4}},
    PlotRangeClipping -> True,
    AspectRatio -> 1,
    Frame -> True,
    Axes -> True,
    AxesOrigin -> {0, p5},
    AxesStyle -> GrayLevel[0.6],
    LabelStyle -> Directive[FontSize -> 12],
    FrameLabel -> {
        Style[p6, FontSize -> 14],
        Style[p7, FontSize -> 14],
        Style[p8, Bold, FontSize -> 16, FontFamily -> "Helvetica"]
    },
    RotateLabel -> False,
    GridLines -> Automatic,
    GridLinesStyle -> Directive[GrayLevel[0.7], Dashed],
    ImageSize -> {512, 512}
]

Plot[t^2 - t, {t, -1, 1},
    GraphOptions[-4, 4, 0, 4, 1, u, v, "A simple title"]
]
```

Currently, *Mathematica* complains

> Options expected (instead of GraphOptions...). An option must be a rule or a list of rules.

So what's wrong with this code ?  I tried with **{ }** instead of **Sequence[ ]**, but I'm getting the same error message.

This is surrely pretty basic, but I don't see my mistake.

Comment: `Plot` is `HoldAll`, try with `Evaluate@GraphOptions`.

Comment: Why this ?  Is there a better way to define my **GraphOptions** function ?

Comment: Perhaps [defining your own `PlotTheme`](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/54545/is-it-possible-to-define-a-new-plottheme) is the way to go.

Comment: Why do you object to the need for prefixing your call to `GraphOptions` with `Evaluate @`?

Comment: @m_goldberg, I do not object to use it.  I was wondering if my settup could be done in another way (something more "natural" I'm unaware of ?).  Currently, the **Evaluate[ ]** works very well.

Comment: Related: [(2414)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/2414/121), [(3247)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/3247/121), [(20718)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/20718/121), [(22697)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/22697/121), [(38827)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/38827/121)

Comment: Just a silly question :  I prefer to write **Evaluate[...]** instead of **Evaluate@...**.  I think that my code is a bit easier to read and to understand with the first way, since my notation is more consistent on the whole code.  Is there any advantage in using the second way (i.e. using @) ?