# Why is Evaluate[] in Plot[] not necessary in some cases?

Tags: plotting, evaluation, hold

after reading some related materials([Why do I have to put Evaluate[] here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/6894/why-do-i-have-to-put-evaluate-here)), in my understanding, Because`Attributes[Plot]` has `HoldAll`, so `Plot[Evaluate[Table[a*x^2,{a,1,5}]],{x,-1,1}]` should have a Evaluate[] there, but when i remove Evaluate[] before Table[], correct picture still can be drawn. this confused me.

For detailed questions, plz see the comments in the image below. But I'd better write it again:

1. Why `Table[] & Plot[]` both have `HoldAll`, but `Table[]` must add `Evaluate[]` while `Plot[]` is no need to in this case?
2. Why outputs of `Plot[]` with `Evaluate[]` and without differs slightly?

[image]

[image]

---

code for tests:

```
(*case 1*)
Attributes[Table]

p={a,1,5};
Table[a*x,p] (*failed as i think*)
Table[a*x,Evaluate[p]] (*succeed as i think*)

(*case 2*)
Attributes[Plot]

q={x,-1,1}
Plot[x,q] (* no problem but why Evaluate[] before q is not neccessary? *)
Plot[Table[a*x,{a,1,3}],q] (* no problem but why Evaluate[] before Table[] is not neccessary? *)

Plot[Evaluate[Table[a*x,{a,1,3}]],q] 
(*Why here have a color difference while not in the before ?
What causes the slight difference in the output？*)
```

Comment: `HoldAll` prevents evaluation of arguments at the time of the function call.  What happens after that point is up to the function that is called.  It can evaluate its arguments if it wants to. `Plot[]` checks some of its arguments in particular ways, which have evolved over time. So do some of the other numerical solvers. The details are complicated and probably not fully known to non-developers.

Comment: `{x,2x,3x} // Plot[#, {x,-5,5}]&`  :)

Comment: Related: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/1731/plot-draws-list-of-curves-in-same-color-when-not-using-evaluate

Comment: A variation on @AsukaMinato comment, `Plot @@ {{x, 2 x, 3 x}, {x, -5, 5}}`

Comment: Please include the code text in your question so we can easily test.

Comment: And, if it was 10 years ago, you wouldn't have the first question: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/2414/1871 https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/20718/1871 Not sure when this feature is added, though. (It's not in _v9_, but already in _v12.3_. )

Comment: We can check that in v.13.2 in  `GeneralUtilities`PrintDefinitions@Plot` there is option  `Evaluated -> Automatic`. Instead of this Mr.Wizard has recommended `Evaluated -> True`.

Answer (score 11):

I thought this Q&A might be closed as too broad or needing input from WRI.  But it's still open with no close votes.  I suppose I can explain two things, which might provide the understanding why `Table` and `Plot` are different: (1) The purpose of `HoldAll` (in these functions) and (2) why what `Plot` does isn't needed in `Table` (in almost all cases).

#### The purpose of `HoldAll`

The purpose of `HoldAll` in `Table[]` and `Plot[]` is primarily to keep the symbolic expressions passed as arguments in their original forms, so that numerical definitions for the symbols in the expressions are not substituted.

For instance, without `HoldAll`:

```
foo[x^2, {x, 0, 2}]
(*  foo[x^2, {x, 0, 2}]  <-- good syntax for Plot/Table *)

(* BUT: *)
x = 3.4;
foo[x^2, {x, 0, 2}]
(*  foo[11.56, {3.4, 0, 2}]  <-- bad syntax for Plot/Table *)
```

In the case where `foo` is `Plot` or `Table`, the user does not usually want to worry about whether the variable they wish to use has been defined during their current session.  While the user could be required to clear the value of `x` before calling `Table[]` or `Plot[]`, this would be inconvenient. (Using `Block[{x}, Plot[...]]` instead of `Clear[x]` is still quite inconvenient.)  So `Table[]` and `Plot[]` have been programmed to do this automatically for the user without destroying any value(s) that might be assigned to `x`.

#### Why `Plot[]` differs from `Table[]`

The answer centers on when to evaluate the first argument, the function(s) to be plotted or "tabled."  Many things can be handled by all the functions in Mathematica that control evaluation: `Evaluate`, `Unevaluated`. `HoldAll`, `HoldAllComplete`, etc.

In the case of `Table[]`, there is no common use case in which the first argument of `Table[]` needs to be evaluated before `Table[]` is normally ready to evaluate it.  The most common case would probably :) be the use of random functions like `RandomReal[]`, which is discussed in the docs (e.g `Table[RandomReal[], {5}]` gives five different numbers while `Table[Evaluate@RandomReal[], {5}]` gives the same number five times.

`Plot[]` has evolved to handle various use-cases commonly encountered by users.  It's hard to remember all the changes over the years.  Now, `Plot[]` needs to evaluate the first argument both symbolically and numerically.  It analyzes the discontinuities of the function(s) before trying to numerically plot them.  It seems to distinguish a vector-valued function from a list of functions and handle these differently.  Perhaps to do this, it numerically evaluates the functions before starting to plot them.  It also seems to check both the unevaluated argument and the evaluated argument to distinguish these cases.  The details are hidden internally, and I cannot be precise about the decision algorithm.

These considerations point to three distinct times at which the `funcs` argument of `Plot[funcs, {x, 0, 1}]` might be evaluated:

1. Before the call to `Plot`, e.g. `Plot[Evaluate@funcs, {x, 0, 1}]`, which substitutes the value of `x` if any (usually a disaster): both the argument and the symbolic analysis is made on the value of `funcs` with `x` not blocked.
2. After the call to `Plot` but before symbolic analysis begins, e.g. `Plot[funcs, {x, 0, 1}, Evaluated -> True]`: both the argument and the symbolic analysis is made on the value of `funcs` but with the value of `x` blocked.
3. After the call and symbolic analysis, that is, what the normal call `Plot[funcs, {x, 0, 1}]` does: the argument is literally `funcs` and the symbolic analysis depends both on literal form of `funcs` and the value of `funcs` (with the value of `x` blocked).

*Examples:*
By "colored", I mean that `Plot` styles independent functions with different colors. By "uniform," I mean each curve has the same color.  If you have an old version of Mathematica, you may find that some plots that are colored in V13 are uniform in your version. (I cannot detail when the version changes occurred.)

```
Plot[{Sin[x], Cos[x]}, {x, 0, 10}] (* colored *)

funcs = {Sin[x], Cos[x]}; (* list of scalar function *)
Plot[funcs, {x, 0, 10}] (* colored *)

funcs2[] := {Sin[x], Cos[x]}; (* list of scalar function *)
Plot[funcs2[], {x, 0, 10}]    (* colored *)

funcs3[x_] := {Sin[x], Cos[x]}; (* vector-valued function *)
Plot[funcs3[x], {x, 0, 10}]     (* uniform *)
Plot[funcs3[x], {x, 0, 10}, Evaluated -> True] (* colored *)

funcs4[x_?NumericQ] := {Sin[x], Cos[x]};  (* vector-valued function *)
Plot[funcs4[x], {x, 0, 10}, Evaluated -> True] (* uniform *)
(*  colored pairs of uniformly colored vector components: *)
Plot[{funcs4[x], -funcs4[x]}, {x, 0, 10}, Evaluated -> True]
```

The last example might need further explanation. Because of `?NumericQ`, `funcs4[x]` evaluates to `funcs4[x]` if `x` is not numeric.  It numerically evaluates to a list of two real numbers.  So it is treated as a vector-valued function.  The plot argument, therefore, is a list of vector-valued functions. The first function gets one color, the second gets another color. The components of each function get the same color. This is undocumented, AFAIK, and these are my inferences from observed behavior.

As for the others, apparently: `funcs` and `funcs2[]` are examined and seen to be lists of functions. It is assumed these are lists of independent functions. In (surprising) contrast to `funcs2[]`, the argument `x` in `funcs3[x]` changes the analysis to decide it's a vector-valued function: the two components are colored the same because they come from the same function. If evaluated before symbolic analysis (with `Evaluate`), the form `Plot` sees is `{Cos[x], Sin[x]}`, which looks the same as the first example and is treated the same.