# How can I access the name of a variable inside a function?

Tags: functions, variable

How can I access the name of a variable inside a function?
For example I have variables
mike={some stuff}
jenny={other stuff}
and want to write a function f giving the following:
input>  f[mike]
output>  Mike: some stuff
input>  f[jenny]
output>  Jenny: other stuff
(I know how to capitalize the first letter.)

Comment: Duplicate of [this](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/15689/58370)

Comment: Thank you both for the hint. It works. Sorry for duplicate. My earlier research was not extensive enough. Many thanks.