# Convert defined variables to rule list

Tags: function-construction, evaluation, replacement

I'd like to make a function that takes a list of variables and returns a corresponding rule list with the current values of the variables.  E.g.

```
x = 1;
y = 2;
VariablesToRules[{x, y, z}]
(* {x -> 1, y -> 2, z -> z} *)
```

Is this even possible?

Comment: This is a super interesting question. [This post](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/15687/get-the-name-of-a-symbol-passed-to-a-function) is related, because you will need to get the symbol names in order to `Clear` them, but it's not clear how to short-circuit the evaluation when you will be feeding a *list* of variable names to the function rather than just the variable name.

Comment: Is `OwnValues /@ Unevaluated@{x, y, z}` OK?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Update 2**

Based on a suggestion by [Somos](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/61616/somos), the following version is nicer.  According to what the OP wants:

```
SetAttributes[variableToRule, {HoldAll, Listable}]
variableToRule[var_] := SymbolName@Unevaluated@var -> var
```

and according to my original interpretation of the problem:

```
SetAttributes[variableToRule, {HoldAll, Listable}]
variableToRule[var_] := Module[{val = var}, Clear@var; var -> val]
```

**Update 1**

After some comments from the OP, it seems they want instead something like

```
variableToRule[var_] := SymbolName@Unevaluated@var -> var
```

instead.

**Original Post**

Here's a first iteration. First define the helper function,

```
ClearAll@variableToRule
SetAttributes[variableToRule, HoldAll]
variableToRule[var_] := Module[{val = var}
 , Clear@var
 ; var -> val
 ]
```

Then, the function is

```
ClearAll@variablesToRules
SetAttributes[variablesToRules, HoldAll]
variablesToRules[vars_List] := variableToRule /@ Unevaluated@vars
```

This uses the trick from [this answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/15689/29734).

Then,

```
x = 1; y = 2; z = 3;
variablesToRules[{x, y, z}]
(* {x -> 1, y -> 2, z -> 3} *)
```

Comment: Thanks - any way to keep the variables' values afterwards?

Comment: @ChrisK. Your question confuses me. If you're making replacement rules, isn't the whole point that you will use them to replace the values of `x` and `y`, etc. in expressions that contain those variables? In that place, you don't want `x` and `y` set before-hand. What is it that you are trying to do here? Is this just for display purposes or something? If you keep the variables set, then you will get `{1 -> 1, 2 -> 2}`.

Comment: I think the trick from your link works: `variableToRule[var_] := SymbolName[Unevaluated@var] -> var` seems OK

Comment: But then, what is the point of the replacement rule? Because that won't actually work as a replacement rule, because you have the symbol *name* (which is a string), instead of the symbol itself.

Comment: It's a bit hard to explain, but I've got an inner function that takes a list of rules as an argument, which needs to be defined in an outer function where the variables are already defined.  Anyhow I think I'm sorted now.  Thanks!

Comment: Obviously I don't necessarily have enough info, but can't you scope the inner function using `Block` or something?

Comment: Perhaps, but `SymbolName[Unevaluated[]]` is an easy enough solution for me!

Comment: A slight improvement is the code `SetAttributes[variableToRule, {HoldAll, Listable}]` and `variableToRule[var_Symbol] := SymbolName@Unevaluated@var -> var` and `variableToRule[var___] := variableToRule[List@var]`

Comment: @Somos. Yes, I definitely like that better, although since the OP explicitly asked for feeding a *list* to the function, I think `variableToRule[var_List] := variableToRule @ var` makes that work.

Comment: Using attribute `Listable` is a general way to make it work also.

Comment: @Somos. Yeah, I just figured that out!  I'm editing my post with your suggestions.

Answer (score 4):

Pass in the names of the symbols as strings, and the rest is quite easy:

```
ClearAll[varsToRules];
varsToRules[s_] := With[{t = Map[Symbol, s]},
    s // Apply[ClearAll];
    MapThread[Rule, {Symbol /@ s, t}]
];

ClearAll[x, y];
{x, y, z} = {1, 2, 3};
varsToRules[{"x", "y", "z"}]
(* {x -> 1, y -> 2, z -> 3} *)
```

Comment: Thanks - any way to keep the variables' values afterwards?