# How to apply Set to held symbols listed in a variable?

Tags: evaluation, hold

I have a variable `states` that contains a list of held symbols:

```
states = Table[Hold@Evaluate@Unique[state], {2}]
(* {Hold[state$817], Hold[state$818]} *)
```

Initializing the valuse of these variables is not really a problem, I can do it as in

```
Evaluate@ReleaseHold@states[[1]] = Red
Evaluate@ReleaseHold@states[[2]] = Red
```

But I didn't manage to find a convenient way to replace the values of these symbols after the first initialization.
I tried a variety of things, including the [Trott-Strzebonski in-place evaluation technique](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/29318/27539).

I managed to make this *almost* work, but I still feel like I'm missing something.
If I for example try

```
states[[1]] /. s_Symbol :> RuleCondition[s = Green;];
```

the value of the variable is correctly reassigned, but I also get the error

```
Set::wrsym: Symbol Hold is Protected.
```

which I'm guessing arises from `Hold` itself matching the `s_Symbol` condition.
But if I try to make `Hold` not match with

```
states[[1]] /. s_Symbol?(Head@# =!= Hold &) :> RuleCondition[s = Green;];
```

the error does not go away.

What's the preferred way to handle this situation?

Comment: `Hold[var] /. Hold[s_] :> RuleCondition[s = Green;];`

Comment: Not sure why you want to use RuleCondition. Just: `states[[1]] /. Hold[s_] :> Set[s, Green]` should work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This general operation has been covered before, including:

- [Reassign values to symbols](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/280/121)
- [How to pass a symbol name to a function with any of the Hold attributes?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/2651/121)
- [Assigning values to a list of variable names](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/6511/121)
- [Elegant manipulation of the variables list](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/10322/121)

From my answer to the last question:

```
func_[bump[lst_, idx___], arg___] ^:= 
  func[#, arg] & @ Part[List @@@ Unevaluated @@ {lst}, {1}, idx]
```

Applied:

```
states = Join @@ Table[Hold@Evaluate@Unique[state], {3}]
```

> ```
> Hold[state$534, state$535, state$536]
> ```

```
bump[states, 1] = "red";
bump[states, {2, 3}] = {"green", "blue"};

List @@ states
```

> ```
> {"red", "green", "blue"}
> ```

```
bump[states, 2] = "black";

List @@ states
```

> ```
> {"red", "black", "blue"}
> ```

Please see that answer for more examples of use.

Comment: thanks, I somehow missed those references. My question is basically a duplicate of your first and fourth links