# How to inject an evaluated expression into a held expression?

Tags: evaluation, replacement, hold, insert

I know that there are methods to structurally manipulate held expressions (discussed e.g. [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/1929/injecting-a-sequence-of-expressions-into-a-held-expression)), but I failed to apply those for this particular problem:

```
(Hold[{3, 4, 5 | 6}] /. (Verbatim@Alternatives)[x__] :> RandomChoice@List@x)
```

> ```
> Hold[{3, 4, RandomChoice[{5, 6}]}]
> ```

The code should replace any `Alternatives` in the held expression with an appropriate choice from the alternatives, in this case either 5 or 6, i.e. it *should* evaluate the replacement.

Comment: @kguler but `HoldFirst` is not a "held expression" wrapper, it's an attribute.

Comment: @FJRA, just realized why OP wanted to use `Hold` rather than `HoldFirst` or `HoldRest` or `HoldAll` (and deleted my previous comment before I saw your explanation)

Comment: @rm-rf & WReach, is there any particular reason why `Verbatim` is used in each answer? This will do too: `/. x_Alternatives :> RuleCondition@RandomChoice@(List @@ x)` or `/. x_Alternatives :> 
   With[{eval = RandomChoice@(List @@ x)}, eval /; True])`.

Comment: @Kuba `Verbatim` is only used becase I wanted to pass on arguments as `Sequence[5, 6]` instead of `5|6` as in a replacement, the latter could possibly match more than one thing. It's not necessary but I guess they all tried to comply with my original specification. Your's is equally good.

Comment: Ok, thanks, I just wasn't sure if I get everything :)

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Here are a couple of alternatives to *Trott-Strzebonski* in @R.M's answer:

```
Hold[{3,4,5|6}] /.
  Verbatim[Alternatives][x__] :> RuleCondition@RandomChoice@List@x
```

> Hold[{3, 4, 5}]

```
Hold[{3,4,5|6}] /.
  Verbatim[Alternatives][x__] :> Block[{}, RandomChoice@List@x /; True]
```

> Hold[{3, 4, 6}]

They operate on the same principle as Trott-Strzebonski (i.e. `RuleCondition`), but express the effect in different ways.

Comment: I was tempted to post this answer, but decided to wait for you, as the proper one to do it :). +1.

Answer (score 23):

This is a case where the [Trott-Strzebonski in-place evaluation trick](http://library.wolfram.com/infocenter/Conferences/377/) is useful. You use `With` to inject inside your held expression as:

```
(Hold[{3, 4, 5 | 6}] /. (Verbatim@Alternatives)[x__] :> 
    With[{eval = RandomChoice@List@x}, eval /; True])

Out[1]= Hold[{3, 4, 5}]
```

You should definitely read [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6633334) by Leonid, that gives you a good insight into how this works, but in short, using `Condition` or `/;` forces the evaluation of `eval` when the condition is `True` (i.e., always) and then injected arbitrarily deep using `With`.

Comment: Just a note the talk title is "Working with Unevaluated Expressions" in case the link to wolfram library changes again in the future.