# How to implement a regular grammar?

Tags: replacement, parsing

What is the most simple, elegant way of implementing a rewrite-system defined as:

$$
\begin{aligned}
\Sigma &= \{a_1, a_2, a_3, ...\} \\
N &= \{A_1, A_2, A_3, ...\} \\
\{\alpha_1 , \alpha_2, \alpha_3, ...\} &= \Sigma \bigcup N \\
F &= \{f_1, f_2, f_3, ... \} \\
P &= \left\{ 
\begin{aligned}
  A &\rightarrow  a \\
  A &\rightarrow \alpha \\
  A &\rightarrow \alpha_1 | \alpha_2| \alpha_3 | ... \\
  A &\rightarrow f(\alpha_1, \alpha_2, \alpha_3, ...) \\
\end{aligned}
  \right\}
  
\end{aligned}
$$

That is: given a set of terminal symbols $\Sigma$, a set of nonterminal symbols $N$, a set of functions $F$ and a set of rewrite rules $P$, starting from an arbitrary but well-formed sentence $S$ of the grammar $G = (\Sigma, N, F, P, S)$, the system should apply the rewrite rules until all non-terminals are resolved, producing sentences like:

$$
f_1(a_3, a_1, f_2(a_4, a_1), a_1, f_3(a_2, f_1(a_1), a_4))
$$

**UPDATE: Specification**

- terminal and nonterminal symbols can be e.g. strings;
- only symbols of $\Sigma$ and $N$ are replaced, functions of $F$ are left intact, though symbols inside them are to be replaced. Therefore `g["A"]` in the initial sentence below is to be replaced, e.g.:

  `g["A"]` --applying-7th-rule--> `g["B" ~~ "b"]`;
- some functions should evaluate immediately to result in a (non)terminal symbol (`|` = random choice, `..` = repeate 1 or more times, `...` = repeate 0 or more times);
- all $f_i$ should be held until termination;
- rules should be applied randomly: any that fits could be chosen for a certain replacement.

At present, I am struggling with recursively applying structural replacements in held rules, and it's becoming more and more complex and convoluted. There must be a simpler way, concerning *Mathematica* is by design a very effective rewrite system. Though I have no idea how to start to exploit e.g. regular expressions.

**UPDATE: Example**

An example follows (note that I used `StringExpression`, but it can be replaced with `List`, or similar):

```
terminals = {"a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g", "h"};
nonTerminals = {"A", "B", "C", "D"};
functions = {f, g, h, i};

initSentence = g["A"] ... ~~ "B"; (* ... indicates zero or more g["A"] *)
rules = {
   "A" :> "a",
   "B" :> "b" | "c" | "d", (* immediately choose any terminal of the rhs *)
   "C" :> "e" | "f",
   "D" :> "g" | "h",
   "A" :> "a" ~~ "b",
   "A" :> "A" ~~ "a",
   "A" :> "B" ~~ "b",
   "A" :> f["e" | "f"] ~~ "a", (* do not evaluate f but choose "e" or "f" *)
   "A" :> g@"h" ~~ "C",
   "B" :> g@"C", (* do not evaluate g but "C" must be replaced later *)
   "B" :> "B" ~~ h@"e",
   "C" :> f@"f",
   "C" :> "C" ~~ g@"d"
   };
```

Starting from `initSentence` one possible process with a valid outcome would be:

```
g["A"] ... ~~ "B"                 (* initial sentence *)
g["A"] g["A"] ~~ "B"              (* g["A"] is repeated randomly *)
g["A" ~~ "a"] g["A"] ~~ "B"       (* rule A ":>"A "~~"a " is applied *)
g["A" ~~ "a"] g[g@"C"] ~~ "B"     (* rule "B" :> g@"C" is applied *)
g["a" ~~ "a"] g[g@"C"] ~~ "B"     (* rule "A" :> "a" is applied *)
g["a" ~~ "a"] g[g@f@"f"] ~~ "B"   (* rule "C" :> f@"f" is applied *)
g["a" ~~ "a"] g[g@f@"f"] ~~ "b" | "c" | "d"  (* rule "B":>"b"|"c"|"d" is applied *)
g["a" ~~ "a"] g[g@f@"f"] ~~ "d"   (* one terminal is randomly chosen *)
(* terminate and evaluate g, f *)
```

The point is that the grammar is represented as a set of rules that are both probabilistic (e.g. random choices) and are applied in a random way, i.e. for each symbol (at each step), a **random** fitting rule should be applied.

Comment: It is not quite clear what you want to do. Grammars usually *define* a language, which is a set of all possible phrases which can be derived by using the productions of the grammar, and is usually infinite, for interesting cases. To get a specific sentence, you have to provide a sequence of productions to be used, *in addition* to the grammar, or, equivalently, a parse tree. A more specific example grammar and a specific example of such a parse tree / production set would be useful here.

Comment: For a real-world example of the kind you seem to look for, look at the code of the package ``SymbolicC` `` in the Mathematica distribution, particularly function `GenerateCode`, which generates a string of C code (more or less a sequence of terminal tokens, although they are not separately generated and the joined, but rather joined on the fly), from the Symbolic C representation, which is, in fact, a form of a parse tree for C code. Of course, C grammar is more complex than regular grammars, so this may be an overkill for your purposes.

Comment: I assume that you did try using `/.` and `//.` with some `Rule`s, but that does not solve the problem completely.  Can you give a simple example where `/.` doesn't do what you need?  I guess the key is in "What is of importance here is that the some functions (e.g. |, cf. Alternatives) should evaluate immediately to result in a (non)terminal symbol, while some fi should be held until termination." but I do not completely understand what you mean by that, and I also don't understand where held expressions come in when you use `Replace(All)` (as `HoldAll` doesn't affect replacements)

Comment: If the problem is only that you need to prevent some `f` from evaluating until you reach the terminal point, then `Block` them during the `//.` phase: `Block[{f1, f2}, expr //. repl]`.

Comment: @LeonidShifrin please see edit.

Comment: @Istvan Thanks, but this did not improve things much. First of all, what you name a sentence is actually representing a class of sentences, because sentences should not contain non-terminals ( at least if we stick to the standard terminology). Second, there is no production in the above grammar that can, as far as I can see, produce `g["A"]`. So, it still remains a mystery to me what is it you are after here.

Comment: @Istvan Oops, sorry, I just noticed you mentioned that rules are picked randomly - so you want to generate a random sentence compatible with the grammar. This makes it more clear. But your `initSentence` still does not look to be a legal sentence obtained from the grammar, since there is no production to get `g["A"]`.

Comment: For generating random sentences, or parsing given ones, might get some ideas from http://library.wolfram.com/infocenter/Conferences/388/ in section "Tree application: A rudimentary parser"

Comment: @ArchimedesofSyracuse, @ Leonid I've updated the post again, as things are starting to clear up for me as well.

Comment: "a" ~~ "b" seems to auto-evaluate to "ab", so be careful with ~~

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The following code defines the function `randomSentence`.  It uses recursive descent to generate a sentence from a grammar expresssed as rules:

```
ClearAll[randomSentence, randomCount]
randomCount[] := RandomVariate[GeometricDistribution[0.5]]

SetAttributes[randomSentence, HoldAll]
randomSentence[rules_, expr_] :=
  Module[{generate}
  , SetAttributes[generate, HoldAll]
  ; Replace[#[[1, 1]] :> #& /@ GatherBy[rules, First], (_ :> r_) :> r, {3}] /.
      (a_ :> {b___}) :> (generate[a] := generate[Alternatives[b]])
  ; generate[a_Alternatives] :=
      generate @@ RandomChoice[List @@ Hold /@ Unevaluated @ a]
  ; generate[(r:(Repeated|RepeatedNull))[e_]] :=
      Hold @@ Evaluate @ ConstantArray[0, randomCount[] + Boole[r===Repeated]] /.
        0 :> generate[e] /.
        Hold -> Composition[generate, List]
  ; generate[l_List] := StringJoin @@ generate /@ Unevaluated @ l
  ; generate[x:_[___]] := generate /@ Unevaluated @ x
  ; generate[x_] := x
  ; generate[expr]
  ]
```

Here is the species grammar, adapted (sic) to the form required by `randomSentence`:

```
ClearAll[f, g, h, i]
f[x___] := x <> "er";
g[x___] := x <> "ed";
h[x___] := x <> "ing";
i[x___] := x <> "y";

$rules =
  { "Species" :> "Animal" | "Plant"
  , "Species" :> f@"Action"
  , "Species" :> {"Color" | "Type", "-", "Species"}

  , "Attribute" :> "Type" | "Color"
  , "Attribute" :> {"Animal", "-", f@"Action"}
  , "Attribute" :> {"Color" | "Type", "-", g@"Part"}
  , "Attribute" :> i@"Plant"
  , "Attribute" :> {"Plant" | "Animal", "-", h@"Action"}

  , "Animal" :> "warble"|"shrew"|"whale"|"caiman"|"babuin"|"bat"|"bug"
  , "Plant" :> "bush"|"moss"|"fern"|"grass"|"squash"|"seed"
  , "Part" :> "back"|"head"|"finger"|"tail"|"ear"|"wing"|"thorn"
  , "Color" :> "black"|"red"|"white"|"blue"|"silver"|"crimson"|"dark"
  , "Type" :>  "long"|"cross"|"sharp"|"thick"|"heavy"|"fluffy"|"big"|"wild"
  , "Action" :> "jump"|"kill"|"stalk"|"sting"|"climb"|"crawl"|"eat"
  };
```

Here is a sample use of the function (note that there is no need to explicitly specify the terminals, non-terminals and functions):

```
Table[randomSentence[$rules, {{"Attribute", " "}..., "Species"}], {10}] // Column
```

> bug
>   bat-climbing moss
>   red-heavy-cross-dark-thick-stalker
>   babuin
>   squashy heavy-killer
>   killer
>   seed
>   squashy white-fingered heavy-red-whale
>   climber
>   squashy thick-winged stinger

**How It Works**

The trickiest part of this problem is to make sure that none of the function expressions in the grammar are evaluated until they are needed -- and even then they may require some preprocessing of their arguments.  To make this possible, `randomSentence` must not evaluate the rules or sentence form passed to it:

```
SetAttributes[randomSentence, HoldAll]
randomSentence[rules_, expr_] :=
```

We are going to use a helper function called `generate`.  Again, it must not evaluate any expressions prematurely:

```
  Module[{generate}
  , SetAttributes[generate, HoldAll]
```

`generate` will be able to convert any grammar expression into a string.  There are many types of grammar expressions.  First, we will teach `generate` how to deal with each of the non-terminal symbols.  We group all of the rules into lists, one for each nonterminal.  Then we convert each of those groups into definitions for `generate` as if
they had been specified using `Alternatives` in the original grammar:

```
  ; Replace[#[[1, 1]] :> #& /@ GatherBy[rules, First], (_ :> r_) :> r, {3}] /.
      (a_ :> {b___}) :> (generate[a] := generate[Alternatives[b]])
```

`Alternatives` expressions are processed by selecting a random alternative from the list and then applying `generate` to that choice:

```
  ; generate[a_Alternatives] :=
      generate @@ RandomChoice[List @@ Hold /@ Unevaluated @ a]
```

`Repeated` expressions are processed by generating the repeated expression a random number of times.  `RepeatedNull` allows zero occurrences whereas `Repeated` will have at least one.  The tortured logic in this operation is due to the need to make sure that each repetition is not evaluated before it has been duly interpreted as a grammar expression.  Also, it is important to ensure that each repetition is generated independently:

```
  ; generate[(r:(Repeated|RepeatedNull))[e_]] :=
      Hold @@ Evaluate @ ConstantArray[0, randomCount[] + Boole[r===Repeated]] /.
        0 :> generate[e] /.
        Hold -> Composition[generate, List]
```

Each grammar expression in a list is evaluated independently and then the results are joined together:

```
  ; generate[l_List] := StringJoin @@ generate /@ Unevaluated @ l
```

Any function call must be made *after* the arguments have been individually generated:

```
  ; generate[x:_[___]] := generate /@ Unevaluated @ x
```

Anything else is passed unchanged (presumably strings):

```
  ; generate[x_] := x
```

Now that `generate` is defined, all that remains is to use it:

```
  ; generate[expr]
  ]
```

`randomSentence` uses the helper function `randomCount` to generate a random repetition counts.  For this example, we are using a geometric distribution where the probability of each successive count is half that of its predecessor.  Adjust this distribution to suit your taste.

```
randomCount[] := RandomVariate[GeometricDistribution[0.5]]
```

Answer (score 9):

Since no full solution has arrived, I've created the code based on the different sources you have provided.

The function `applyRulesRepeated` scans through the initial sentence and replaces the first nonterminal symbol it founds while holding all external functions (`f`, `g`, ..., for suffixing or alike). Here I used the holding part of [Archimedes' answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/2698/89). This replacement is done one-by-one for each found nonterminal. At the end, when there are only terminals, I substitute these terminals with random choices from the appropriate lexicon variables. I refer to the variables by their symbolname (in `$Replacements`, solution given by [WReach](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/2661/89)). In the full version, I use a specific function to choose the words by removing them from the original list to prevent repetition (a specific `RandomChoice` with `HoldAll` attribute), thus it was necessary to rely on such complicated methods of word-choice (I actually used the [Trott-Strzebonski method](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/2678/how-to-inject-an-evaluated-expression-into-a-held-expression) in the more complicated version). Also I reverted rules to use List instead of StringExpression due to the fact that `"a"~~"b"` evaluates to `"ab"` which is unwanted (thanks Archimedes). I was also inspired by [Daniel Lichtblau's parser](http://library.wolfram.com/infocenter/Conferences/388/Lichtblau_Algorithms.nb?file_id=2476) and its more evolved version in [Sal Mangano's cookbook](http://books.google.co.uk/books?id=BkDxC_O1WisC&lpg=PA235&ots=hjhVEkHBDX&dq=Sal%20mangano%20parser&pg=PA227#v=onepage&q&f=false).

Here it is, presented as a toy experiment with species names, I hope you will enjoy playing with/extending it:

### Regular grammar producing hypothetic animal names

```
(* Lexicon of different types of words *)
animal = {"warble", "shrew", "whale", "caiman", "babuin", "bat", "bug"};
plant  = {"bush", "moss", "fern", "grass", "squash", "seed"};
part   = {"back", "head", "finger", "tail", "ear", "wing", "thorn"};
color  = {"black", "red", "white", "blue", "silver", "crimson", "dark"};
type   = {"long", "cross", "sharp", "thick", "heavy", "fluffy", "big", "wild"};
action = {"jump", "kill", "stalk", "sting", "climb", "crawl", "eat"};

(* symbols of the grammar *)
$Terminals = {"animal", "plant", "color", "part", "type", "action"};
$NonTerminals = {"Species", "Attribute"};

(* functions not to be evaluated during sentence-generation *)
f[x___] := x <> "er";
g[x___] := x <> "ed";
h[x___] := x <> "ing";
i[x___] := x <> "y";
$Functions = {f, g, h, i};

(* initial sentence specification *)
$Sentence = "S" :> {{"Attribute", " "} .., "Species"};

(* allowed replacements in the grammar *)
$Rules = {
   "Species" :> "animal" | "plant",
   "Species" :> f@"action",
   "Species" :> {"color" | "type", "Species"},

   "Attribute" :> "type" | "color",
   "Attribute" :> {"animal", f@"action"},
   "Attribute" :> {"color" | "type", g@"part"},
   "Attribute" :> i@"plant",
   "Attribute" :> {"plant" | "animal", h@"action"}
   };

(* define replacements for injecting actual words into sentence *)
$Replacements = # -> (ToExpression[#, InputForm, Hold] /. Hold[v_] :> Hold@RandomChoice@v) & /@ $Terminals;

(* parameters *)
$MaxRecursion = 100; (* max number of repeats when resolving Repeated(Null) *)
$MaxIteration = 2; (* max number of recursions when resolving nonterminals *)

(* Aux. function to replace only the first n occasion for each rule, successively *)
replaceEach[expr_, rep_List, args___] := Fold[replaceEach[#1, #2, args] &, expr, rep];
replaceEach[expr_, rule_[lhs_, rhs_], level_: {0, \[Infinity]}, n_: 1,
     opts : OptionsPattern[]] /; MemberQ[{Rule, RuleDelayed}, rule] :=
   ReplacePart[expr, rule[#, rhs] & /@ Position[expr, lhs, level, n, opts]];


(* applyRulesRepeated replaces nonterminals one-by-one in a recursive manner *)
applyRulesRepeated[pattern_] := applyRulesRepeated[pattern, 1];
applyRulesRepeated[pattern_, level_] := 
  Module[{patt, terminals, terminalReplace, nonTerminals, 
    nonTerminalReplace, temp},

   (* resolve : |, .., ... *)
   patt = pattern /. {
      (Verbatim@Alternatives)[x__] :> RandomChoice@List@x,
      (Verbatim@Repeated)[x_] :> Table[x, {RandomInteger@{1, $MaxIteration}}],
      (Verbatim@RepeatedNull)[x_] :> Table[x, {RandomInteger@{0, $MaxIteration}}]
      };

   (* find FIRST nonterminal symbol in sentence *)
   nonTerminals = 
    Cases[patt, _?(MemberQ[$NonTerminals, #] &), \[Infinity], 1];

   (* if no nonterminal was found (or max recursion level is reached) sentence is cosidered ready *)
   If[nonTerminals === {} \[Or] level === $MaxRecursion,
    (* if sentence is ready, replace terminals with actual words and return sentence AND chosen words *)
    terminals = Cases[patt, _?(MemberQ[$Terminals, #] &), \[Infinity]];
    terminalReplace = 
     Thread[terminals -> ReleaseHold[terminals /. $Replacements]];
    ReleaseHold@replaceEach[patt, terminalReplace]
    ,
    (* if there is still any unresolved nonterminal, use a rule on it *)
    nonTerminalReplace = 
     Thread[nonTerminals -> (nonTerminals /. 
         RandomChoice@
          Cases[$Rules, _?(MatchQ[First@nonTerminals, First@#] &)])];
    applyRulesRepeated[
     replaceEach[patt, nonTerminalReplace, {0, \[Infinity]}, 1], 
     level + 1]
    ]
   ];

(* Apply rules repeatedly while the necessary functions are held by Block *)
generateSentence[init_, term_, nonTerm_, rules_, {held___}] := 
  StringJoin@Block[{held}, applyRulesRepeated@Last@init];
```

Let's generate some random sentences:

```
Column@Table[
    generateSentence[$Sentence, $Terminals, $NonTerminals, $Rules, $Functions],
{10}]
```

> ```
> crimson warble
> fluffywinged ferny caiman
> bugkiller shrew
> whiteeared darkbat
> grassclimbing seedy bug
> thick whalekilling crimsonmoss
> redwinged babuinstinger caiman
> whaleeater whale
> fluffy warblejumper babuin
> caimankiller squash
> ```

As you can see, the output is sometimes nonsensical, sometimes quite realistic, but there was no semantic consideration behind the project. Each sentence is well-formed and complies to the (implicit) rules of the grammar. It is nice to realize though that (whale-)cannibalism is simply nature's way of recursion.

Comment: That's what killer whales will do, given the opportunity. http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=K0YpLG88SFc http://news.nationalgeographic.com/news/2003/03/0324_030324_tvkillerwhales.html

Answer (score 4):

Does this help?

First, let's get rid of `StringExpression` because it acts as `StringJoin` and messes things up.

```
fix[expr_] := expr /. StringExpression -> List

initSentence = fix[initSentence]
rules = fix[rules]
```

I used `initSentence = {g["A"], "B"}` here.

Then let's gather the rules into `Alternatives` expressions:

```
gatherRules[rules_] := #[[1, 1]] -> Alternatives @@ #[[All, 2]] & /@ 
  GatherBy[rules, First]
```

define `Alternatives` temporarily to be `RandomChoice` (which I don't like, but `|` is indeed a convenient notation), and do a replacement:

```
repl[initSentence_, rules_, {heldFunctions___}] :=
 Block[{Alternatives = RandomChoice[{##}] &, heldFunctions},
  initSentence /. gatherRules[rules]
 ]

repl[initSentence, rules, {f,g}]
```

This will prevent f and g from evaluating util the replacement is done.

We can also apply the replacements several times:

```
Nest[repl[#, rules, {}] &, initSentence, 10]
```

The reason I didn't use `//.` is that once the expression gets big, it's very likely it'll never reach a terminal state.

**Edit**

If you want a function to evaluate in some rules, and not evaluate in other rules, then instead of this solution you can wrap them in some head to prevent evaluation, i.e. write `H[f]["a","b"]` instead of `f["a", "b"]`.  Then when you are ready to evaluate them, just `/. H -> Identity`.

Comment: I was just about to write up something like this. Termination is a bit tricky, maybe have repl throw something when initSentence contains no non-terminal symbols using MemberQ?

Comment: Thanks Archimedes, I made good use of your `repl` function.