# How to implement a regular grammar in Mathematica 10.0 onwards?

Tags: programming, string-manipulation

I would like to see a new answer to this question: [How to implement a regular grammar?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/2694/how-to-implement-a-regular-grammar) considering the introduction of **GrammarRules** in 10.0 ( 2014 ).

( I don't know if this question satisfies the stackexchange protocol but considering the ongoing and ever faster innovation of Mathematica some answers in the database will become outdated eventually. )

Comment: I think the standard protocol is to start a bounty on the old question, adding a comment that there are new `GrammarRules` in *Mathematica 10.0, and so new answers to the old question are worthwhile.

Comment: In fact, one of the options for why you're starting a bounty is "Current answers are outdated". So do that!

Comment: So you do agree that the current answers are outdated ?

Comment: Are there examples of outdated answers that have been updated by a bounty?

Comment: Oh, I have no idea, because I'm not familiar with that stuff at all. But if there were new features directly related to this topic introduced in a version later than the ones featured in that question, then the current answers are in some sense outdated.