# Creating an image grid that displays a full-size image when a thumbnail in the grid is clicked on

Tags: output-formatting, image, interactive

I am working on some teaching resources and pulled a whole bunch of images off the internet to illustrate the idea of "angle".

I can get *Mathematica* to import them and display them in a nice "collage", a kind of "preview" image with all the picture files.

```
dir = NotebookDirectory[];
picturedir = FileNameJoin[{dir, "Pictures"}];
pictlist = Import /@ FileNames[{"*.jpg", "*.png", "*.gif"}, {picturedir}];
GraphicsGrid[Partition[pictlist, 8], Frame -> All, ImageSize -> 800]
```

I have two questions.

First. When I partition the list, how can I get it to "pad" and simply leave a blank space in the grid if the number of images isn't a multiple of 8?

Second, the more important question.  Could I make the `GraphicsGrid` "clickable", so I could click on the small image in my collage and have it open the full size image in another *Mathematica* notebook for better viewing?

Comment: `Partition[Range[20], 8, 8, 1, {}]`, I don't know why this isn't a default behaviour.

Comment: Regarding clicability, this answer using `Button` could be useful: http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/2725/131.

Comment: The `PopupWindow` docs under Applications has an example of this. Just wrap `Grid` around the list.

Answer (score 3):

```
GraphicsGrid[
 Partition[
  Join[PopupWindow[#, #] & /@ pictlist, 
   ConstantArray["", Mod[Length@pictlist, 8]]], 8], Frame -> All, 
 ImageSize -> 800]
```

Answer (score 3):

Here is a simple way to do it using[`Multicolumn`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Multicolumn.html), which is new in V10. I use a 4 x 4 grid with a list of three pictures

[image: pics]

```
Multicolumn[
  Item[PopupWindow[#, #, WindowSize -> {All, All}], ItemSize -> 10] & /@ pictlist, 
  2, 
  Frame -> All]
```

[image: grid]

And clicking on one the thumbnails produces

[image: popup]

Answer (score 2):

Here's a small example:

```
image := Graphics[{Hue@RandomReal[], Rectangle[]}, ImageSize -> 50]
images[n_] := Partition[PadRight[Table[image, {n}], n + 8 - Mod[n, 8], Null], 8];
```

[image: Color grid]

The key is that `Null` gives a blank space when used in `GraphicsGrid`. I agree with Zviovich that `PopupWindow` is the best way to achieve what you ask for when it comes to displaying the images in a larger size. If I were to extend my example to include that I might use

```
Deploy@GraphicsGrid@Map[
   MouseAppearance[PopupWindow[#, #], "LinkHand"] &,
   images[60],
   {2}
   ]
```

where `Deploy` and `MouseAppearance` are just there to add niceties. See also the example under "Applications" in the documentation for [`PopupWindow`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/PopupWindow.html).