# Displaying a series obtained by evaluating a Taylor series

Tags: hold, expression-manipulation

#### Description of problem

I would like to use Mathematica to display the series obtained by substituting a value for $x$ in a Taylor series expansion.  The terms of the series will be rational numbers, so they should be in their reduced forms.

For example, consider the following partial sum:

```
In[1]:= taylor=Series[Log[1+x],{x,0,6}] // Normal
Out[1]= x-x^2/2+x^3/3-x^4/4+x^5/5-x^6/6
```

If I use `ReplaceAll` to carry out the substitution $x=1$, then I will get

```
In[2]:= taylor /. {x->1}
Out[2]= 37/60
```

as opposed to $1-\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{3}-\frac{1}{4}+\frac{1}{5}-\frac{1}{6}$.

---

#### First attempt

The first thing which comes to mind is the following:

```
In[3]:= HoldForm[Evaluate[taylor]] /. {x->1}
Out[3]= 1-1^2/2+1^3/3-1^4/4+1^5/5-1^6/6
```

Now I just need to replace each of the terms with its simplified versions.  The first problem is that `Evaluate` only works on level 1, so the following code does not work.

```
In[4]:= Map[Evaluate,%,{2}]
Out[4]= Evaluate[1]+Evaluate[-(1^2/2)]+Evaluate[1^3/3]+Evaluate[-(1^4/4)]+Evaluate[1^5/5]+Evaluate[-(1^6/6)]
```

**Is there a way to carry out an evaluation deep inside `HoldForm`?**

I also tried applying `Replace` at level 2, but the correct replacement rule still eludes me.

```
In[5]:= Replace[
           HoldForm[Evaluate[taylor]] /. {x->1},
           {x_->Evaluate[x]},
           {2}]
Out[5]= 1-1^2/2+1^3/3-1^4/4+1^5/5-1^6/6
```

If I knew the appropriate replacements to carry out without peeking inside `HoldForm`, say `x_->0`, then the code above would work.

**How can I carry out the idea behind `In[5]`?**

---

#### Second attempt

If I am satisfied with just having a list of the terms, the following is certainly good enough:

```
In[6]:= List@@taylor/.{x->1}
Out[6]= {1,-(1/2),1/3,-(1/4),1/5,-(1/6)}
```

I can use `HoldForm` to prevent `Plus` from collapsing the series while retaining the pretty typesetting on the front end:

```
In[7]:= HoldForm[Plus[1,-(1/2),1/3,-(1/4),1/5,-(1/6)]]
Out[7]= 1+-(1/2)+1/3+-(1/4)+1/5+-(1/6)
```

So splicing the sequence portion of `Out[6]` into `HoldForm[Plus[...]]` is just what I need.  My plan was to use the splicing trick with `Sequence`, but that does not work within `HoldForm`.  For example,

```
In[8]:= HoldForm[Plus[Sequence[1,2]]]
Out[8]= +Sequence[1,2]
```

**Is there a way to splice `Out[6]` into `HoldForm[Plus[...]]`?**

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to inject an evaluated expression into a held expression?](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/2678/how-to-inject-an-evaluated-expression-into-a-held-expression)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

#### #1

[Trott-Strzebonski in-place evaluation](http://library.wolfram.com/conferences/devconf99/villegas/UnevaluatedExpressions/Links/index_lnk_30.html):

```
hf = HoldForm[1 - 1^2/2 + 1^3/3 - 1^4/4 + 1^5/5 - 1^6/6]

hf /. x_Times :> With[{eval = x}, eval /; True]
```

> ```
> 1 - 1/2 + 1/3 - 1/4 + 1/5 - 1/6
> ```

```
Replace[hf, x_ :> With[{eval = x}, eval /; True], {2}]
```

> ```
> 1 - 1/2 + 1/3 - 1/4 + 1/5 - 1/6
> ```

One may simplify this method using the undocumented function `RuleCondition` as [WReach shows](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/2683/121):

```
Replace[hf, x_ :> RuleCondition[x], {2}]
```

> ```
> 1 - 1/2 + 1/3 - 1/4 + 1/5 - 1/6
> ```

#### #2

[Injector pattern](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/1937/121):

```
{1, -(1/2), 1/3, -(1/4), 1/5, -(1/6)} /. {x__} :> HoldForm[+x]
```

> ```
> 1 - 1/2 + 1/3 - 1/4 + 1/5 - 1/6
> ```

Comment: @Michael `ReplaceAll` replaces subexpressions in any expression, not only a list.  The "injector" is turning the usual replacement upside down with the "target" expression being the RHS of the rule.  If the LHS of the rule does not match the full expression to the left of `/.` you will find that substitutions are still being made to that expression.

Comment: The documentation says that it "applies a rule or list of rules in an attempt to transform each subpart of an expression _expr_".  In my mind, `ReplaceAll` is about locally replacing subexpressions in a list.  The injector pattern does not return anything to the original list, so I find it really strange.  The example `{a,b} /. {x__} :> x`, which returns `Sequence[a,b]` shows that my understanding is off the mark.  Why does it not return `{Sequence[a,b]}`?

Comment: @Michael The entire expression `{a,b}` is matched by the pattern `{x__}` therefore the entire thing is replaced with `x` ; compare to `{a,b} /. {x__} :> g[x]` or `thing[{a,b}, {1,2,3}] /. {x__} :> Plus[x]`

Comment: Looks like you saw the comment I accidentally added and deleted soon afterwards.

Comment: I get it now!  The **whole expression** is matched by the LHS of the rule.  Your examples for comparison helped a lot.

Comment: I have only used `With` to give name to an expression I will use repeatedly.  Looking at the help file again, I found out that I can also use `With` to insert values into held expressions.  The one thing which still puzzles me is your use of seemingly redundant condition `/; True`.  If I take this part out, the `With[...]` pieces in HoldForm will not be evaluated.  What is going on?

Comment: @Michael that's an advanced technique; I didn't learn about it until last year.  See [this section](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Condition.html#123) in the documentation, and also [my answer here.](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/1852/121)  It allows a certain non-standard evaluation in `With` or `Module` which is used in the *Trott-Strzebonski method* to force an evaluation that otherwise would not happen.

Comment: @Michael thanks for the Accept.

Answer (score 9):

You might want

```
HoldForm[Plus[##]] & @@ (List @@ taylor /. x -> 1)
```

Comment: This is a simple way but I'm not sure it answers the OP's questions.  I focused on the questions he emphasized in **bold**.  Nevertheless, +1 for pragmatism.

Comment: I just looked up `SlotSequence`.  This is a useful trick to remember.

Comment: Here is a slightly neater way to do Mike's construction: `With[{x0 = 0, n = 6, x = 1}, HoldForm[Plus[##]] & @@ DeleteCases[CoefficientList[Series[Log[1 + \[FormalX]], {\[FormalX], x0, n}], \[FormalX]] Prepend[x^Range[n], 1], 0]]`

Comment: @J.M. I am not sure I understand why your code is neater given that it is significantly longer.  Is there a fringe case where `List @@ Series[Log[1+x],{x,0,n}] /. x->x0` fails?  Also is there a reason why the use of `With` is advisable in this case?

Comment: @Michael: the snippet as you gave it doesn't work. `List @@ Normal[Series[Log[1 + \[FormalX]], {\[FormalX], x0, n}]] /. \[FormalX] -> x` does work, but I think it's cleaner to use `CoefficientList[]` to extract the coefficients to be subsequently turned into terms...