# Determine whether some expression contains a given symbol

Tags: pattern-matching, expression-test, searching

Given a symbol `t` and an expression `expr`, how can I determine whether or not the symbol `t` appears somewhere in `expr`?

The best solution I have up with so far is:

```
Block[{t,s},(expr/.t->s)=!=expr]
```

which will return `True` if `t` is in `expr`, and `False` otherwise.

But this feels a bit like a hack because it's not really using `/.` because it's the right tool, but rather because `/.` happens to need to search through `expr` in order to do its unrelated task. This results in having to search through `expr` at least three times (I think?): once for the `/.`, and twice for each side of the `=!=`, when clearly its possible to find `t` in only one search.

Comment: -1? Sure the answer is obvious once you know it, but I spent a very long time looking for an answer, and even longer trying to code my own answer. It's not like `FreeQ` is a terrible descriptive function name, and it's not listed in the 'Patterns' Guide, or the 'Testing Expressions' guide, or a bunch of other guides that might seem relevant to a newish user.

Comment: It's in ["Testing and Searching List Elements"](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/tutorial/TestingAndSearchingListElements.html) at least, but I have to agree that the omission of `FreeQ[]` in the "Testing Expressions" is a most unfortunate omission.

Comment: @J.M. i filed FreeQ as a suggestion to be added to "Testing Expressions"

Comment: Also even if it is obvious and easy to find, at least the question makes sense, is well-written, and doesn't need mind-reading skills to answer. This is more than can be said for lots of others that people upvote

Comment: Don't forget FreeQ takes a levelspec optional argument. Can be useful if your quarry is hiding deep inside. Also there is ``Internal`DependsOnQ[expr,var]`` which attempts (operative word, that) to determine if expr has a functional dependence on x. Can be useful for tasks where detecting literal symbol presence is not quite what is wanted.  Example: ``In[1]:= Internal`DependsOnQ[f[x], x]

Out[1]= True``

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Try `FreeQ`

```
FreeQ[x^2, t]
(*True*)
FreeQ[x^2, x]
(*False*)
```

Answer (score 11):

ruebenko provides the built-in function, but supposing `FreeQ` was not provided we can find another way.  You are on the right track to use `ReplaceAll`, but it would be much better to give a result as soon as the search pattern is found.

```
freeQ[expr_, pat_] :=
 Catch[expr /. pat :> RuleCondition@Throw[False, "freeQ"]; True, "freeQ"]
```

`RuleCondition` [<sup>(1)</sup>](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5869885/618728)[<sup>(2)</sup>](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7679152/618728)[<sup>(3)</sup>](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/2683/121) is needed in the case that `expr` is `Hold[ ]` or the `Throw` will never evaluate.

Creating a massive expression (~1GB) and doing Timings (each in a separate session to circumvent caching) shows that this is reasonably fast.

```
big = Expand[(1 + x + y)^200 (2 - q)^150];

! FreeQ[big, q] // Timing
```

> {1.03, True}

```
! freeQ[big, q] // Timing
```

> {1.311, True}

```
Block[{q, s}, (big /. q -> s) =!= big] // Timing
```

> {6.739, True}

---

Another approach that is cleaner, but perhaps less didactic, that will also return as soon as the pattern is found uses `Cases`:

```
freeQ2[expr_, pat_] :=
   {} === Cases[expr, pat, {0, -1}, 1, Heads -> True]

! freeQ2[big, q] // Timing
```

> {0.983, True}

An important difference is that `ReplaceAll` (short form `/.`) will scan from the outside in while `Cases`, like most *Mathematica* functions, will scan inside out.  See:

- [How to perform a depth-first preorder traversal of an expression?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/9233/121)

And more examples:

- [ReplaceRepeated seemingly omits some rules](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/38668/121)
- [How to remove redundant {} from a nested list of lists?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/20180/121)
- [Using ReplaceAll to replace a head](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/56010/121)
- [why Level does not sort output according to their levels](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/56016/121)
- [How to ReplaceAll independent of depth?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/57361/121)
- [Is Replace doing double work?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/67196/121)

Comment: @Mr.Wizard If I am interested in testing for more than one variable I defined `freeQ[a_, b_] := FreeQ[a, b] /; Length[b] <= 1;
freeQ[a_, b_] := And @@ Map[FreeQ[a, #] &, b] /; Length[b] > 1
` Is this the most efficient way to proceed? Why isn't it the default behaviour?

Comment: @chris I'd suggest trying `Alternatives`: `FreeQ[expr, x | y | z]`  Or do you mean something else?

Comment: I understand your answer as I should use `freeQ[a_, b_List] := FreeQ[a, Or@@b]/; Length[b] > 1 `. (I was after FreeQ taking lists)

Comment: @chris no, I mean: `freeQ[a_, b_List] := FreeQ[a, Alternatives @@ b]` -- see [Alternatives](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Alternatives.html).

Comment: Thanks. I guess I have to wrap my head around Trott-Strzebonski, now. :)

Comment: Thanks for the reference for `RuleCondition`!