# What is the most elegant way to see if an expression is affected by a certain symbol?

Tags: expression-test

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Determine whether some expression contains a given symbol](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/9772/determine-whether-some-expression-contains-a-given-symbol)

Let's say I have some expression:

```
sample = {1, 1/q, f[m]}
```

And I want to check it if it has the symbol `m` in it.

My question: Is there a clean or fast way of checking if `m` is in the equation?

---

What I came up with so far:

```
Do[StringFreeQ[ToString[sample], "m"], {i, 300}] // AbsoluteTiming
(* {0.0120007, Null} *)
```

and

```
Do[(sample /. m -> Unique[]) === (sample /. m -> Unique[]), {i, 300}] // AbsoluteTiming
(* {0.0100005, Null} *)
```

These solutions work, but I feel like there might be a faster, functional way of doing this.

Comment: What about `FreeQ`?

Comment: FreeQ - but thats too short for an answer ;-)

Comment: @Rojo Don't `MemberQ` and `FreeQ` only check on the first level?  I checked this for `MemberQ` before.

Comment: No, `FreeQ` checks all levels by default. Both can take a level specification anyway

Comment: Counterexample: `FreeQ[{1, 1/q, D[m, t]}, m]`

Comment: That's because `D[m, t]` evaluates to `0`. If you want to check in held expressions, hold the evaluation with `Hold` or `Unevaluated`

Comment: Haha! Almost forgot what D stood for!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about:

```
sample = {1, 1/q, ff[f[m]]};
FreeQ[sample, m]
(* False *)
```