# How to remove redundant {} from a nested list of lists?

Tags: list-manipulation

There are numerous examples here, whose end result is the removal of empty brackets `{}` and empty lists. I still can't find an example of simply removing redundant brackets though.

It's hard for me to believe there isn't already a common solution to this problem. Please point me there if I missed it. As I am new to *Mathematica* I am learning primarily by example so when I ran into this problem I was at a loss of where to even start.

For example I have this list as INPUT to a new function:

> {
>   {{{0, 5}, {1, 4}, {2, 3}, {3, 2}, {4, 1}, {5, 0}}},
>   {{{1, 5}, {2, 4}, {3, 3}, {4, 2}, {5, 1}}},
>   {{{2, 5}, {3, 4}, {4, 3}, {5, 2}}},
>   {{{3, 5}, {4, 4}, {5, 3}}},
>   {{{4, 5}, {5, 4}}},
>   {{{5, 5}}, {{5, 5}}}
>   }

I would like the new function to generate this list as OUTPUT:

> {
>   {{0, 5}, {1, 4}, {2, 3}, {3, 2}, {4, 1}, {5, 0}},
>   {{1, 5}, {2, 4}, {3, 3}, {4, 2}, {5, 1}},
>   {{2, 5}, {3, 4}, {4, 3}, {5, 2}},
>   {{3, 5}, {4, 4}, {5, 3}},
>   {{4, 5}, {5, 4}},
>   {{5, 5}, {5, 5}}
>   }

---

The actual input TO new function:

```
{{{{0, 5}, {1, 4}, {2, 3}, {3, 2}, {4, 1}, {5, 0}}}, {{{1, 5}, {2, 4}, {3, 3}, {4, 2}, {5, 1}}}, {{{2, 5}, {3, 4}, {4, 3}, {5, 2}}}, {{{3, 5}, {4, 4}, {5, 3}}}, {{{4, 5}, {5, 4}}}, {{{5, 5}}, {{5, 5}}}}
```

The actual output FROM new function:

```
{{{0, 5}, {1, 4}, {2, 3}, {3, 2}, {4, 1}, {5, 0}}, {{1, 5}, {2, 4}, {3, 3}, {4, 2}, {5, 1}}, {{2, 5}, {3, 4}, {4, 3}, {5, 2}}, {{3, 5}, {4, 4}, {5, 3}}, {{4, 5}, {5, 4}}, {{5, 5}, {5, 5}}}
```

Comment: Your example following "At this point' makes no sense, because expressions like `(t,c)` have no meaning, nor do expressions enclosed in square brackets.  Otherwise, it appears you are asking to apply a replacement rule like `//. {a_List->a}` to your expressions. Is that what you're looking for?

Comment: Did you look at Flatten command. Flatten[%, 1] should help.

Comment: @s.s.o `Flatten` will only help if the extra brackets are at a particular level.  If the idea is to get rid of extra brackets anywhere in the expression something else will be needed.  I think my replacement rule is probably the simplest way.

Comment: @ Mr.Wizard true but you don't know how many open and closed brackets you should remove as well :) İn this case you choose 2...

Comment: @s.s.o No, I used `//.` so that it will keep applying the rule until all extraneous brackets are gone.  Probably not the most efficient way, but it should be effective.

Comment: @ Mr.Wizard true...

Comment: [Strongly related](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6562902/efficient-way-to-remove-empty-lists-from-lists/)

Answer (score 48, accepted):

Starting with:

```
a = {{{{0, 5}, {1, 4}, {2, 3}, {3, 2}, {4, 1}, {5, 0}}}, {{{1, 5}, {2, 4}, {3, 3}, {4, 
      2}, {5, 1}}}, {{{2, 5}, {3, 4}, {4, 3}, {5, 2}}}, {{{3, 5}, {4, 4}, {5, 3}}}, {{{4, 
      5}, {5, 4}}}, {{{5, 5}}, {{5, 5}}}};
```

This is probably the simplest:

```
a //. {x_List} :> x
```

---

### A single-pass method

Though using [`ReplaceRepeated`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/ReplaceRepeated.html) is pleasingly concise it is not efficient with deeply nested lists.  Because [`ReplaceAll`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/ReplaceAll.html) and `ReplaceRepeated` [scan from the top level](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/9233/121) the expression will have to be scanned multiple times.

Instead we should use [`Replace`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Replace.html) which scans expressions from the bottom up.  This means that subexpressions such as `{{{{6}}}}` will have redundant heads sequentially stripped without rescanning the entire expression from the top.  We can start scanning at *levelspec* `-3` because `{{}}` has a `Depth` of 3; this further reduces scanning.

```
expr = {{1, 2}, {{3}}, {{{4, 5}}}, {{{{6}}}}};

Replace[expr, {x_List} :> x, {0, -3}]
```

> ```
> {{1, 2}, {3}, {4, 5}, {6}}
> ```

Here I will use [`FixedPointList`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/FixedPointList.html) in place of `ReplaceRepeated` to count the number of times the expression is scanned in the original method:

```
Rest @ FixedPointList[# /. {x_List} :> x &, expr] // Column
```

> ```
> {{1,2},{3},{{4,5}},{{{6}}}}
> {{1,2},{3},{4,5},{{6}}}
> {{1,2},{3},{4,5},{6}}
> {{1,2},{3},{4,5},{6}}
> ```

We see that the expression was scanned four times, corresponding to the three levels that were stripped from `{{{{6}}}}` plus an additional scan where nothing is changed, which is how both `FixedPointList` and `ReplaceRepeated` terminate.  To see the full extent of this scanning try:

```
expr //. {_?Print -> 0, {x_List} :> x};
```

Or to merely count the total number of matches attempted:

```
Reap[expr //. {_?Sow -> 0, {x_List} :> x}][[2, 1]] // Length
```

> ```
> 50
> ```

We see that only 7 expressions in total are scanned with the single-pass method:

```
Reap[
  Replace[expr, {_?Sow -> 0, {x_List} :> x}, {0, -3}]
][[2, 1]] // Length
```

> ```
> 7
> ```

#### Timings

Let us compare the performance of these two methods on a highly nested expression.

```
fns = {Append[#, RandomInteger[9]] &, Prepend[#, RandomInteger[9]] &, {#} &};

SeedRandom[1]
big = Nest[RandomChoice[fns][#] & /@ # &, {{1}}, 10000];
Depth[big]
```

> ```
> 3264
> ```

```
big //. {x_List} :> x                           // Timing // First
Replace[big, {x_List} :> x, {0, -3}] ~Do~ {800} // Timing // First
```

> ```
> 0.452
>
> 0.468
> ```

On this huge expression the single-pass `Replace` is about **800 times faster** than `//.`.

Comment: I have a similar problem, but somehow none of the suggestions here worked. My code looks like

{{{0}}, {{1}}, {{2}}, {{0, 0}}, {{0, 1}, {1, 0}}, {{0, 2}, {2, 
   0}}, {{1, 1}}, {{1, 2}, {2, 1}}, {{2, 2}}, {{0, 0, 1}, {0, 1, 
   0}, {1, 0, 0}}, {{0, 0, 2}, {0, 2, 0}, {2, 0, 0}}, {{0, 1, 1}, {1, 
   0, 1}, {1, 1, 0}}, {{0, 1, 2}, {0, 2, 1}, {1, 0, 2}, {1, 2, 0}, {2,
    0, 1}, {2, 1, 0}}, {{0, 2, 2}, {2, 0, 2}, {2, 2, 0}}, {{1, 1, 
   2}, {1, 2, 1}, {2, 1, 1}}, {{1, 2, 2}, {2, 1, 2}, {2, 2, 1}}}

I would just like to have a list of single sets of numbers like {{1,2},{0,1,2},{2.2},...,{1,0,0}}

Comment: @Solarmew It is not clear how your input would be transformed into that output.  However I suspect you want one of `Flatten`, `Join`, or `Union`.  For example start by assigning your existing code to `expr`, then try each of these: `Union @@ expr`, `Join @@ expr`, `Flatten[expr, 1]`.

Comment: Wizard , turns out what i was looking for was {x__?(Head[#] =!= List &)} :> {x}, -1])]; , which, as you can see from my most recent post, was part of a massive overkill to begin with XD

Comment: @Solarmew For that example you could replace `Cases[Permutations /@ 
  Rest@DeleteDuplicates@Subsets[n], {x__?(Head[#] =!= List &)} :> {x}, -1]` with `Join @@ Permutations /@ Rest@DeleteDuplicates@Subsets[n]` or `Flatten[Permutations /@ Rest@DeleteDuplicates@Subsets[n], 1]`.  These will both be faster than using pattern matching.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard Can you clarify about how the negative level spec and `_List` work here? For example, if we have `expr={{0, {{1, 2}}, {3}}, {4}}`, `Replace[expr, {x_List} :> x, {0, -3}]` gives `{{0, {1, 2}, {3}}, {4}}`, leaving the `{3}` and `{4} untouched. Doing instead `Replace[expr, {x_} :> x, {0, -2}]` gives `{{0, {1, 2}, 3}, 4}`, but `Replace[expr, {x_} :> x, {0, -3}]` gives `{{0, {1, 2}, {3}}, {4}}`. Why this difference for level spec -2 vs -3? And Why does removing the `_List` requirement enable taking off the brackets from the `{3}` and `{4}`?

Answer (score 25):

***NOTE: merged from a later duplicate question***

---

**Update**

Ok, since this became another shootout, here is my answer to the challenge:

```
lremoveFaster[lst_List]:= Replace[lst, {l_List} :> l, {0, Infinity}]
```

my benchmarks show that it is the fastest so far.

**Initial solution**

Here is a recursive version:

```
ClearAll[lremove];
lremove[{l_List}] := lremove[l];
lremove[l_List] := Map[lremove, l];
lremove[x_] := x;
```

So that

```
lremove[l]

(* {{{2, 2}, 3}, 2, {2, 33}, 4, 5} *)
```

"Theoretically", it should be more efficient than `ReplaceRepeated` for large lists, since the latter has to do many passes through expression. I don't have the time to benchmark right now, though.

Another difference is that `lremove` will be "stopped" by heads other than `List`, and *not* remove extra lists inside such heads. In contrast, `ReplaceRepeated` -based solution is greedy and will also work inside other heads. Which one is better depends on the goals.

Comment: Nice improvement.  (I already voted, too).  But, darn it, I considered `Replace` but thought it wouldn't handle `{{{1}}}` -- just do one replacement.  Stupid me.  Learned something new.  Thanks for playing.

Comment: @MichaelE2 Here you can find an explanation why `Replace` is more efficient in this case than `ReplaceAll`: [how does mathematica determine which rule to use first in substitution](http://stackoverflow.com/a/4824119/590388).

Comment: Thanks, @AlexeyPopkov, I was looking for some links like this one. But there were two more, one actually for a question asked by you, IIRC. Will try to find them.

Comment: @MichaelE2 Ok, [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6562902/efficient-way-to-remove-empty-lists-from-lists/6563973#6563973) is the one I was looking for, although there has to be yet another one that is relevant, if memory serves.

Comment: @MichaelE2 I also discussed this issue in my book, [here](http://www.mathprogramming-intro.org/book/node218.html). I don't have the time right now, but will add these links to my answer soon.

Comment: @AlexeyPopkov All right, found one of them.

Comment: @AlexeyPopkov [Nancy Blachman's article](http://www.mathematica-journal.com/issue/v8i4/features/blachman/contents/DemystifyingRules.pdf) on rules might also be related to your link.

Comment: I stumbled across this old duplicate today and marked it as such.  (1) If you disagree please tell me, and why. (2) I think perhaps a *merge* is in order to move these answers to that question; do you agree or disagree with that idea?

Comment: @Mr.Wizard Seems like a dupe indeed. Interesting that it had to wait for so long to be discovered. I have no objections to both closing this one as a dupe (which you already did) and merging these.

Answer (score 20):

You can also use `Position` to find the locations of the nested braces and `FlattenAt` to flatten the list at those positions:

```
strip = Identity @ FlattenAt[#, Position[#, {_List}]] &

strip @ {{{{{{2, 2}}, 3}, 2, {{2, 33}}, 4, 5}}}
(* {{{2, 2}, 3}, 2, {2, 33}, 4, 5} *)
```

Comment: +1, very nice! This problem makes for a great small case study.

Comment: If we were playing code golf, I could beat you by three characters with `strip = List @@ FlattenAt[#, Position[#, {_List}]] &`  :)

Comment: @m_goldberg, if we were playing code golf I would have written it as `+FlattenAt[#, #~Position~{_List}] &`  :-)

Comment: @m_goldberg `List @@` is not appropriate for the case in which the `Head` is not `List`. Such as `strip@f[{{}}]`.

Comment: @luyuwuli. OP's question was _specifically_ concerned withremoving "braces", so I don't think your quibble applies (pun intended :)

Comment: @m_goldberg I agree the removing "braces" part and it's a small issue. However, by saying `List@@` is not appropriate ..., I want to stress that `Identity @` can't be replaced by `List@@` (or it's safer to use `Identity@ ` than `List@@`), because it will keep the `Head` intact. Changing the `Head` is _unexpected_ , so it should be avoided (especially in a big program).

Comment: I stumbled across this old duplicate today and marked it as such.  (1) If you disagree please tell me, and why. (2) I think perhaps a *merge* is in order to move these answers to that question; do you agree or disagree with that idea?

Comment: @Mr.Wizard, I agree it's a duplicate and merging makes sense.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard FYI I just received a silver Necromancer badge following the merge, is this the expected behaviour? It seems a little odd that merging results in rewards for answering an old question. Not a complaint, just an observation.

Comment: @SimonWoods Yes, that happens.  It's a nice *silver* lining to a lost Accept in some cases.

Answer (score 14):

**Update**

Here's faster way that avoid reprocessing:

```
deflate = Block[{flatten},
    flatten[x_List] := x;
    flatten[x___] := {x};
    # /. List -> flatten
    ] &;
```

---

**Original**

In some cases you might be able to use [`Flatten`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Flatten.html).  In this one, [`ReplaceRepeated`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/ReplaceRepeated.html) can be use like this:

```
l = {{{{{{2, 2}}, 3}, 2, {{2, 33}}, 4, 5}}};

l //. {{x___}} :> {x}
(* {{{2, 2}, 3}, 2, {2, 33}, 4, 5} *)
```

This works, too

```
l //. {x_List} :> x
```

---

**Comparison**

*Timings -- Big lists*

We can create some data randomly nesting lists like this:

```
SeedRandom[1];
l0 = {Table[RandomInteger[{0, 3}], {5}]}
Nest[# /. i_?Positive :> RandomChoice[{0, 1, 0, 1, 3, 4}, i] &, l0, 3]

(* {{3, 1, 0, 1, 1}} *)
(* {{{0, 0, {{0, 3, 0}}}, {{{1}, {0, 0, 0}, 0}}, 0, {0}, {0}}} *)
```

Each positive number is replace recursively by a list of length equal to the number.  We get excess braces every time the number `1` is replaced in a list `{1}`.

Here is a big list:

```
SeedRandom[1];
l0 = {Table[RandomInteger[{0, 3}], {5}]}
l2 = Nest[# /. i_?Positive :> RandomChoice[{0, 1, 0, 1, 3, 4}, i] &, l0, 38];

(* l2 // Flatten // Length *)
(* 537612 *)
```

It has over 95,000 extra braces:

```
Module[{cnt = 0},
 f1 = l2 //. {x_List} :> (cnt++; x);
 cnt
 ]
(* 95784 *)

f1 = l2 //. {x_List} :> x; // AbsoluteTiming
f2 = deflate[l2]; // AbsoluteTiming
f3 = lremove[l2]; // AbsoluteTiming
f4 = lremoveFaster[l2]; //AbsoluteTiming
```

> {2.814402, Null}
>   {0.558850, Null}
>   {0.773060, Null}
>   {0.155110, Null}

```
f1 == f2 == f3 == f4
```

> True

*Timings -- Small lists*

Here we'll use the OP's list and the site's favorite `timeAvg` function.

```
SetAttributes[timeAvg, HoldFirst]
timeAvg[func_] := Do[If[# > 0.3, Return[#/5^i]] & @@ Timing@Do[func, {5^i}], {i, 0, 15}]

l //. {x_List} :> x; // timeAvg
deflate[l]; // timeAvg
lremove[l]; // timeAvg
lremoveFaster[l]; // timeAvg
```

> 9.2105*10^-6
>   0.0000167781
>   0.0000108307
>   6.2308*10^-6

One can see that `ReplaceRepeated`, while rather natural and short to code, takes rather a long time on big lists but is fastest on small ones. Leonid's `lremoveFaster` is fastest.

---

Actually, if I make `flatten` a global function instead of local to `deflate`, then the speed is comparable to `ReplaceRepeated` on short lists.

```
flatten[x_List] := x;
flatten[x___] := {x};
l /. List -> flatten // timeAvg
```

> 8.9970*10^-6

Comment: Very nice (I already voted), but see my update :)

Comment: I stumbled across this old duplicate today and marked it as such.  (1) If you disagree please tell me, and why. (2) I think perhaps a *merge* is in order to move these answers to that question; do you agree or disagree with that idea?

Comment: @Mr.Wizard Closing/merging both seem fine to me.

Comment: Thanks; I have been waiting on your reply. :-)

Comment: @Mr.Wizard Work got busy and I took a break from SE.

Comment: No problem, and glad to have you back!  I meant only that your opinion mattered to me.