# How to take single item out of List?

Tags: list-manipulation

I often get `List`s that contain a single item, like `{name}` or `{{2,3,4}}`.

Is there a function that simply takes the item out of the `List` without needing to use `Part`, like `#[[1]]&`?

Comment: Uh, isn't #[[1]]& a crude version of Part? The double  bracket [[]] is a short version of Part, check `a[[1]] // FullForm`.

Comment: `First` ... `Last`...

Comment: I intend to close this as a duplicate of [(20180)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/20180) unless you explain why it not the same.

Comment: What's wrong with `Part`? It's a basic and very fast function.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `First` as in `First@{{2,3,4}}`. Not entirely sure though, why this should be preferable to `[[1]]`.