# How to remove brackets from this list?

Tags: list-manipulation

I have some lists which have many brackets. 
I'd like to remove brackets from the lists.

For example, I need to change the list

```
{{{{0, 5}, {1, 4}, {2, 3}, {3, 2}, {4, 1}, {5, 0}}}, {{{1, 5}, {2, 4}, {3, 3}, {4, 2}, {5, 1}}}, {{{2, 5}, {3, 4}, {4, 3}, {5, 2}}}, {{{3, 5}, {4, 4}, {5, 3}}}, {{{4, 5}, {5, 4}}}, {{{5, 5}}, {{5, 5}}}}
```

into

```
{{0, 5}, {1, 4}, {2, 3}, {3, 2}, {4, 1}, {5, 0}, {1, 5}, {2, 4}, {3, 3}, {4, 2}, {5, 1}, {2, 5}, {3, 4}, {4, 3}, {5, 2}, {3, 5}, {4, 4}, {5, 3}, {4, 5}, {5, 4}, {5, 5}, {5, 5}}.
```

Here, I'd like `{5, 5}` to remain intact, and the extra brackets to be erased.

How should I do it?

Comment: Look up `Flatten[]`. Pay attention to its second argument.

Comment: `Flatten[list, 2]` to be precise.

Comment: May be helpful: [(20180)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/20180/121)