# How to Apply Functions to Lists with Many Curly Brackets?

Tags: list-manipulation

For example, consider the list defined below.

```
samplelist = {{{1,2,3,4}}, {{5,6,7,8}}};
```

How would I apply the `Times` operator to the subsets `{1,2,3,4}` and `{5,6,7,8}`?

Neither `Map` nor `Apply` work (or at least not in the ways I've tried).

If somebody could please help me out, I'd greatly appreciate it. I seem to run into this problem of trying to circumvent extra curly brackets quite often.

**Edit:** Sorry for not clarifying.  The desired output is `{24,1680}`. Extra brackets are fine for something like `{{24},{1680}}` since at this point, `Flatten` can be used.

Comment: You can remove the extra brackets: `Apply[Times, Flatten[samplelist, 1]]`

Comment: When I try that, how come the output is {5,12,21,32}? I experienced something similar when I tried using Table.

Comment: E.g., `Apply[Times, samplelist, {2}]`... and `Apply[Times, samplelist, -2]` will do it for a list of lists with differing depths...

Comment: Ah, it's because Flatten turns samplelist into all into one list, which isn't what I want. I want to apply Times to each element separately. Sorry for not clarifying.

Comment: Please state for your example what you want the output to be.

Comment: Ah, that works @ciao. Thank you very much!

Comment: @ciao Make it an Answer!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I suspect you'd be fine with

```
samplelist /. {x__Integer} :> Times@x // Flatten
```

If you always store numbers you want to multiply in lists, and you know them to be integers, this will “apply” `Times` to all such lists in your data.

For more general numbers try something like

```
samplelist /. {x__?NumberQ} :> Times@x // Flatten
```

Note: this way you don't have to adjust `Apply`'s (positive) levelspec to every single data sample you're dealing with, which is handy if you don't know in advance what depth exactly your lists will have, and if you also have lists of atoms you don't want to multiply. In absence of the latter condition, Mr Wizard's answer is probably better.

Answer (score 8):

If elements are atomic you can use *levelspec* `{-2}`:

```
Apply[Times, samplelist, {-2}]
```

> ```
> {{24}, {1680}}
> ```

Since `Plus[x]` and `Times[x]` each reduce to `x` you can also use `-2` if you not want the extra brackets, as shown by ciao (rasher):

```
Apply[Times, samplelist, -2]
```

> ```
> {24, 1680}
> ```

With a dummy head `foo` to see how this works:

```
Apply[foo, samplelist, -2]
```

> ```
> {foo[foo[1, 2, 3, 4]], foo[foo[5, 6, 7, 8]]}
> ```

Some reading for you:

- [Levels: how do they work?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/15567/121)
- [How to remove redundant {} from a nested list of lists?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/20180/121)
- [Scan vs. Map vs. Apply](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/46238/121)

Comment: I'm not really sure why this question isn't closed. p.s. `# /. List -> Times & /@ samplelist`

Comment: @Kuba Do not let my answer dissuade you from voting to close!

Answer (score 3):

Another approach, perhaps only slightly different than @Akater's:

```
samplelist /. v_?VectorQ :> Times @@ v
(*  {{24}, {1680}}  *)
```

One can give [`VectorQ`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/VectorQ.html) other arguments that restrict what type of elements the vector `v` might contain.  By default, an element can be anything except a list.

For example:

```
{{{x, Exp[x], 3, 4, x Exp[x]}},
 {{{5, Plot[Sin[x], {x, 0, 2 Pi}], Plot[Sin[x], {x, 0, 2 Pi}]}}}} /.
  v_?VectorQ :> Times @@ v
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Answer (score 1):

```
Times @@@ samplelist ~Flatten~ 1
```

> `{24, 1680}`

One could also directly `Replace` the innermost `List` with `Times`

```
Replace[samplelist, List -> Times, {3}, Heads -> True] // Flatten
```

> `{24, 1680}`

Comment: Isn't that bill's answer ?

Comment: @Sektor [bills comment](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/87047/how-to-apply-functions-to-lists-with-many-curly-brackets/87114?noredirect=1#comment236796_87047) is `Apply[Times, Flatten[samplelist, 1]]`, which doesn't give the correct output. This is `Apply[Times, Flatten[samplelist, 1], {1}]` and does give the correct output.

Comment: I was talking about being the same answer as an idea. Clearly, there's a difference between the two, but you are assuming the OP is not going to experiment any further with the answers/suggestions he receives.

Comment: I completely disagree with the assumptions about the OP and about the actions by the OP, that the [comment by @Sektor](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/87047/how-to-apply-functions-to-lists-with-many-curly-brackets/87114#comment237011_87114) assumes about me.

Comment: Then the difference between your answer and bill's is just philosophical

Comment: I'd call it educational or didactical and see it closer to the [answer by Mr.Wizard](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/87059/18476) than to [bills comment](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/87047/how-to-apply-functions-to-lists-with-many-curly-brackets/87114?noredirect=1#comment236796_87047).

Answer (score 1):

Some more options:

New in 12.2

```
ArrayReduce[Apply @ Times, list, 3]
```

{{24}, {1680}}

New in 13.1

```
ReplaceAt[list, x_ :> Times @@ x, {;; , ;;}]
```

{{24}, {1680}}

```
Query[;; , ;; , Apply @ Times] @ list
```

{{24}, {1680}}