# Brackets around each item in matrix

Tags: list-manipulation, matrix

I have a matrix where every item in the matrix has its own brackets that I do not want. How can I remove the brackets around each item?

[image: Here is the matrix shown in both displays]

Comment: Try `mat /. List[x__] /; Length[List[x]] == 1 :> x` where `mat` is your matrix (I can't read which letter you're using in this image).

Comment: Flatten /@ matrix

Comment: Related: [(20180)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/20180/121)

Comment: `Catenate /@ m` is also a fast option.

Answer (score 14):

Wrap the matrix rows with the the `Flatten` function

```
M = {{{1}, {2}, {3}, {4}}, {{5}, {6}, {7}, {8}}}
```

[image: the matrix]

To save time you can wrap your whole matrix using: `Map[Flatten, <yourmatrix> ]`

```
Map[Flatten,{{{1}, {2}, {3}, {4}}, {{5}, {6}, {7}, {8}}}]
```

the outermost list contains two elements (the rows). the `Map` function *wraps* these elements with the `Flatten` function

> {{1, 2, 3, 4}, {5, 6, 7, 8}}

In *Mathematica* this is known as "nested" Lists. Flatten removes all wrappings of the `List` function until only one remains

To understand what the `Map` function does: Below is the "manual" approach without the `Map` function.

```
{  
 Flatten[{{1}, {2}, {3}, {4}}],

 Flatten[{{5}, {6}, {7}, {7}}]
}
```

As you are talking to an awesome machine called the *Mathematica* kernel you don't have to waste time writing things in long hand to make them readable (like you would for a slow-to-understand human reader of an essay or your future self reading your code).

hence `Map[Flatten, Matrix]` has the terse shorthand form `Flatten /@ matrix`

mentioned by @garej , @jjc385 and @Mr.Wizard below

Comment: As this answer is clearly geared for new users, I think this answer would be somewhat improved by mentioning the syntactic sugar `Flatten /@ <matrix>`.

Comment: (Is it polite/conventional to delete a comment such as mine above after the edit has been made?)

Comment: @jjc385 I have not observed a specific convention in that regard.  The comments can serve as minor credit for the source of an edit, and I don't see anything wrong with that.  However since you are mentioned by (nick)name in the answer now the comments seems redundant and I would probably delete it if it where mine.

Answer (score 14):

Lots of solutions.  Time for a benchmark.  My own contribution is [`Part`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Part.html):

```
m = {{{1}, {2}, {3}}, {{2}, {4}, {6}}};

m[[All, All, 1]];
```

> ```
> {{1, 2, 3}, {2, 4, 6}}
> ```

*Update: I made a complete mess of my earlier attempt at benchmarking. Here is a rewrite.*

```
methods = Hold[Flatten /@ m, ArrayReshape[m, Most@Dimensions@m], 
   ArrayReshape[m, Dimensions[m][[1 ;; 2]]], Flatten[m, {Depth[m] - 1, 1}], 
   Apply[Sequence, m, {2}], Apply[Sequence, m, {-2}], Join @@@ m, m[[All, All, 1]], 
   Catenate /@ m];

names = {"Map[Flatten]", "ArrayReshape 1", "ArrayReshape 2", "Flatten w/ Depth", 
   "Sequence {2}", "Sequence {-2}", "Join", "Part", "Map[Catenate]"};

upk[{x_, y_}] := Table[{ToString[i*j]}, {i, x}, {j, y}];
pkd[{x_, y_}] := RandomReal[1, {x, y, 1}];

tab = 
 Table[
  List @@ First /@ RepeatedTiming /@ methods,
  {fn, {upk, pkd}},
  {shape, {{10, 100000}, {1000, 1000}, {100000, 10}}},
  {m, {fn[shape]}}
 ];

TableForm[
  Append[names] /@ (tab //. {x_List} :> x),
  TableHeadings -> {{"Unpacked", "Packed"}, {{10, 100000}, {1000, 1000}, {100000, 10}}},
  TableSpacing -> {5, 1, 0.5}
]
```

[image]
(Benchmark timings in 10.1.0 under Windows 7 x64.)

It seems that in most instances `Part` wins, but a few times [`Catenate`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Catenate.html) edges it out.

Comment: I don't mean to question the infinite wisdom of Mr.Wizard, but as a relatively new user who just spent a few minutes trying to understand this code, I think it would be immensely helpful (and not terribly time consuming) if you somehow paired each column of output for the tests with a description of that test.  For example, you could include a line `{"Flatten-Map", "ArrayShape-Most", "ArrayShape", "Flatten-Depth","Apply-Sequence","Apply-Sequence-Backward","Join","Part-All"}` each of the three sets of output.  It _might_ also be helpful to sort somehow, but I can imagine arguing either way.

Comment: I'm sure a wizard like you can work this into the definition of the tests themselves!

Comment: @jjc385 Sorry, I was just being lazy.  Actually *really* lazy as if the code I copied is actually what I ran the second test is a total mess.  Earlier I had a comment "where's my coffee" -- I guess I really needed it!

Comment: @jjc385 I rewrote the benchmark and got a different result.  I hope I got it right this time but I am not certain I am still thinking clearly.  Please let me know if you notice any stupid mistakes.

Comment: It looks good to me, but then again I'm running on 2 hours of sleep and a can of soda at 7am ;)

By the way, and I'm not suggesting you implement this here, do you know of a slick way to do something like highlighting the elements of a list, with the highlighting color changing based on their values?  It would be a good way to instantly see the winner for tests like these.  (I admit I ask more out of curiosity than practicality.)

Comment: @Mr.Wizard, would you mind to check this method: `Catenate /@ m`. It will not beat `Part` but I'm not sure about other options.

Comment: I get slightly different results with your benchmarking: http://i.stack.imgur.com/MlcPo.png, but in both yours & mine, `ArrayReshape` has roughly constant timing on 10^6 elements in all three shapes, esp. on packed arrays.  `Join` seems quite different on my system on packed arrays (Mac/Intel i7).

Comment: @MichaelE2, at my machine `Catenate /@ m` wins in many categories (Win, i5, 8Gb).

Comment: @garej Added to benchmark, along with a note of the system I am performing the benchmarking on.

Comment: @garej What I found interesting was that *relative* performance seemed to vary by system so much. It's nice to see a new function (`Catenate`) be an improvement once in a while. My last row is very different: 0.0044, 0.0063, 0.11.  Note though that `Catenate` is not compilable, which is why it loses out to `Flatten` on longer lists; it also why mapping it unpacks the list (to level 1 only), making further processing less efficient (unless repacked).  `Join` unpacks to level 2; `Sequence` unpacks the whole array. Not sure why a difference in timing is not reflected on Mr.Wizard's computer.

Comment: @MichaelE2, I have results similar with yours (on Win machine). Thank you for pointing out the packing issue.

Answer (score 10):

You can use [`ArrayReshape`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ArrayReshape.html).
Either

```
ArrayReshape[mat, Most@Dimensions@mat]
```

or

```
ArrayReshape[mat, Dimensions[mat][[1 ;; 2]]]
```

It will keep a packed array packed, too.

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: Readers of this answer can find some further discussion of using `ArrayReshape` to remove unwanted singleton list wrappings, e.g., `{a]` or `{{a, b, c}}` in [this answer](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/121964/3066)

Answer (score 7):

**Edit**    With  `m = RandomInteger[9, {3, 6, 1}]`

Just for completeness:

```
Catenate /@ m
```

---

Just for diversity reasons

```
Apply[#&, m, {2}]
Apply[Sequence, m, {-2}]
Map[First, m, {2}]
```

Using @Mr.Wizard code I have updated the benchmark.

[image]

@MichaelE2 also noticed in comments that `Catenate` is not compilable.

Comment: I get similar results, to within a scaling factor for my slow CPU. Interesting that `Join` is much *worse* on packed arrays!

Comment: @SimonWoods, MichaelE2 in a comment says "that `Join` unpacks to level 2. `Sequence` unpacks the whole array". He gets similar results. I'm surprized that `Catenate` behaves so different _within_ packed group.

Answer (score 7):

You can also `Apply` `Join` at `level 1` to your list:

```
m = RandomInteger[9, {2, 4, 1}]
```

> {{{0}, {6}, {7}, {5}}, {{1}, {3}, {8}, {8}}}

```
Join @@@ m
```

> {{0, 6, 7, 5}, {1, 3, 8, 8}}

Answer (score 5):

I suggest `Flatten[m, {Depth[m] - 1, 1}]`, where `m` is the matrix in question.

For example,

```
SeedRandom[1]; m = RandomInteger[99, {4, 5, 1}]
```

> ```
> {{{80}, {14}, {0}, {67}, {3}}, 
>  {{65}, {23}, {97}, {68}, {74}}, 
>  {{15},{24}, {4}, {90}, {83}}, 
>  {{70}, {1}, {30}, {48}, {25}}}
> ```

```
Flatten[m, {Depth[m] - 1, 1}]
```

> ```
> {{80, 14, 0, 67, 3}, 
>  {65, 23, 97, 68, 74}, 
>  {15, 24, 4, 90, 83}, 
>  {70, 1, 30, 48, 25}}
> ```

Answer (score 2):

...and of course, there's always `Transpose[]`:

```
Transpose[{{{1}, {2}, {3}}, {{2}, {4}, {6}}}, {2, 3, 1}] // First
   {{1, 2, 3}, {2, 4, 6}}
```

The `Flatten[]` equivalent is then

```
Flatten[{{{1}, {2}, {3}}, {{2}, {4}, {6}}}, {{1}, {3, 2}}]
   {{1, 2, 3}, {2, 4, 6}}
```