# How to remove extra levels in list

Tags: list-manipulation, matrix

My question is how to turn a 4-level matrix (notice one extra level)

```
A = {{{{1, 2, 3}, {4, 5, 6}}}, {{{7, 8, 9}, {10, 11, 12}}}};
```

into the following:

```
B = {{{1, 2, 3}, {4, 5, 6}}, {{7, 8, 9}, {10, 11, 12}}};
```

I think `Flatten` might do the job but I was unable to understand how it works, especially with these matrix second argument.

So a more general question: is there a way to detect extra levels and eliminate them all together?

I am using Mathematica 10.4.1

Comment: Either `B = Flatten[A, 1]` or `B = Join @@ A` works.

Comment: That doesn't work.

Comment: Sorry, that was a typo.

Comment: Still not working, sorry.

Comment: Hm, it should work. Could you try restarting the kernel?

Comment: Join is working, but it feels cheating

Comment: Sorry, but are working now

Comment: Can you answer the general question about how Flatten works and how to remove extra levels in general? I will give you points. Thanks

Comment: `Flatten` by itself removes all `List`s. The second argument specifies which level it should remove. (e.g. `2` removes two enclosing `Lists`). If you put a list or a matrix in the second argument, it `Flatten`s those levels only. Here is a good explanation on that: [(119)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/119).

Comment: Have you even considered searching the site for "Flatten" before you posted your question?

Comment: Or `B = First /@ A`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In this case, I would recommend [`ArrayReshape`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ArrayReshape.html), which I think is easy to understand

Let

```
a = {{{{1, 2, 3}, {4, 5, 6}}}, {{{7, 8, 9}, {10, 11, 12}}}};
b = {{{1, 2, 3}, {4, 5, 6}}, {{7, 8, 9}, {10, 11, 12}}};
```

Now

```
Dimensions[b]
```

> `{2, 2, 3}`

So you want `a` to be reshaped into a 2 x 2 x 3 array; therefore,

```
ArrayReshape[a, {2, 2, 3}] == b
```

> `True`

#### Update

`ArrayReshape` can easily handle complicated cases of unwanted extra levels of `List` wrapping, which is something Mathematica is prone to produce. In general one can use

```
ArrayReshape[list, DeleteCases[Dimensions[list], 1]]
```

to unwrap sub-lists of one element. Thus,

```
ArrayReshape[a, DeleteCases[Dimensions[a], 1]] == b
```

> `True`

and

```
c = {{{{{{1}, {2}, {3}}, {{4}, {5}, {6}}}}, {{{{7}, {8}, {9}}, {{10}, {11}, {12}}}}}}
ArrayReshape[c, DeleteCases[Dimensions[c], 1]] == b
```

> `True`

Comment: You might consider addition a few of these points to Michael's answer here: [(105866)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/105866/121)

Comment: @Mr.Wizard. I added a comment to the answer you cite that links to this answer. I hope that's sufficient -- I feel uncomfortable making substantive edits to the answers. of others.

Answer (score 4):

**Example**

```
a = {{{{1, 2, 3}, {4, 5, 6}}}, {{{7, 8, 9}, {10, 11, 12}}}};
b = {{{1, 2, 3}, {4, 5, 6}}, {{7, 8, 9}, {10, 11, 12}}};

Flatten[a, 1]
```

**Output**

> {{{1, 2, 3}, {4, 5, 6}}, {{7, 8, 9}, {10, 11, 12}}}

**Test**

```
Flatten[a, 1] == b
```

> True

Answer (score 3):

I use `Join @@` (`@@` is shorthand for [`Apply`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Apply.html)) most of the time but version 10 introduced [`Catenate`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Catenate.html) which is now arguably the canonical method:

```
Catenate[A] === B   (* True *)
```

Be aware however that `Catenate` and `Flatten` unpack; this just came up in

- [Efficiently Delete Duplicates](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/123205/efficiently-delete-duplicates/123231#123231)