# Efficiently Delete Duplicates

Tags: list-manipulation, performance-tuning, memory

**The Goal**

I have a list consisting of 2 million lists of (positive) integers. The length of the list when flattened is about 60 million. The goal is to `Flatten` the list (`Catenate`) and delete all duplicates.

**The Issue**

The list consists of very large numbers (`>10^11`) and `DeleteDuplicates` causes the error `SystemException["MemoryAllocationFailure"]`.

**My Attempts**

As a dummy, let `list` be defined as:

```
a := RandomInteger[10^10, 30];
list = Table[a, 2*^6];
```

Using `Catenate` and `DeleteDuplicates` on `list` consumes a lot of memory:

```
MaxMemoryUsed[DeleteDuplicates@Catenate@list]
(* 3475344280 *)
```

I have tried `Fold`ing `Join` and `DeleteDuplicates`

```
Fold[DeleteDuplicates[Join[#1, #2]]&, {}, list]
```

It takes less memory but takes too much time (takes ~300x more time).

I attempted using [@RayKoopman 's method](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/2419/delete-duplicate-elements-from-a-list/35214#35214), which actually took more memory and crashed my computer.

```
DD[data_] := Part[data,Sort@Part[Range[Length@data][[#]],
   Most@FoldList[Plus,1,Length/@Split@data[[#]]]]]& @ Ordering@data;
DD@Catenate@list
```

**The Question**

How could one memory-efficiently remove all duplicates in a very long list?

Note: My list consists of only positive integers.

Comment: What percentage of duplicates do you have? If it is significant,  you could start with smaller pieces of your list and whittle those down,  to be reunited and treated later on.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Don't use [`Catenate`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Catenate.html); it is unpacking your lists!

```
On["Packing"]

Catenate[list] // ByteCount
```

> Developer`FromPackedArray::punpack1: Unpacking array with dimensions {30}. >>
>
> Developer`FromPackedArray::punpack1: Unpacking array with dimensions {30}. >>
>
> Developer`FromPackedArray::punpack1: Unpacking array with dimensions {30}. >>
>
> General::stop: Further output of Developer`FromPackedArray::punpack1 will be suppressed during this calculation. >>
>
> ```
> 1440000080
> ```

[`Join`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Join.html) instead:

```
Join @@ list // ByteCount   (* no messages *)
```

> ```
> 480000144
> ```

- On this packed array `DeleteDuplicates` works OK.
- [`MaxMemoryUsed`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/MaxMemoryUsed.html) is significant but not overwhelming for modern hardware.
- [`Union`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Union.html) is slightly more memory efficient if order does not matter.

Code:

```
DeleteDuplicates[Join @@ list] // ByteCount       (*  479855632   *)

DeleteDuplicates[Join @@ list] // MaxMemoryUsed   (*  2039547560  *)    

Union @@ list // MaxMemoryUsed                    (*  1936000536  *)
```

Answer (score 3):

I would use `Union @@ list`:

```
a := RandomInteger[10^10, 30];
list = Table[a, 2*^6];

MaxMemoryUsed[Union @@ list;]/MaxMemoryUsed[2 list;]
```

> 2.01666

If it is important that no sorting is applied, the following uses less memory than your `Fold` approach and its faster, though still slow (~sqrt(300)x more time)

```
Catenate[Reap[Nest[(Sow[First[#]]; DeleteCases[Rest[#],
  Alternatives @@ First[#]]) &, list, Length[list]]][[2, 1]]]
```

Comment: `Union` isn't really as important as avoiding `Catenate`, which you also did.  +1 nevertheless.

Answer (score 1):

Actually I do not agree with your statement that `DeleteDuplicates` uses a lot memory. Let us take your example and make some tests taking `MaxMemoryUsed[2 list]` as a reference:

```
MaxMemoryUsed[2 list]
(*960 000 520*)    

MaxMemoryUsed[Flatten[list]]/MaxMemoryUsed[2 list ] // N
(*2.74375*)

fl=Flatten[list];
MaxMemoryUsed[DeleteDuplicates[fl]]
(*2.12015*)

MaxMemoryUsed[DeleteDuplicates[Flatten[list]]]
(*3.62015*)
```

From this data we see that `DeleteDuplicates` uses a moderate amount of memory that is even smaller than that of `Flatten`! Notice also, that the memory scales *linearly* in all cases.