# How do I remove curly brackets around each element in a list?

Tags: list-manipulation

I have a list/array like so:

```
{{{1}, {2}, {3}, {4}, {5}, {6}}, {{7}, {8}, {9}, {10}, ... }}
```

I want to remove the curly brackets around each element (so I can use ListDensityPlot) so that I have:

> `{{1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6}, {7, 8, 9, ...}}`

Comment: `Flatten[{{{1, 2}, {3, 4}, {5, 6}}, {{7, 8}, {9, 10}}}, {{1}, {2, 3}}]`. (Pretty sure this is a dupe...)

Comment: Or perhaps even `Flatten /@ {{{1, 2}, {3, 4}, {5, 6}}, {{7, 8}, {9, 10}}}`

Comment: `{{{1}, {2}, {3}, {4}, {5}, {6}}, {{7}, {8}, {9}, {10}}}[[All, All, 1]]`

Comment: With white-out?

Answer (score 7):

```
list = {{{1}, {2}, {3}, {4}, {5}, {6}}, {{7}, {8}, {9}, {10}}};

Flatten /@ list
```

> {{1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6}, {7, 8, 9, 10}}

Or use the operator form

```
Map[Flatten] @ list
```

Answer (score 4):

Just to put my comment on record, I propose

```
{{{1}, {2}, {3}, {4}, {5}, {6}}, {{7}, {8}, {9}, {10}}}[[All, All, 1]]
```

which gives

> `{{1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6}, {7, 8, 9, 10}}`

Comment: I see that you have adopted [my solution](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/105897/121) since this was last asked. ;^)

Comment: @Mr.Wizard. Why not? Your methods are often the best, and I can still learn even at my advanced age.

Comment: I am sincerely flattered.  Also I strongly suspect your memory works better than mine, age notwithstanding.

Answer (score 1):

Given your list as:

```
list = {{{1}, {2}, {3}, {4}, {5}, {6}}, {{7}, {8}, {9}, {10}}};
```

Use  Flatten to remove the inner brackets.

```
Flatten /@ list
```

Which gives:

```
{{1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6}, {7, 8, 9, 10}}
```

Comment: Isn't this the same answer as eldo's above?