# NumericQ exercise in Wagner

Tags: numerics, homework, expression-test

I've been thinking about this exercise in [Wagner](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/22724/6555) (p. 269), but I can't answer. Can you tell me?

[image]

Comment: I think there are a few missing pieces in the problem description. `NumberQ[π]`, for instance, returns `False`. That means you have to check for a different attribute (hint, hint ;)).

Comment: I need to read that book more carefully!  I just learned something really surprising to me: **invalid syntax is NumericQ**.  `NumericQ@Mod[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]` yields `True`.  Thanks for asking this!

Comment: @Mr. Wizard, to give another pathology of `NumericQ[]`: it gives a `True` result for `QPochhammer[2]` even if that does not actually evaluate to a number with `N[]`.

Comment: @J.M. My eye have been opened. Good thing I do not write production code or I would have *a lot* of leaks to fix in my argument testing.  One I *was* aware of is that `_Symbol` will match `Symbol[foo, bar]`, `_Real` will match `Real[1,2,3]` etc.  Do any others common ones come to mind?  (I foolishly thought the Q tests were more robust.)

Comment: @Mr. Wizard, that prolly should be a separate question… :)

Comment: @J.M. I'll write it up if you promise to answer. :-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is a first attempt at implementing this, likely not robust.

```
SetAttributes[{attrQ, numberQ}, HoldAll];

attrQ[s_Symbol, attr_] := MemberQ[Attributes @ s, attr]

numberQ[x_] := NumberQ @ Unevaluated @ x || attrQ[x, Constant]

numericQ[expr_] :=
  Replace[
    Hold[expr],
    _?numberQ | h_[__?numberQ] /; attrQ[h, NumericFunction] :> 1,
    {1, -1}
  ] === Hold[1]
```

It matches the (surprising to me) behavior of `NumericQ` on:

```
numericQ[Mod[1, 2, 3, 4] + Pi^2]
```

> Mod::argt: Mod called with 4 arguments; 2 or 3 arguments are expected. >>
>
> ```
> True
> ```

`Replace` is used for a bottom-up collapse of the tree; for another example see:

- [How to remove redundant {} from a nested list of lists?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/20180/how-to-remove-redundant-from-a-nested-list-of-lists/20181#20181)

---

Here is a second attempt, this time using recursion, and not attempting to avoid evaluation of the elements to allow for cleaner code.

```
ClearAll[attrQ, numericQ]

Attributes[attrQ] = HoldAll;

attrQ[s_Symbol, attr_] := MemberQ[Attributes@s, attr]

numericQ[_?NumberQ] = True;
numericQ[s_ /; attrQ[s, Constant]] = True;
numericQ[h_[___?numericQ] /; attrQ[h, NumericFunction]] = True;
numericQ[_] = False;
```

Tests:

```
numericQ[E^(I Pi)]
numericQ[Mod[1, 2, 3, 4] + Pi^2]
numericQ[1 + 2^"x" + Pi^2]
numericQ[7 + foo[1, 2, Pi^2]]
```

> ```
> True
> ```
>
> Mod::argt: Mod called with 4 arguments; 2 or 3 arguments are expected. >>
>
> ```
> True
>
> False
>
> False
> ```

Comment: Interesting, yet Wagner asks about _recursive_ implementation ... Can we agree that's one weird exercise.

Comment: @BoLe Oh, let me think about that.

Comment: @BoLe, I suppose something along the lines of recursively checking `attrQ[head, NumericFunction]` until you hit an atom where `numberQ[]` can be applied as the base case.

Comment: I think this is it; `___?numericQ`, nice ...