# Create pattern to "redo" Nest for symbolic purposes, e.g. for commutators

Tags: pattern-matching, symbolic, expression-manipulation, functional-style

I am symbolically working with matrix commutators (`comm`) and face the following issue: There are nested commutators in my final results, defined as

```
NestedComm[mat1_, mat2_, n_] /; n > 1 := comm[NestedComm[mat1, mat2, n - 1], mat2];
NestedComm[mat1_, mat2_, 1] := comm[mat1, mat2];
NestedComm[mat1_, mat2_, 0] := mat1;
```

which due to the nature of the algorithm appear for instance as `comm[comm[comm[a,b],b],b]` in my final expressions. Note that the level of nesting `n` can in principle be anything from one to infinity. In order to make the results more readable, I am looking for a pattern or something else that would transform `comm[comm[comm[a, b], b], b]` to `nestedComm[a,b,3]` (the lowercase letter would be intended to avoid evaluation of the actual definition and to avoid the need of messing around with `Hold` and the like). The pattern should of course only apply if it is really a nested commutator according to the definition of `NestedComm` - there are also terms like `comm[comm[comm[a,b],c],b]` which should stay untouched by the transformation.

Is it somehow possible to automatically recognize this type of `Nest`ed functions and the corresponding level of nesting in order to replace them with a shorthand notation?

**Update:** It has not been clear from the question, that I do not want the nested `comm[]`objects to simplify automatically everywhere. Actually, my algorithm relies on them not being transformed to `nestedComm[]` throughout many steps of computation. But since the expressions may become quite involved and long, I would like to use a replacement rule/function/... on the final result, so that the nested objects are only simplified where I want them to be.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You might use transformation rules to transform nested commutators to `nestedComm` :

```
nestedCommRules = {
    comm[comm[a_, b_], b_] :> nestedComm[a, b, 2], 
    nestedComm[comm[a_, b_], b_, n_] :> nestedComm[a, b, n + 1]
}
```

(It's possible that you may want to include `comm[nestedComm[a_, b_, n_], b_] :> nestedComm[a, b, n + 1]` as well, but you don't need it for your example above.)

Then you can do

```
comm[comm[comm[a, b], b], b] //. nestedCommRules
(* nestedComm[a, b, 3] *)

comm[comm[comm[a, b], c], b] //. nestedCommRules
(* comm[comm[comm[a, b], c], b] *)
```

You mentioned pattern matching, so I'm not sure this answers your question fully.  Hopefully it's a start.

Note that you can use `NestedComm` instead of `nestedComm` if you implemented the original definitions of `NestedComm` using transformation rules rather than `SetDelayed`, but this is of course your choice.

Comment: Forgot about the power of `ReplaceRepeated` in this situation, thank you very much for pointing me to it!

Comment: I appreciate the accept, but I would highly recommend waiting a while.  Someone could very well give you a better answer -- there's a lot more to expression manipulation that I don't understand.

Comment: Ok, I will then wait another few days for people to reply ;)

Answer (score 4):

### Speed

We can make jjc385's operation far more efficient by replacing from the inside out, rather than repeatedly scanning the entire expression from the top down using `//.`, as explained in [How to remove redundant {} from a nested list of lists?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/20180/121) and elsewhere.

*Updated to scan only down to levelspec -3 for slightly improved efficiency.*

Let's compare performance on a deeply nested expression.

```
nestedCommRules = {comm[comm[a_, b_], b_] :> nestedComm[a, b, 2], 
  nestedComm[comm[a_, b_], b_, n_] :> nestedComm[a, b, n + 1]};

inOutRules = {comm[comm[a_, b_], b_] :> nestedComm[a, b, 2], 
   comm[nestedComm[a_, b_, n_], b_] :> nestedComm[a, b, n + 1]};

deep = Nest[comm[#, b] &, a, 5000];

deep //. nestedCommRules            // RepeatedTiming
Replace[deep, inOutRules, {0, -3}]  // RepeatedTiming
```

> ```
> {0.234, nestedComm[a, b, 5000]}
>
> {0.00388, nestedComm[a, b, 5000]}
> ```

### Simplicity

I would encourage you to consider a different form that makes replacement simpler: `comm[a, b, 3]` to represent `comm[comm[comm[a, b], b], b]`.

```
deep = Nest[comm[#, b] &, a, 5000];


rule = comm[comm[a_, b_, n_: 1], b_] :> comm[a, b, n + 1];

Replace[deep, rule, {0, -3}] // RepeatedTiming
```

> ```
> {0.00455, comm[a, b, 5000]}
> ```

If that format won't work for you then perhaps:

```
rule =
  comm[(nestedComm | comm)[a_, b_, n_: 1], b_] :> nestedComm[a, b, n + 1];

Replace[deep, rule, {0, -3}] // RepeatedTiming
```

> ```
> {0.00473, nestedComm[a, b, 5000]}
> ```

Comment: Sorry for the late response. Thank you very much for your answer and suggestions about the form of `comm`. Indeed, it is perfectly fine for me to use `comm[a,b,x]` to display nested commutators.

Answer (score 3):

An alternative is to use `TagSetDelayed[]` to set rules on how your `comm[]` and `nestedComm[]` objects should act. For instance:

```
comm /: comm[comm[x_, y_], y_] := nestedComm[x, y, 2];

comm /: comm[nestedComm[x_, y_, k_Integer?NonNegative], y_] := nestedComm[x, y, k + 1]
```

After evaluating those:

```
comm[comm[comm[a, b], b], b]
   nestedComm[a, b, 3]

comm[comm[comm[a, b], c], b]
   comm[comm[comm[a, b], c], b]
```

Comment: Thank you very much. Didn't know about `TagSetDelayed` until now. Very interesting. As I understand, there is no possibility to use this only in some expressions, right? I would evaluate `comm /: ...`, then reevaluate the expression in question and afterwards need to `ClearAll[comm]` again in order to not use the rules in subsequent computation?

Comment: Wait, you don't always want the nested `comm[]` objects to automatically simplify?

Comment: Right, sorry if that wasn't clear. Actually it is important that they are not simplified throughout my algorithm. But I would like to use some rule/function/... on my final result so that the nested `comm[]`objects are only simplified there. Will make that clearer in the question

Comment: In that case, jjc's replacement rules are definitely the way to go, and not this.

Comment: Right, but for a future application, your solution might be more applicable. Appreciate your answer anyways, although there was missing information on my side - sorry for that