# How to Flatten {1, {2, {3, 4}, 5}, 6} into {1, {2, 3, 4, 5}, 6}?

Tags: list-manipulation

**I've tried 3 methods but all failed to do that.**

1st Method

```
Apply[Flatten, {1, {2, {3, 4}, 5}, 6}, {2}]
```

2nd Method

```
Map[Flatten, {1, {2, {3, 4}, 5}, 6}, {2}]
```

3rd Method

```
Flatten[{1, {2, {3, 4}, 5}, 6}, {2}]
```

I wanna get {1, {2, 3, 4, 5}, 6}

Comment: This problem is very underspecified. You might be asking "flatten the deepest level across everything" like `{a, {b, c}, {d e}, f} -> {a,b,c,d,e,f}`. You might be asking "assuming things are nested x -> (A x B), flatten the deepest" (not the case since presumably you want this to also work on `{1,{2,3,4,5},6}`). You might be asking "flatten the second element". You might be asking "flatten the second element by one level". You need to either specify the problem unambiguously, and/or provide like 10 all-encompassing edge-case examples (e.g. the empty list, etc.).

Answer (score 21, accepted):

```
lst = {1, {2, {3, 4}, 5}, 6};
FlattenAt[lst, {2, 2}]
```

> {1, {2, 3, 4, 5}, 6}

Also

```
Map[## & @@ # &, lst, {2}]
```

> {1, {2, 3, 4, 5}, 6}

```
Replace[lst, List -> Sequence, {3}, Heads -> True]
```

> {1, {2, 3, 4, 5}, 6}

And

```
☺ = ## & @@@ # & /@ # &;
☺ @ lst
```

> {1, {2, 3, 4, 5}, 6}

Comment: Because this is an accepted answer, I suppose it is important to note a principal difference between `FlattenAt[lst, {2, 2}]` and the rest of the examples: `FlattenAt` flattens _position_, while, for example, `Replace[lst, List -> Sequence, {3}, Heads -> True]` flattens _level_.

Answer (score 14):

We've got a few answers already, but here's my 2 cents:

```
Replace[l_List :> Flatten[l]] /@ {1, {2, {3, 4}, 5}, 6}
```

> {1, {2, 3, 4, 5}, 6}

Comment: Is it possible to do this with ```Apply```?

Comment: Using `Apply` doesn't make much sense with `Flatten`, since `Flatten` is a single-argument function (It does have an infrequently-used but useful second argument, but still). `Apply` is more useful for multi-argument functions like `Join`, `List`, and `Plus`. Technically, `Flatten[{##}] & @@@ {1, {2, {3, 4}, 5}, 6}` works, but only because 1 and 6 are atomic. It wouldn't work with, e.g., `{Sin[1], {2, {3, 4}, 5}, Sin[6]}`, so it's not a very good way to do what you want.

Answer (score 11):

This will work:

```
l = {1, {2, {3, 4}, 5}, 6}
MapAt[Flatten, l, 2]
```

> {1, {2, 3, 4, 5}, 6}

also:

```
# /. x_ /; Length[x] > 1 :> Flatten@x & /@ l
```

> {1, {2, 3, 4, 5}, 6}

Answer (score 5):

```
list = {1, {2, {3, 4}, 5}, 6};
```

If we want do modify `list` directly there is `ApplyTo` (since V 12.2)

```
list[[2]] //= Flatten;

list
```

{1, {2, 3, 4, 5}, 6}

A more traditional and explicit approach is

```
list /. {a_, b_, c_} :> {a, Flatten[b], c}
```

{1, {2, 3, 4, 5}, 6}

Answer (score 4):

A couple more:

```
list = {1, {2, {3, 4}, 5}, 6};

Apply[## &, list, {2}]

Flatten[{##}] & @@@ list
```

Also if you are looking for specific level control consider *levelspec* in [`Replace`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Replace.html).  For example with:

```
rl = {a_, x__, z_} :> {a, {x} /. rl, z};
deep = Range[14] /. rl
```

> ```
> {1, {2, {3, {4, {5, {6, {7, 8}, 9}, 10}, 11}, 12}, 13}, 14}
> ```

Then:

```
Replace[deep, {x__} :> x, {3, 5}]
```

> ```
> {1, {2, {3, 4, 5, 6, {7, 8}, 9, 10, 11, 12}, 13}, 14}
> ```

Related:

- [How to remove redundant {} from a nested list of lists?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/20180/121)
- [How to avoid returning a Null if there is no "else" condition in an If construct](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/3700/121#3705)

Answer (score 3):

```
lst[[2]]=Flatten@lst[[2]];lst
```

> {1, {2, 3, 4, 5}, 6}

Also:

```
Delete[lst, {2,2,0}]
```

> {1, {2, 3, 4, 5}, 6}

Comment: The `Delete`-solution is so different, nice and funny, that I would have posted it as another answer.

Answer (score 2):

Using `Table`:

```
Table[If[ListQ[#[[i]]], Flatten[#[[i]]], #[[i]]], {i, Length@#}] &@list

(*{1, {2, 3, 4, 5}, 6}*)
```

Also, using `Cases`:

```
Cases[list, x_ :> If[ListQ[x], Flatten@x, x]]

(*{1, {2, 3, 4, 5}, 6}*)
```