# How to add a removed element to the associated sublist after manipulating a list

Tags: list-manipulation

I have the attached point list and use the following script to cluster the points. The clustering should just be applied to the first three-member of each sublist so I removed the fourth element from each sublist. However, after clustering the fourth member should be added to the associated sublist. How I can do that.
https://pastebin.com/SKvFEEQD

```
A11 = Drop[dataDCMp, None, {4}];
nng = NearestNeighborGraph[A11, 4];
ccmp = ConnectedComponents[nng];
```

Comment: You could try something like `NearestNeighborGraph[dataDCMp, 4, DistanceFunction -> (EuclideanDistance[#1[[;; 3]], #2[[;; 3]]] &)]`, which may take a while to finish.

Comment: Mehdi, can you try if `Extract[dataDCMp, List /@ ConnectedComponents[IndexGraph@nng]]` gives what you need?

Answer (score 1):

One way to do it, not efficient but overhead is small compared to generating the graph.

```
Import["https://pastebin.com/raw/SKvFEEQD"] // ToExpression;

(* Test on the first 100 to save time *)
assoc = <|Most@# -> Last@#|> & /@ dataDCMp[[1 ;; 100]];
A11 = assoc // Keys
nng = NearestNeighborGraph[A11, 4];
ccmp = ConnectedComponents[nng];

find[key_] := #[key] & /@ assoc // DeleteMissing

Map[Append[#, First@find[#]] &, ccmp, {-2}]
```

Comment: Thank you Rohit! Your code works but I am getting extra braces. I tried to remove them by flatten function but no proper answer. Do you have any idea what the solution is?

Comment: I found this "a //. {x_List} :> x " from former posts https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/20180/how-to-remove-redundant-from-a-nested-list-of-lists and it modified the braces. Thank you again, Rohit!

Comment: The analysis takes too long. Is there any way to do it faster?

Comment: @MehdiEbadi You mean time for `NearestNeighborGraph`?

Comment: Thank you Rohit! Now I realized that the speed is not too bad. I believe the problem was with my processor.

Comment: Hi Mehdi, glad that I could help. I am curious about the data and what you are trying to do with it. I plotted the first 3 members using `A11 // Flatten[#, 1] & // ListPlot3D` and it looks like mountain terrain.

Comment: Hi Rohit, It is part of the body torso. I could not upload it because of the capacity limitation of Pastebin.