# ReplaceRepeated seemingly omits some rules

Tags: replacement, rule

Is there a simple way in Mathematica to prevent rule reordering? Let me give an example:

```
a -> b //. {b -> c, (x_ -> y_) -> (x -> Expand[y])}
(* a -> b *)
```

though

```
a -> b /. {b -> c}
(* a -> c *)
```

works fine, of course. (I think that) *Mathematica* has determined that the second rule in expression 1 is more specific than the first rule and so has ordered it first. But, in the `ReplaceRepeated`, *Mathematica* now never checks the first rule. I realize that there are ways to rewrite this so that it works fine but is there a simple way to tell *Mathematica* not to reorder the rules? It seems like there should be.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

As István describes this has to do with the traversal direction of `//.`.  [`ReplaceAll`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/ReplaceAll.html) and by extension [`ReplaceRepeated`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/ReplaceRepeated.html) are very unusual in the context of *Mathematica* in that they perform a [depth-first *preorder* traversal](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/9233/how-to-perform-a-depth-first-preorder-traversal-of-an-expression), whereas nearly all other functions perform a depth-first *postorder* traversal.  Since it is the latter that you want here you merely need to use [`Replace`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Replace.html) instead of `ReplaceRepeated` (with the correct [*levelspec*](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/29750/121)), and you can complete the behavior with [`FixedPoint`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/FixedPoint.html).

```
postorderReplaceRepeated[expr_, rules_] :=
  FixedPoint[Replace[#, rules, {0, -1}, Heads->True] &, expr]

postorderReplaceRepeated[a -> b, {b -> c, (x_ -> y_) :> (x -> Expand[y])}]
```

> ```
> a -> c
> ```

(Note: be sure to use [`RuleDelayed`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/RuleDelayed.html) (short form `:>`) when working with named patterns on the right-hand side unless you specifically know otherwise.)

Comment: Wow. Very nice. I wasn't aware of the intricacies of tree traversal order, in particular that Replace with all levels included and applied repeatedly is different from  ReplaceAll (of course, I wish the Mathematica documentation stated some of this ;-( ). István, of course, got the reason for the problem correct and offered useful suggestions, but your method does essentially fix it. Thanks.

Comment: Hi. I added Heads->True to the options for Replace, since I think this better mimics the behavior of ReplaceRepeated. Also, do you mind explaining what the levelspec of {0,-1} does vs. {0,Infinity}? I don't understand (including from the documentation) what the -1 level spec refers to.

Comment: @jondaman21 Good catch on `Heads -> True`!  Levels are described and illustrated by several people [here](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/15567/121) -- I like *both* David's and Rahul's graphics myself.  In this case `{0, -1}` and `{0, Infinity}` should behave the same; the first is simply faster to write.

Answer (score 15):

There is no reordering: `ReplaceRepeated` simply starts replacement from the outside of the expression. For example here the result is not `f[g[g[1]]]` but:

```
 f[f[f[1]]] //. f[f[x_]] :> g[g[x]]   (*   ==> g[g[f[1]]] *)
```

So in your case, the first rule that is matched is the second one, which happens to be more general (but it has nothing to do with evaluation order). `Print` statements make it explicit that indeed the first rule is not tried at all:

```
a -> b //. {b -> (Print[1]; c), (x_ -> y_) :> (x -> (Print[2]; Expand[y]))}
```

> ```
> During evaluation of In[12]:= 2
>
> a -> b
> ```

There are at least two ways to overcome this. First, you can apply rules repeatedly from the inside (deepest-level-first). Giving explicit (reversed) level specifications to `Replace` inside `Fold` will do the replacements from inside->out.

```
expr = a -> b;
rules = {b :> (Print[1]; c), (x_ -> y_) :> (x -> (Print[2]; Expand[y]))};

Fold[Replace[#1, rules, {#2}] &, expr, Reverse@Range[0, Depth@expr]]
```

> ```
> During evaluation of In[83]:= 1
>
> During evaluation of In[83]:= 2
>
> a -> c
> ```

Other way is to specify an explicit order of the rules to be applied:

```
Fold[ReplaceRepeated, expr, rules]
```

> ```
> During evaluation of In[16]:= 1
>
> During evaluation of In[16]:= 2
>
> a -> c
> ```

Note that the two approaches are not identical: the second one might do repeated replacements per iteration of `Fold`, while the first one only tries each rule once per iteration of `Fold`.

Comment: Ok, but why isn't `b->c` applied to `a->b` after the rule `(x_ -> y_) -> (x -> Expand[y])` operates (and does nothing)? Isn't the idea of ReplaceRepeated to keep replacing until it can no longer be done? What would be a procedural algorithm for ReplaceRepeated?