# How to test if $ⅈ$ is in an expression?

Tags: expression-manipulation, expression-test, searching

From this answer https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/9773/68791 and according to [the documentation](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/TestingAndSearchingListElements.html):

> `FreeQ[list,form]`    test whether form occurs nowhere in list

However, I encountered some oddities:

```
expr = x[0] + (-(1/2) - (I*Sqrt[3])/2)*x[1] + (-(1/2) + (I*Sqrt[3])/2)*x[2];
FreeQ[expr, I]
(* True -- I *is not* in expr whereas it obviously is *)

FreeQ[expr, I/2]
(* False -- I/2 *is* in expr *)
```

By using `TreeForm` it seems to me than `I/2` is handled as an atom, and not as a compound expression `Div[I,2]`.

[image]

**How can I reliably test if $\large ⅈ$ (or any complex with a non-zero imaginary part) is in an expression?**

Comment: How would one treat things like `ArcSin[2]`? I assume it should be flagged as a nonreal, complex number.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Look at the [`FullForm`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/FullForm.html). This is what Mathematica actually sees.

```
expr // FullForm

Plus[x[0], 
 Times[Plus[Rational[-1, 2], 
   Times[Complex[0, Rational[-1, 2]], Power[3, Rational[1, 2]]]], x[1]], 
 Times[Plus[Rational[-1, 2], 
   Times[Complex[0, Rational[1, 2]], Power[3, Rational[1, 2]]]], x[2]]
 ]

I/2 // FullForm

Complex[0,Rational[1,2]]
```

`I` is really `Complex[0, 1]` so Mathematica searches for that specifically. If you just want to find a `Complex` number use `FreeQ[_Complex]`

If you have to deal with the corner cases where the expression may contain `Complex[_, 0.]` or `Complex[_, 0]`, you should use `FreeQ[Complex[_, n_?(#==0.&)]]`

Comment: Isn't there some corner cases where an expression would contain `Complex[ _, 0]`?

Comment: @SylvainLeroux that can't happen unless stuff is held, but `Complex[1, 0.]` can. On the other hand, you can catch that with `FreeQ[Complex[_, n_?(#==0.&)]]`. The bigger point is that you need to think about _true_ form of an expression when pattern matching, not the one you see displayed.

Comment: It could happen if in `Complex[x, 0]`, x is not a number. E.g. `Complex[Sqrt[2], 0]`.  These forms do not arise from normal arithmetic/algebraic computations done by *Mathematica*, however.  They would have be the result of some explicit construction of a `Complex` expression (by the user).

Comment: @MichaelE2 interesting! Didn't realize that would happen

Comment: So that brings back to my original question: "how to can I _reliably_ test if ⅈ (or any complex with a non-zero imaginary part) is in an expression?"

Comment: @SylvainLeroux I literally gave that to you... `FreeQ[Complex[_, n_?(#==0.&)]]`

Comment: Sorry @b3m2a1, I didn't get that `0==0.` was true.

Comment: @SylvainLeroux `0==0.` but `0=!=0.`

Comment: Thanks, @b3m2a1. I took the liberty to edit your answer with the version you gave in the comment above. I hope you'll be OK with that.

Comment: @b3m2a1 Could you check if the proper test is `Complex[_, n_?(#==0.&)]` or `Complex[_, n_?(#!=0.&)]`? It seems to be the later is the correct solution since `FreeQ` returns `True` when the pattern is *not* found.