# Removing calls to MainEvalute when using inlined compiled closures

Tags: performance-tuning, compile

This question is tightly related to the answer [Shaving the last 50 ms off NMinimize](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/4877/745).

There @OleksandR shows how inlined closures can be used to eliminate calls to `MainEvaluate`. This is crucial for my application, since I need every last drop of performance mma can offer. Here is an extremely simplified working example (before you run this code, make sure to evaluate [this package](http://w910989.open.ge.tt/1/files/86WpmcH/0/blob?download), containing the NelderMeadMinimize code):

```
Needs["CompiledFunctionTools`"]
With[{minimizer = 
    NelderMeadMinimize`Dump`CompiledNelderMead[
     Function[{a, b, c}, (a - d1)^2 + (b - d2)^2 + (c - d3)^2], {a, b, c},
        "ReturnValues" -> "OptimizedParameters"], 
   epsilon = $MachineEpsilon},
  orgFitter = 
   Compile[{{d1, _Real, 0}, {d2, _Real, 0}, {d3, _Real, 0}}, 
    minimizer[RandomReal[{0, 1}, {3 + 1, 3}], epsilon, -1], 
    CompilationOptions -> {"InlineCompiledFunctions" -> True}, 
    RuntimeOptions -> {"Speed", "EvaluateSymbolically" -> False}]];
StringMatchQ[CompilePrint[orgFitter], "*MainEvaluate*"]
(* -> False *)
orgFitter[12, 2, 3]
```

Now, if I change `(a - d1)^2 + (b - d2)^2 + (c - d3)^2` to calling a compiled function the calls to `MainEvalute` are not eliminated! Please, instead of the simple `myHi2` imagine a monster of a compiled procedure containing several hundred lines.

```
myHi2 = Compile[{{a, _Real, 0}, {b, _Real, 0}, {c, _Real, 
     0}, {d1, _Real, 0}, {d2, _Real, 0}, {d3, _Real, 
     0}}, (a - d1)^2 + (b - d2)^2 + (c - d3)^2];
With[{minimizer = 
    NelderMeadMinimize`Dump`CompiledNelderMead[
     Function[{a, b, c}, myHi2[a, b, c, d1, d2, d3]], {a, b, c}, 
     "ReturnValues" -> "OptimizedParameters"], 
   epsilon = $MachineEpsilon},
  orgFitter = 
   Compile[{{d1, _Real, 0}, {d2, _Real, 0}, {d3, _Real, 0}}, 
    minimizer[RandomReal[{0, 1}, {3 + 1, 3}], epsilon, -1], 
    CompilationOptions -> {"InlineCompiledFunctions" -> True, 
      "InlineExternalDefinitions" -> True}, 
    RuntimeOptions -> {"Speed", "EvaluateSymbolically" -> False}]];
StringMatchQ[CompilePrint[orgFitter], "*MainEvaluate*"]
(* -> True *)
orgFitter[12., 2., 3.]
```

**How can I eliminate this calls to `MainEvaluate`?**

Also, could someone help me understand, why this does not compile:

```
orgFitter = Compile[{{d1, _Real, 0}, {d2, _Real, 0}, {d3, _Real, 0}},
   With[{minimizer = 
      NelderMeadMinimize`Dump`CompiledNelderMead[
       Function[{a, b, c}, (a - d1)^2 + (b - d2)^2 + (c - d3)^2], {a, 
        b, c}, "ReturnValues" -> "OptimizedParameters"], 
     epsilon = $MachineEpsilon},
    minimizer[RandomReal[{0, 1}, {3 + 1, 3}], epsilon, -1]], 
   CompilationOptions -> {"InlineCompiledFunctions" -> True, 
     "InlineExternalDefinitions" -> True}, 
   RuntimeOptions -> {"Speed", "EvaluateSymbolically" -> False}];

CompilePrint[orgFitter]
```

Answer (score 21, accepted):

This is actually not specific to the `` NelderMeadMinimize` ``  package but rather a limitation of the behaviour of `Compile` with respect to `CompilationOptions -> {"InlineCompiledFunctions" -> True}`. Essentially, compiled functions will only be inlined (in most cases) if they appear *lexically* in the input to `Compile`. You can ensure that in three main ways:

#### Nested `With`

This is my preferred approach of the three shown here (although [Leonid's `LetL` macro](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/10451/312) would be even more preferable). Unfortunately it's a little difficult to demonstrate it without copying your code out in full, but hopefully this abbreviated version is clear enough. Instead of writing

```
myHi2 = Compile[...];
With[{minimizer = ..., ...}, ...]
```

you can use

```
With[{myHi2 = Compile[...]},
 With[{minimizer = ..., ...}, ...]
]
```

which ensures that `myHi2` is never encountered by `Compile` as an opaque function call, but rather as a compiled function. It is then inlined correctly.

#### `"RuntimeOptions" -> {"EvaluateSymbolically" -> False}` and `Evaluate`

Simply define

```
myHi2 = Compile[
 {{a, _Real, 0}, {b, _Real, 0}, {c, _Real, 0},
  {d1, _Real, 0}, {d2, _Real, 0}, {d3, _Real, 0}},
 (a - d1)^2 + (b - d2)^2 + (c - d3)^2,
 "RuntimeOptions" -> {"EvaluateSymbolically" -> False}
];
```

and you can then use

```
With[{minimizer = ... Evaluate@myHi2[...] ..., ...}, ...]
```

If you weren't to use `"RuntimeOptions" -> {"EvaluateSymbolically" -> False}`, you would see a message and the code may possibly be compiled incorrectly, especially if you have stray values in your session or the real `myHi2` contains procedural code.

#### Manual inlining

Well, I don't mean completely manually. Here is a function that does what `CompilationOptions -> {"InlineCompiledFunctions" -> True}` does, without requiring that option (this was very useful prior to version 8, and indeed you can probably see that this code is of a certain vintage).

```
ClearAll[EvaluatePattern];
EvaluatePattern[expr_, patt_, opts___] :=
  Module[{holdTemporary},
   If[Hold /. {opts} /. Options[EvaluatePattern, Hold],
    SetAttributes[holdTemporary, HoldAll]
   ];
   Identity @@ ReplaceRepeated[
    holdTemporary[expr],
    p : patt :> With[{eval = p}, eval /; True],
    MaxIterations -> (
     MaxIterations /. {opts} /. Options[EvaluatePattern, MaxIterations]
    )
   ]
  ];
Attributes[EvaluatePattern] = {HoldFirst};
Options[EvaluatePattern] = {MaxIterations -> $IterationLimit, Hold -> False};
```

That was just a wrapper that gives more control over the [Trott-Strzebonski device](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/2680/745). It can be done more concisely (and, I think, clearly) using `RuleCondition` directly, but I didn't know about `RuleCondition` when I wrote the above, and as it's undocumented others may not recognise it either. Here comes the function we require in the present context:

```
ClearAll[InlineFunctionCalls];
InlineFunctionCalls[expr_, opts___] :=
 EvaluatePattern[
  expr, 
  sym_Symbol /; MemberQ[{Function, CompiledFunction, LibraryFunction}, Head[sym]],
  Sequence @@ Thread[
    {MaxIterations, Hold} -> (
      {MaxIterations, Hold} /. {opts} /.
       Options[InlineFunctionCalls, {MaxIterations, Hold}]
      )
    ]
  ];
Attributes[InlineFunctionCalls] = {HoldFirst};
Options[InlineFunctionCalls] = {MaxIterations -> $IterationLimit, Hold -> True};
```

Now we can just write

```
myHi2 = Compile[...];
With[{minimizer = ... // InlineFunctionCalls, ...}, ...]
```

which will catch and inline all external `Function`, `CompiledFunction`, and `LibraryFunction` objects (and more reliably so than `Compile` itself).

## Edit

I forgot to mention why the final example doesn't compile. The reason is that `Compile` is `HoldAll` and it doesn't do a lot of analysis of its argument to find out whether it is compilable or not--if it's [not on the list](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/1096/list-of-compilable-functions/1101#1101), it's not coming in. In this case `Compile` can't tell that `` NelderMeadMinimize`Dump`CompiledNelderMead `` produces a compiled function, so here it's your responsibility to generate the closure first:

```
orgFitter = With[{
    minimizer = NelderMeadMinimize`Dump`CompiledNelderMead[
      Function[{a, b, c}, (a - d1)^2 + (b - d2)^2 + (c - d3)^2], {a, b, c},
      "ReturnValues" -> "OptimizedParameters"
     ],
    epsilon = $MachineEpsilon
   },
   Compile[{{d1, _Real, 0}, {d2, _Real, 0}, {d3, _Real, 0}},
    minimizer[RandomReal[{0, 1}, {3 + 1, 3}], epsilon, -1],
    CompilationOptions -> {
     "InlineCompiledFunctions" -> True, "InlineExternalDefinitions" -> True
    },
    RuntimeOptions -> {"Speed", "EvaluateSymbolically" -> False}
   ]
  ];
```

Comment: Thank you for the great answer! What exactly does lexically mean in this context? In my original example I thought that the `With` block would inject the minimize inside the `Compile` block before anything else happens, so that myHi2 would effectively appear inside `Compile`. Well obviously I was wrong and it's not that simple:)

Comment: Also, regarding my last example that has `Compile` on the outside. Do you think it would be possible to use `Internal`CompileValues` to make  `NelderMeadMinimize`Dump`CompiledNelderMead` compilable? (asking purely out of curiosity, since you have already presented 3 solutions to my problem:)

Comment: @Ajasja your `With` *did* successfully inject the minimizer into the compiled code--but you hadn't followed that through to its logical conclusion and injected `myHi2` into the minimizer (remember, `Function` is `HoldAll` too). Once you've dealt with all the dependencies, everything should work out automatically. BTW, I forgot to mention that inlining like this avoids the need for `CompilationOptions -> "InlineCompiledFunctions" -> True` in all cases (AFAIK) *except* that of compiled closures, which won't work otherwise (and also aren't supported prior to version 8).

Comment: @Ajasja as far as using ``Internal`CompileValues`` goes, the answer is probably yes but I'm not certain how to do it. These values are only looked at fairly deep inside `Compile` and after a lot of preprocessing has already been done, so I don't really know exactly what's supported using this mechanism. The function ``Internal`CompileInline`` probably has something to do with what you're after, but I've no idea how to use it.