# Catching and debugging numerical errors in compiled functions

Tags: compile, debugging

I have a compiled function (that was created using the [second method](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/13289/745) of this question). Basically it's using a compiled closure. The problem is that for some parameter values it does not evaluate. Here is a small example:

```
(*just some function that has a singularity at x=5*)
f = Compile[{{x, _Real, 0}, {a, _Real, 0}}, Sin[a*x*Pi/180]/(x - 5)
   , RuntimeOptions -> {"Speed", "EvaluateSymbolically" -> False}];

(*The wrapper just increments the x values by diff. Aa is the 
variable that is supposed to be inlined in the closure*)
Block[{Aa},
  With[{wrapper = 
     Compile[{{x, _Real, 0}, {diff, _Real, 0}}, 
      Evaluate@f[x + diff, Aa]]},
   min = Compile[{{xs, _Real, 1}, {Aa, _Real, 0}, {diff, _Real, 0}},
     First@Sort[wrapper[#, diff] & /@ xs]
     , CompilationOptions -> {"InlineCompiledFunctions" -> True, 
       "InlineExternalDefinitions" -> True, 
       "ExpressionOptimization" -> True}, 
     RuntimeOptions -> {"Speed"}](*compile*)
   ]
  ];

(*The warning is harmeless*)
(*CompiledFunction::cfsa:Argument diff+x at position 1 should be a machine-size real number. >>*)

(*The function is compiled*)
Needs["CompiledFunctionTools`"]
CompilePrint[min]


        3 arguments
        9 Integer registers
        11 Real registers
        3 Tensor registers
        Underflow checking off
        Overflow checking off
        Integer overflow checking off
        RuntimeAttributes -> {}

        T(R1)0 = A1
        R0 = A2
        R1 = A3
        I7 = 0
        I6 = -5
        I3 = 1
        R6 = 3.141592653589793
        I5 = 180
        Result = R7

1   I2 = Length[ T(R1)0]
2   I8 = I7
3   T(R1)1 = Table[ I2]
4   I4 = I7
5   goto 20
6   R3 = GetElement[ T(R1)0, I4]
7   R2 = R1
8   R5 = R2 + R3
9   R4 = R0
10  R8 = I5
11  R9 = Reciprocal[ R8]
12  R8 = R6 * R9
13  R9 = R4 * R5 * R8
14  R8 = Sin[ R9]
15  R9 = I6
16  R10 = R5 + R9
17  R9 = Reciprocal[ R10]
18  R8 = R8 * R9
19  Element[ T(R1)1, I8] = R8
20  if[ ++ I4 < I2] goto 6
21  T(R1)2 = Sort[ T(R1)1]]
22  R7 = Part[ T(R1)2, I3]
23  Return
```

But then here are the use cases:

```
(*everything works OK even though the singularity is in the arguments*)
min[{1,5,5},1,0]
(*=> -0.0043631*)
```

But for some arguments it does not:

```
(*But if all the arguments are singularites: BLAM!*)
min[{5,5,5},1,0]

(*=> CompiledFunction[{x,a},Sin[(a x \[Pi])/180]/(x-5),-CompiledCode-][5,Aa] *)
```

> ```
>    CompiledFunction::cfne: Numerical error encountered; proceeding with uncompiled evaluation. >>
>    CompiledFunction::cfse: Compiled expression Aa should be a machine-size real number. >>
>    CompiledFunction::cfex: Could not complete external evaluation at instruction 2; proceeding with uncompiled evaluation. >>
> ```

Questions:

- Why is this working if some of the arguments give division by zero, but does not evaluate if all of the arguments are incorrect?
- **How can one debug such problems?** There is nothing obviously wrong at instruction 2 in the compiled output...
- How to guard against and/or catch such errors in compiled code?

Comment: I can't see the code so it's hard to investigate. But in here, I get a result, with these 2 warnings: "CompiledFunction::cfse: Compiled expression blalbab should be a machine-size real number", and "CompiledFunction::cfex: Could not complete external evaluation at instruction 27; proceeding with uncompiled evaluation"

Comment: So perhaps something inside your code doesn't return what it should for those inputs?

Comment: @Rojo Thanks for confirming the error, I thought I was going crazy... :=) I don't see what could possibly be returning an unexpected output (but I'll triple check). By the way: This function is a compiled Nelder-Mead algorithm.

Comment: Honestly, I don't have a clue what the problem might be here (i.e. why `Aspectrum` is not being inlined; everything else looks okay except that there's obviously something amiss with the `CompilePrint` output given the `InputForm`). Can you upload the complete code somewhere?

Comment: @OleksandrR. I posted a small working example.

Comment: @Rojo You are probably right, now the question is how to best find this :)

Comment: The problem arises when you try to *return* an infinity; that this occurs only when the arguments are all the same is a side effect of your returning the smallest element (try `Last@Sort[...]` instead). Interestingly the VM appears to be able to deal with machine infinities during calculations, so it's really a question of how to convert these into `ComplexInfinity` without causing a numerical error. If you compile this to C you could manually edit the C code, but I don't really know how to do it just using *Mathematica*.

Comment: Er... wherever those parameters are used, could you switch `param` for `Abs[param]`? The N-M method doesn't readily admit constraints imposed by returning a large value (which is a method I often use with differential evolution) because the simplex can easily get stuck in a marginally feasible region with this approach. Instead I think you will have better luck if you can transform your objective function so that its domain is bounded. Be careful that it remains unimodal, otherwise you'll run into additional difficulties.

Comment: Yes, that's true... however both/all of the resulting minima will be true global optima, so provided they're reasonably far apart in phase space you'll probably be okay. I was thinking more of the situation whereby a transformation introduces spurious local optima, as it's these that the N-M method has the most difficulty with. As for clipping... it could work, but reflection from the constraint boundary will probably be more effective. By clipping alone you risk introducing large expanses of phase space that have the same function values, which is generally harmful.

Answer (score 5):

**Note: the following applies only to *Mathematica* 8 and above. In previous versions the numerical error occurs immediately when a NaN or inf value is produced, so that avoiding it will be much more difficult.**

The reason this occurs is that, although the VM can work with IEEE NaN/inf internally without a problem, *Mathematica* does not actually support these values at a higher level, using `Indeterminate` and `DirectedInfinity` instead. But, these are symbolic values that cannot appear in a packed array, so that it is basically impossible to pass them in and out of compiled code. As a result, even though the compiled code arrives at the expected answer without a problem, the attempt to return this to the top level triggers a numerical error.

To avoid it, one can perhaps test the result of the calculation and send back not only the value itself, but also a flag indicating the existence of a non-numerical or infinite quantity if this appears. For instance:

```
cf = With[{$MaxMachineNumber = $MaxMachineNumber},
  Compile[{{a, _Real, 0}, {b, _Real, 0}},
   Block[{
     inf = 2. $MaxMachineNumber,
     result = a/b, flag = 0
    },
    Which[
     result == inf, result = 0; flag = 1,
     result != result, result = 0; flag = 2,
     True, Null
    ];
    {result, flag}
   ]
  ]
 ];

cf[1, 2]
(* -> {0.5, 0.}, result is numeric *)

cf[1, 0]
(* -> {0., 1.}, result is infinity *)

cf[0, 0]
(* -> {0., 2.}, result is not-a-number *)
```