# How to handle numerical exception within a compiled function

Tags: compile, error-trapping

I'm trying to evaluate a series of expressions, which, given a set of parameters, may be complex. Instead of throwing a `CompiledFunction::cfn`, I'm trying to catch it from within and reset it to some default value. Example:

```
cf = With[{NOTREAL = -1}, Compile[{{x, _Real}}, {Sqrt[x], Sqrt[-x]}]]
cf[100]
```

I want the return to be `{10, -1}` without invoking uncompiled function or `MainEvaluate`. If I used `"RuntimeOptions"` per [Catching error in middle of evaluation of compiled function](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/61596/catching-error-in-middle-of-evaluation-of-compiled-function), the error would still be thrown and the evaluation wil be aborted. Is it possible to tell Mathematica to not evaluate when it sees a non-numeric value coming up and hand it over to some handler? And in reality `Sqrt[x]` will be replaced with some complicated function. `Reduce` can't figure out when it'll be real.

Comment: What about `If[Abs[Im[x]]>1. 10^-12,{Sqrt[x],-1.},{Sqrt[x],Sqrt[-x]}]`?

Comment: @HenrikSchumacher It worked! I tried `Im/@` before posting but the same error is thrown, but directly applying `Im` to each result prevents it. Might have to do with how type inference works.

Comment: That's good to hear! Best practice is to catch errors before they occur... ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thanks to @HenrikSchumacher 's comment, I came up with the following

```
cf = With[{NOTREAL = -1}, Compile[{{x, _Real}},
   Module[{cx = I},
    cx = x;
    If[Abs[Im@#] > 1.*^-12, NOTREAL, Re@#] & /@ {Sqrt[-cx], Sqrt[cx]}]]
  ]
```

`CompilePrint` shows that this forces Mathematica to recognize the result of `Sqrt` as complex, avoiding numerical exception.