# Efficient compilation of a list of functions

Tags: performance-tuning, function-construction, compile

Let's say that we have at our disposal

```
nbfunc = 4;
```

functions, whose exact expressions are gathered in the list

```
tabfunc = Table[LegendreP[n,x], {n, 1, nbfunc}];
```

For the purpose of the example, I gave myself the list of Legendre polynomials, whose evaluation can be compiled.
For a given run, the number of functions `nbfunc` and their expressions `tabfunc` are fixed forever.
But, they may change from one run to another.

Now, I would like to evaluate efficiently the function `f[neval_,xeval_]` defined as

```
f[neval_,xeval_] := tabfunc[[neval]] /. {x -> xeval};
```

where the integer `neval` is always assumed to satisfy `1 <= neval <= nbfunc`.
I can compile this evaluation by defining the function `fC` as

```
fC = Compile[{{n, _Integer}, {x, _Real}},
tabfunc[[n]],
CompilationTarget -> "C",
CompilationOptions -> {"ExpressionOptimization" -> True, "InlineCompiledFunctions" -> True, "InlineExternalDefinitions" -> True},
RuntimeOptions -> {"CatchMachineOverflow" -> False , "CatchMachineUnderflow" -> False, "CatchMachineIntegerOverflow" -> False, "CompareWithTolerance" -> False, "EvaluateSymbolically" -> False}];
```

The compilation works correctly (in particular no calls to `MainEvaluate`), and the timings are improved

```
f[4, 0.2] == fC[4, 0.2]
Table[f[4, 0.2], {i, 1, 1000}]; // AbsoluteTiming // First
Table[fC[4, 0.2], {i, 1, 1000}]; // AbsoluteTiming // First
(*True
0.005839
0.000169*)
```

Yet, when inspecting the compiled code of `fC`,

```
Needs["CompiledFunctionTools`"];
CompilePrint[fC]
```

we note that the code contains lines of the form

```
22  T(R1)0 = {R0, R6, R8, R5}
23  R6 = Part[ T(R1)0, I0]
24  Return
```

This implies that to compute `fC[4,0.2]`, the compiled function first computes the list `{f[1,0.2],f[2,0.2],f[3,0.2],f[4,0.2]}`, then returns the fourth element of this list, i.e. the value `f[4,0.2]`.
Unfortunately, this is unsatisfactory, as to compute `fC[4,0.2]`, there should be no need to compute all the others `f[i,0.2]` for `1<=i<=3`.

My question is therefore as follows:

How should one proceed to compile the function `fC[n_,x_]`, so that only the needed expression for the `n` that is asked is effectively evaluated?

In particular, I face the difficulty that the number `nbfunc` may change from one run to another (and can be quite large), so that this cannot be done by hand.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since `Which` is compilable, you can try this:

```
fC = Block[{n},
   With[{

    code = Which @@Join[Riffle[Thread[n == Range[nbfunc]], N[tabfunc]], {True,0.}]

    },
    Compile[{{n, _Integer}, {x, _Real}},
     code,
     CompilationTarget -> "C",
     Parallelization -> True,
     RuntimeAttributes -> {Listable},
     RuntimeOptions -> "Speed"
     ]
    ]
   ];
```

This way, the function is both listable and parallelized (although parallelization does not help very much):

```
k = 1000000;
fC[RandomInteger[{1, 4}, k], RandomReal[{-1, 1}, k]]; // 
  AbsoluteTiming // First
```

Don't forget to give a default case (with `True`); it might not work otherwise. Notice also how I inlined the actual code with `With` in order to "precompute" what can be computed in advance. The respective `"CompilationOptions"` for inlining are infamous for their lack of robustness.

Comment: Thank you very much for your prompt answer! To be sure, I understand all the details, could you elaborate on:
(i) "Notice also how inlined the actual code with With in order to precompute what can be computed in advance.": I am not sure I understand what this means, could you explain it to me?

(ii) "The respective CompilationOptions for inlining are infamous for their lack of robustness.": I was unaware of these infamous issues, would you have a relevant link to point me to?

Comment: Right, there is no real computation done. What I meant is that the expression for `code` is create. But one _can_ performs some simplifications in advance, for example, the conversion to machine floating point numbers of the constants in `tabfunc`; otherwise, these conversion will be done by type casts at runtime.

Comment: Towards (ii): https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/13289