# Function in Table

Tags: list-manipulation, function-construction, functional-style, faq

I need a table with the elements made of pure functions and list elements. This is a simplified example:

I need a list as:

```
{a[[1]]*Sin[#]&,a[[2]]*Sin[#]&,a[[3]]*Sin[#]&}
```

and, my failed try is : `Table[a[[i]]*Sin[#]&,{i,3}]`

Why is the failure and how can I improve it?

Comment: What's `a` supposed to be? Do you need something like the result of `Function[c, c Sin[#] &] /@ Range[3]` or `Table[With[{cs = c}, cs Sin[#] &], {c, Range[3]}]`?

Comment: [This](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7523836/evaluate-seems-to-not-work-inside-button/) may be relevant.

Comment: @R.M, that puts the constant outside the `Function[]` as opposed to the inside, no?

Comment: @WReach, nice to see you around. Undelete your post!!

Comment: Also, I illustrate various techniques of generating lists of pure functions with injected elements (very close to what you ask for), in [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6470625/mathematica-table-function/6471024#6471024).

Comment: @LeonidShifrin, you'll make him cry while trying to follow that code!

Comment: @Rojo But the part on pure functions is in the middle of the post, and independent on anything else - have a look.

Comment: @LeonidShifrin I see. Then you'll make him happy :)

Comment: Rojo, JM: you're right. Heh, I need breakfast

Comment: Wow, Rojo and WReach posted at the exact same time, down to the second!

Comment: @R.M. Apparently, one second granuarity is not enough (too coarse).

Comment: My favorites for this problem would still be either `Range[3] /. i_Integer :> (a[[i]] Sin[#] &)` or `Array[Function[x, a[[x]] Sin[#] &], {3}]`.

Comment: Has anyone mentioned Evaluate?"Table[Evaluate[a[[i]]*Sin[#]]&,{i,3}]"

Answer (score 45, accepted):

`Function` has the attribute `HoldAll`, so the reference to `i` in the `Table` expression will not be expanded.

However, you can use `With` to inject the value into the held expressions:

```
Table[With[{i = i}, a[[i]]*Sin[#] &], {i, 3}]
```

> ```
> {a[[1]] Sin[#1] &, a[[2]] Sin[#1] &, a[[3]] Sin[#1] &}
> ```

This issue will be present not only for `Function` but for all expressions that hold their arguments (via attributes like `HoldFirst`) -- for example: `Plot`, `Dynamic`, `RuleDelayed (:>)` etc.

The solution using `With` is mentioned in the tutorial "[**Introduction To Dynamic / A Good Trick to Know**](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/IntroductionToDynamic.html#2125133640)".

Comment: If I do `a = Range[3]; Table[With[{i = i}, a[[i]] Sin[#] &], {i, 3}]`, then the `a[[i]]` remain frozen as `Part[]` expressions as opposed to whatever the actual values of the `a[[i]]` are, but maybe this is what the OP wants...

Comment: @J.M. It gets substituted when the function is evaluated: `Through[Table[With[{i = i}, a[[i]] Sin[#] &], {i, 3}][x]]`

Comment: @R.M, yes, that's true, but it's still a bit jarring for me to see the list of `Function[]`s still carrying `Part[]` objects around...

Comment: @JM, the thing is that the OP showed an example where `a` is undefined. If you try to evaluate it and it's undefined you get an error

Comment: @Rojo: hence my "what's `a` supposed to be?" question in my first comment. ;)

Comment: @J.M. Yes, it's almost like `SetDelayed` in that changing `a` changes the functions. Useful to know, but can create unexpected results if one weren't aware of it

Comment: @Rojo et al: thanks for undelete :)

Answer (score 11):

`. . .  &` is a held expression.  (`Function` has attribute `HoldAll`.)

[Injector pattern](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/1937/121) to the rescue:

```
Range@3 /. i_Integer :> (a[[i]] Sin[#] &)

Replace[Range@3, i_ :> (a[[i]] Sin[#] &), 1]

Table[j /. i_ :> (a[[i]] Sin[#] &), {j, 3}]
```

Or using [`\[Function]`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/character/Function.html) and [`Array`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Array.html):

```
Array[i \[Function] (a[[i]] Sin[#] &), 3]
```

---

In this case you could do the replacement the other direction but you will need to hold `i` to protect it from a global value:

```
Table[a[[i]] Sin[#] & /. HoldPattern[i] -> j, {j, 3}]
```

Or use `Block`:

```
Block[{i},
  Table[a[[i]] Sin[#] & /. i -> j, {j, 3}]
]
```

Answer (score 8):

This works, but only because `j` is undefined:

```
Table[(a[[j]]*Sin[#] &) /. j -> i, {i, 3}]
```

(if we do `j = 5; Table[(a[[j]]*Sin[#] &) /. j -> i, {i, 3}]` then it fails; one could localize this with `Module` to get it to work anyway).

Or, if you hate brevity and compactness:

```
cF = Function[{j}, a[[j]]*Sin[#] &];
Table[
 cF[j],
 {j, 1, 3}
 ]
```

Personally I'd use either this last form or WReach's/Rojo's way.

Comment: @LeonidShifrin thanks. Yes, that it would need to be localized is what I meant (it's accidental that `j` is undefined). Bad choice of words, I suppose (and, oops, I hadn't seen your comment... why not an answer?)

Comment: I've already answered a variant of this question twice (in the links I give in the comments to the question). Trying not to be greedy :-)

Answer (score 5):

With Mathematica 10, you can also do this by

```
Activate@Table[Inactivate[a[[i]]*Sin[#] &], {i, 3}]
```