# How do you properly create Buttons to change dynamic variables using Table

Tags: plotting, dynamic

In this example, I want a series of four buttons to change the value of a variable that is used dynamically to drive a plot.  I am trying to figure out why using Table around the buttons causes a problem.

This works:

```
{Button["1", freq = 1], Button["2", freq = 2], Button["3", freq = 3], 
 Button["4", freq = 4]}
 Dynamic[Plot[Sin[freq * x], {x, 0, 2 \[Pi]}]]
```

Why doesn't this work:

```
Table[Button[ToString[i], freq2 = i], {i, 4}]
Dynamic[Plot[Sin[freq2 * x], {x, 0, 2 \[Pi]}]]
```

Comment: Strongly related: http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/7756/121

Answer (score 14):

The second one does not work, because `Button` has [`HoldRest`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/HoldRest.html) property:

```
In[1]:= Attributes[Button]
Out[1]= {HoldRest, Protected, ReadProtected}
```

Thus, `i` in your buttons are interpreted as literal `i`, not numbers.

The easiest way to solve this is using a `Map`:

```
Map[(Button[ToString[#], freq2 = #]) &, Range[4]]
Dynamic[Plot[Sin[freq2*x], {x, 0, 2 \[Pi]}]]
```

When each value is applied to the pure function, `#` will be replaced with the actual value.

## PS

Just for fun, you can confirm these by using Shift-Ctrl-E (or Shift-Cmd-E on Mac) on your button cell (exposing underlying FE language). This is what you see when expanding the button cell from the original code:

[image: cell]

As you can see, the action assigns `i` to `freq` (all in `$CellContext`), not actual value (1, this case).

Comment: Thank you, that makes perfect sense.

Answer (score 7):

Look at the `FullForm` of the two lists:

```
{Button["1", freq = 1], Button["2", freq = 2], Button["3", freq = 3], Button["4", freq = 4]} //FullForm
(* List[Button["1",Set[freq,1]],Button["2",Set[freq,2]],Button["3",Set[freq,3]],Button["4",Set[freq,4]]] *)

Table[Button[ToString[i], freq2 = i], {i, 4}] // FullForm
(* List[Button["1",Set[freq2,i]],Button["2",Set[freq2,i]],Button["3",Set[freq2,i]],Button["4",Set[freq2,i]]] *)
```

In the second case you `Set` your `freq2` equal to the symbolic `i`, not to the value of the iteration variable. That's because `Button` has the attribute `HoldRest`.

A possible way out would be to inject the value in the variable using `With`, i.e.

```
Table[With[{j = i}, Button[ToString[i], freq2 = j]], {i, 4}] //FullForm
(* List[Button["1",Set[freq2,1]],Button["2",Set[freq2,2]],Button["3",Set[freq2,3]],Button["4",Set[freq2,4]]] *)
```

Moreover, this is referenced in the [documentation](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Button.html) for `Button`, at **Scope** $\rightarrow$ **Button Control**.

Comment: Yes, I see here, as above, the `i` was not being evaluated.  Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 3):

As already stated this is an evaluation problem because of the Hold attribute that `Button` has, and the mechanism of `Table` which is akin to `Block`.  You need a way to get the value into the expression.  In this case I would use `Function` and `Array`:

```
Array[Button[#, freq2 = #] &, 4]

Dynamic @ Plot[Sin[freq2*x], {x, 0, 2 π}]
```

(`ToString` is unnecessary.)

See the answers to this question for other options:

[Function in Table](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/7756/121)

Comment: Thank you.  Nice to see the alternative `Array` to `Map` above.  I would not have thought of the alternative.