# Button's command is not evaluated in iteration

Tags: list-manipulation, evaluation, button

I wish I didn't feel like a newbie after several months, but...

If I enter the following:

```
Table[ Button[ "Number: " <> ToString @ i, Print @ i], {i, 1, 5}]
```

this creates a list of buttons, labelled `Number: 1`, `Number: 2`, etc. but pressing each button only prints `i`, not the number corresponding to the button. I assume this is standard newbie-doesn't-understand `Mathematica` stuff, but would appreciate any explanation of how to change the behaviour so that each button prints the value of `i`.

Comment: Very closely related [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7523836/evaluate-seems-to-not-work-inside-button/)

Comment: Don't feel bad -- it took me a rather embarrassing long time to realize `Button`'s `HoldRest` attribute  required I use `With` to get the kind of behavior you are looking for.

Comment: Strongly related: [(1)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/7756/121), [(2)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/8237/121)

Answer (score 8):

You could do

```
Table[
 With[{i = i}, Button["Number: " <> ToString@i, Print@i]],
 {i, 1, 5}]
```

The reason is that

```
Attributes@Button

(*{HoldRest, Protected, ReadProtected}*)
```

so that the code you produce ends up containing things like `Button["Number: 2", Print[i]]` (try looking at `Table[Button["Number: " <> ToString@i, Print@i],{i, 1, 5}] // FullForm` to see this). `With` literally replaces `i` with the value at each iteration, [even if the expression is held](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/561/16) (as it is here).

Comment: Many thanks, that's a great link too.

Answer (score 5):

Since your parameter  `i` in `Button` is outside `Table` (because of the `HoldRest` attribute of `Button`), it is not a number anymore. However you could do e.g. this :

```
Button["Number: " <> ToString @ #, Print @ #] & /@ Range[5]
```

If there is a need for `i` parameter one can do this :

```
Button["Number: " <> ToString @ #, Print @ # ] & /@ Table[i, {i, 5}]
```

Comment: I guess the question really is "how does `i` end up outside the `Table`" (answer, because `Button` is `HoldRest`)

Comment: The question was : How to change the behaviour so that each button prints the value of i ?  I didn't need the reasoning concerning the attributes of `Button`, my answer explains how to do what the OP wanted.

Comment: OK, my apologies then. Note that your code works precisely because it circumvents the attributes (`i` gets evaluated to a number outside the `Button`, so `HoldRest` can't prevent it), so I don't see how you don't need the `HoldRest` bit.

Answer (score 4):

You can do :

```
Table[With[{i = i}, Button["Number: " <> ToString@i, Print[i]]], {i, 1, 5}]
```

Answer (score 3):

I favor `Array` here:

```
Array[Button[Row @ {"Number: ", #}, Print @ #] &, 5]
```

Also see:

[Function in Table](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/7756/121)

[How do you properly create Buttons to change dynamic variables using Table](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/8237/121)