# Table of Buttons

Tags: list-manipulation, button

What's the correct way to form a table of buttons in which each action depends on the index in the table?  E.g., I want to get

```
{Button[1,f[1]],Button[2,f[2]]}
```

but the obvious attempt

```
Table[Button[i,f[i]],{i,1,2}]
```

fails because the second argument of Button is held.

What's the idiomatic way to do this?

Comment: See also [(15525)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/15525/121)

Answer (score 4):

You can use [`With`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/With.html)

```
Table[With[{i = i}, Button[i, f[i]]], {i, 1, 2}]
```

Comment: Thanks.  I don't think I would soon have hit upon that: reminding the interpreter that i=i doesn't seem like it would all that helpful.  I'm beginning to think that Mathematica isn't such a great language.

Comment: @AndrewDabrowski It's a well documented behavior. See http://wolfram.com/xid/0mrh4y-qke and http://wolfram.com/xid/0gisaa-y9z for example. Also, this isn't really an issue of "reminding the interpreter that i=i", it's more about scoping. `Table` is effectively using [`Block`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Block.html) and the `Button` action is only evaluated, when the `Button` is clicked.

Comment: The key point to remember is that `With` can inject to held expressions. And `Button` is `HoldRest`. p.s. `i=i` is arbitrary, it can be `whatever = i` and now you have to put `whatever` to the button, with `i=i` you don't have to change the code, that's why it is often used.

Comment: Thanks for your help.  I still think these fussy scoping rules are a negative for the language.  It seems Wolfram is still paying for mistakes he made 25 years ago.  Wouldn't the natural way to specify a handler be as a function, perhaps with a HandlerArguments option?  Using a held expression seems to me a terrible idea.  Maybe I should just write an alternative...

Answer (score 2):

This too does the same thing:

```
Button[#, f[#]] & /@ Range@2
```

Also an ugly but stupid way:

```
Table["Button[" <> ToString@i <> ",f[" <> ToString@i <> "]]", {i, 2}] // ToExpression
```

One can write it down without thinking.

Comment: Likewise does `Button[#, f[#]] &~Array~2`.

Comment: Cool Infix using