# Order of operations for the Table function

Tags: list-manipulation, functional-style

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Using pure functions in Table](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/7756/using-pure-functions-in-table)

I have run into a situation that I do not understand when trying to generate a nested list of pure functions. I have the following code.

```
Table[Function[x, i*x + j], {i, 1, 3}, {j, 1, 4}]
```

I expected to get a nested list of pure functions, but the values for `i` and `j` are not being input. I get

```
{{Function[x, i x + j], Function[x, i x + j], Function[x, i x + j], 
  Function[x, i x + j]}, {Function[x, i x + j], Function[x, i x + j], 
  Function[x, i x + j], Function[x, i x + j]}, {Function[x, i x + j], 
  Function[x, i x + j], Function[x, i x + j], Function[x, i x + j]}}
```

What is making this operation fail to behave as I expected?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`Function` has `HoldAll` attribute:

```
Attributes[Function]
(*{HoldAll, Protected}*)
```

To see that this is the cause,

```
SetAttributes[f, HoldAll]
Table[
 f[x, i*x + j],
 {i, 1, 3},
 {j, 1, 4}
 ]
(*
{{f[x, i x + j], f[x, i x + j], f[x, i x + j], 
  f[x, i x + j]}, {f[x, i x + j], f[x, i x + j], f[x, i x + j], 
  f[x, i x + j]}, {f[x, i x + j], f[x, i x + j], f[x, i x + j], 
  f[x, i x + j]}}
*)
```

EDIT: You can either use `With` to inject the values,

```
Table[
  With[{i=i,j=j},Function[x, i*x + j]],
  {i, 1, 3},
  {j, 1, 4}
  ]
```

or, more perversely,

```
Table[
  function[x, i*x + j],
  {i, 1, 3},
  {j, 1, 4}
  ] /. function -> Function
```

or even

```
Block[{Function},
 Table[
  Function[x, i*x + j],
  {i, 1, 3},
  {j, 1, 4}
  ]
 ]
```

Comment: It's probably good to point out that the second and third methods (`function -> Function` and `Block`) are safe only if the `Function` contains an expression that does not evaluate.

Comment: @Szabolcs right, they effectively sidestep the `HoldAll` completely

Answer (score 4):

`Function` has attribute `HoldAll`, which means it doesn't evaluate its arguments.

`Table` localizes the variables in each iteration much like `Block` does. This means, it just temporarily gives the variables the value that corresponds to the iteration, and then run the contained code.

So, try

```
x = 8; Function[i, i x]
```

and see that you get `Function[i, i x]`, where the `x` has not been replaced.

Try

```
Array[{i, j} \[Function] x \[Function] i x + j, {3, 4}]
```

Answer (score 3):

You already have 3 answers including one accepted one.
Notwithstanding, naively I would have done

```
Table[Function[x, i*x + j // Evaluate], {i, 1, 3}, {j, 1, 4}]
```

which works and follows your syntax.

PS: I replaced `Release` by `Evaluate` to avoid unnecessary confusion.

Comment: That's an interesting tactic. Do you think ReleaseHold would work? My Mathematica 8 help tells me that Release was superseded by Evaluate and ReleaseHold.

Comment: I didn't know the function `Release`.  Apparently it's the old and deprecated name for `Evaluate`.  @Carl `Evaluate` will work only at the first level of the head with a `Hold...` attribute.  `Function[x, i*x + j // Evaluate]` will work here, but `Function[x, Evaluate[i]*x + Evaluate[j]]` will not.  This is because `Evaluate` is implemented as a special exception to `Hold...` attributes: when the evaluator sees something with `HoldAll`, it will check if there's an `Evaluate` inside, but only at the first level (it won't do a potentially slow deep search).

Comment: @Szabolcs, as I said a number of times before, `Release[]` is a sort of hybrid of `Evaluate[]` and `ReleaseHold[]`; that is, it was the useful function before the devs at Wolfram finally decided to split `Release[]`'s functionality into the two modern functions `Evaluate[]` and `ReleaseHold[]`.

Answer (score 2):

I encountered this problem myself a while ago.  The evaluation order of the `Table`, which the docs say "usually" has the iterative variable replaced first, is a bit weird here.  I suppose that this is a case when they're not replaced first.

However, they are replaced for `With`.  You can use this to your advantage with (get it?) this:

```
Table[With[{a = i, b = j}, Function[x, a*x + b]], {i, 1, 3}, {j, 1, 4}]
```

Then:

```
%[[1, 1]][3]
(* 4 *)
```

Comment: you can also do `With[{i = i, j = j}, Function[x, i*x + j]]`