# Expansion in Basis Functions

Tags: functions, series-expansion, pure-function

I am trying to create an expansion of the form

```
f[x,y]->Sum[Cn[x] y^n,{n,1,order}]
```

To replace the function `f` by the coefficients `cn`. Since the function `f` appears in a differential equation, it is useful to get this to work as a set of replacement rules for a pure function, such that the function `f` and all its derivatives are replaced. Something like this works:

```
f->((c0[#1]+c1[#1] #2+c2[#1]#2^2)&)
```

Curiously, this expression doesn't

```
f->(( Sum[c[[n]][#1] #2^n,{n,1,order}] )&)
```

(where `c` is a pre-defined vector of coefficients).  The  index `n` is not recognized in the context of defining the pure function (though the same expression defining `f[x,y]` would work).

Similarly, if I have several functions and I am trying to define a collection of these replacement rules, this also does not work:

```
Table[ f[[i]]->f->((c0[[i]][#1]+c1[[i]][#1] #2+c2[[i]][#1]#2^2)&), {i,1,whatever}]
```

Somehow defining and manipulating a collection of pure functions with an index needs a different syntax. I am curious as for the logic of why this does not work, maybe then I'll understand how to fix it.

Edit: Apologies for the vague question. I think the logic that I was missing is related to attributes of pure functions I was trying to use in replacement rules, as pointed out by acl below. This is related to this question: [Function in Table](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/7756)

Comment: One problem is that you are doing the sum with iterators `{n,0,order}` which goes from n=0 up to n=order. But with n=0, C[[n]] is not defined. So maybe C[[n+1]] would fix it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's a number of reasons your code doesn't work (all related to attributes; basically, `Function` [has attribute](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/14304/16) `HoldAll`). I think this does what you want:

```
MapThread[
 Rule,
 Transpose@Table[
   {f[n], With[{n = n}, c[[n]][#1] #2^n &]},
   {n, 1, order}
   ]
 ]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

How does this work? `With[{n=n},body]` is what fixes the problem, as it literally inserts `n` into the body of the `Function`, so the `HoldAll` attribute never gets to see the `n`; it just sees the explicit value.

To illustrate what `With` does here:

```
Block[{y = 2}, y*x &]
Block[{y = 2}, With[{y = y}, y*x &]]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

So, here, in the first case the `y` in the function doesn't evaluate to `2`, then the block exits and we're done. In the second case, `y` gets literally replaced by 2. That is, you may think of `With[{y=2},body]` as a search-and-replace of `y` by 2 in the body before anything else happens (before, i.a., evalution of `body`).

Hope this clarifies things a bit.

Comment: Thanks, the attributes of the function is the point I was missing. Thanks for the link, I will take a look.

Comment: note that I used `f[i]` instead of `f[[i]]`, because if `f` is not defined, trying to take a part of it gives an error. replace `[]` with `[[]]` if this is what you need

Comment: That was a point I caught (fixed by predefining the coefficient vector), but the attributes and the use of  `with` is likely the point I missed. My question was vague because I didn't want to simply fix the code, I wanted to understand what I am missing since the syntax seemed to me like it ought to work. Thanks for pointing me the right direction.

Comment: @Moshe I tried to explain it a bit more here, hope it's clearer.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not really sure about what are you trying to do with those rules, but the following works:

```
c = Table[#/n! &, {n, 0, 10}];
f[order_] := ((Sum[c[[n + 1]][#1] #2^n, {n, 0, order}]) &)

Plot3D[{f[5][x, y], f[10][x, y]}, {x, -10, 10}, {y, -10, 10}, 
       PlotStyle -> {{Opacity[0.6], Red}, {Opacity[0.6], Blue}}]
```

Please remember to start your symbols with lowercase chars, `C`is a system's defined name.

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I don't think I have been very clear, I tried to modify my question to emphasize the point I am not getting, how to define and use a collection of pure functions.

Comment: @Moshe I don't understand your question because you seem to be  defining RULES (`->`) and not pure functions