# Summation of If statements

Tags: evaluation, summation, conditional

The following made me curious. Suppose you want to sum the if statement `If[x[i] < 1., x[i]^2, 0.]` over `i=1,2`, i.e.

```
Sum[If[x[i] < 1., x[i]^2, 0.], {i, 1, 2}].
```

Mathematica returns

```
If[x[1] < 1., x[i]^2, 0.] + If[x[2] < 1., x[i]^2, 0.].
```

Notice the `i`'s if the statement is true. However, I thought a more "natural" representation of the sum should look like

```
If[x[1] < 1., x[1]^2, 0.] + If[x[2] < 1., x[2]^2, 0.].
```

Does anybody can enlighten me on this one? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Try `Sum[If[x[i] < 1., 1/0, 0^0], {i, 1, 2}]`.

Comment: Related: http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/7756/121

Answer (score 9):

Since `If` has attribute `HoldRest`, the `i` will not be inserted into the latter parts during the evaluation. Consider this example showing the same effect:

```
Sum[s[i, Hold[i]], {i, 1, 2}]
(* s[1, Hold[i]] + s[2, Hold[i]] *)
```

I think the best practices way of getting what you are asking for is to use `With` to ensure `i` gets inserted:

```
Sum[With[{i = i}, If[x[i] < 1., x[i]^2, 0]], {i, 1, 2}]
(* If[x[1] < 1., x[1]^2, 0] + If[x[2] < 1., x[2]^2, 0] *)
```